# Sort a list, poorly

Tags: code-challenge, array

Don't you hate it when you're trying to roughly sort a list based on user data, but you have to poll the user for thousands of comparisons?

Hate no more, because the answers to this challenge are (going to be) here!

### Method

The sorted-ness of a list is defined by how many possible comparisons it has which are correct.

Let's have an example. The list `[1, 2, 4, 3]` has the possible comparisons `1 <= 2`, `1 <= 4`, `1 <= 3`, `2 <= 4`, `2 <= 3` and `4 <= 3`. 1 out of those 6 comparisons are incorrect, so this list is (5 / 6) * 100 = 83.33% sorted.

### Challenge

Create a program or function that sorts a given list (but not necessarily 100%) and sorts all of the below test cases by at least 75%.

If your program sorts a list by less than 75% that is not in the test cases, that's okay, but try not to hard-code to the test-cases although I can't ban you from doing so.

You must use a comparison sort. Pretend the numbers are black boxes that only support comparison operations.

Your program may sort the list backwards, which means if it's is able to sort all of the test cases by less than 25%, you can post it as a backwards sort.

For programs that perform STDIO, the list should be taken and printed as base-10 integers with some kind of separator, with optional text at the start and end (for example `1\n2\n3` or `[1, 2, 3]`)

You may also return or print a list of indices that correspond to the sorted list (e.g. `[1, 3, 2]` when sorted is indices `[0, 2, 1]`)

You may not compare any of the elements of the list with any constant values.

The [defaults for I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply as usual.

### Scoring

This is a [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), not a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your code is scored by the highest number of comparisons your code needs to be able to sort across all of the test cases.

A comparison is defined as any operation that involves a value `x` from the given list and another value `y` which may or may not also be from the given list, and does a boolean check of one of `x < y`, `x <= y`, `x == y`, `x >= y` or `x > y` *or* returns a result depending on whether `x < y`, `x == y` or `x > y`. This includes any expressions, including mathematical equations, that have the same effect of comparison.

The test cases are [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5eLiwvC0CtOTU3RMLYwNTE1MDc3sTSxNLY0M7Ew0OTiSssvUohXyMwDaUlP1TA0NdC04lIAgoKizLwSjWioASAKxDfQUTAyNdVUwKItVvP/fwA).

To verify your sorted lists, use [this](https://tio.run/##bY9NasQwDIX3OoWWNhj3Jy2F0vQiQxjSxMOIKnawlCE5fepMwqyqlfSEvvc0LnpNsVpXGsaUFUlD1pRY4BBkEQBgEhWs8RRuLZvZ4iVlnJHitveiPUWfQ9sb62VkUqYYxNgGoA8X7K6h@z1LwYW@6GLYfgKWykEm3sEzftW47FxXmoJ@ZPFdGn4otkoplmOHr4W83@uUS4ZpMAfK4hNyiI8RYMwU1bTM5p8Y@F3js/94v/vyZnr/1Np1Pb0UH4dvDqsGtqFyeEjNHw) program.

The lowest score wins. Good luck!

Comment: Given that it takes about n log n comparison for a naive algorithm, make sure that there are >> n log n lists with some length may work. For example, if each list has length 200, having 50000 tests should be ok.

Comment: Is [this code](https://tio.run/##NYtLDgIhEAWv8lYTSBgSf0u8gScgLHpG8BPsJjK6mrsjmriqSr28O72pzs9bWcaJpphHlnNsCa4R3BFkH1QUf1WJ5wCHH9YVPmhbXvWqWBtIH3rAMEBsyrSc/jfWbRaukqPNclFJ@b3BzuBgsDXovglatw8) valid? (100% sorted, no _observable_ comparison)

Comment: @Arnauld See my Python verifier above, if it helps.

Comment: Now it's not allowed to compare an element with a constant, the verifier is [here](https://tio.run/#%23fZE9b8QgDIbn5Fe46nCgplGut0WXbF07dqmqiOOcHhKBFIhKfn1KPq9DlQEB9mP7td327qbVaeCSWQtvXZMDPMJVg9IOGOcYrO6GcPAHaLC5oIkjrjvliuw/UFhAz7F1UGsDrRHKgUHbSRdHV6yhqoQSrqqIRVkn4GkeR9H4Tn3hV4Q37UboUNzQSVSvO@BMhSPlXErUk/GHqZA@CuLTSdpTcQzf4HR9i2TOAAEflU4dGiYswjuTHb4ao0NLkUHXGQVk1lJOQamnz4vhvBpWjXJsgiUXmi@RLF2FX@g52zDcw4qNU3vcw53D7x2uuHNfe/nKP9xeG2UWx1JYBwV8hLmRI03G@ZGX5T7Rz2H0p1YbR@gwrZtsa6DDLw).

Comment: Info: even if compare to constant is not allowed, it's still possible to hardcode for the test cases with score n+log(number of test cases), assume test cases are random.

Comment: @user202729 "_valid_" was a badly chosen word. I should have asked: what is the score for this code? Is it 0?

Comment: @Arnauld Don't answerers have to prove that their code has the claimed score? If the performed operations are unobservable and the answerer can't count number of comparisons then it's their fault. /// It's possible to make the rules rigorous by making it similar to an interactive problem in competitive programming, but then people are forced to implement a lot of boring boilerplate code to interact via stdin/stdout/etc.

Comment: @Anders Kaseorg Yes, it should. Updated.

Comment: Are we required to use a [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), that is, only access the list by comparing pairs of values at given indices? I'm unclear in general how many operations on elements can be scored if they are not comparisons.

Comment: @xnor Browsing TVTropes, are you? ;) Yes, a comparison sort is required. Pretend the numbers are objects that support comparisons but you are unable to get their intrinsic value for some reason or another.

Comment: @Arnauld user is correct, if you are unable to tell how many comparisons your code actually performs by a custom object or other introspection, it is not valid to post. As for the issue of defining an expression that performs a comparison, anything that splits the programs behavior into one of 2 or 3 outcomes depending on the relationship between `x` and `y`. That means that subtraction doesn't count, as it can yield one of any number of results, as opposed to only one of a few.

Comment: @LyricLy Haha, I ninja-fixed the link. I think this makes sense, but could be made clearer and more precise in the challenge text. The usual model for this is that you have a black-box function that takes two indices `i` and `j` and tells you whether `a[i]<a[j]` (or since, you allow ties, it could give `cmp(a[i],a[j])`.

Comment: Also, a technicality: since the output is itself a list of numbers, the code needs to at some point get the actual values of the numbers, unless it can do something like manipulate pointers to the numbers which is not an abstraction all languages have. Allowing output to be a permutation of list indices that would sort the list could address that.

Comment: Please clarify whether an answer is required to sort all lists 75% of the way (given “To poorly sort a list, you must sort it at least 75% of the way.… Create a program or function that poorly sorts a given list”), or whether it’s allowed to sort the given test cases 75% of the way while sorting other possible inputs less than 75% of the way (given “and sorts all of the below test cases by at least 75%”)? I assumed the former, but it looks like @xnor assumed the latter.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Ah, that's a mistake I made while writing the challenge. It's only required to sort the test case lists all of the way. I'll clarify that.

Comment: @xnor That's what I suggested above, but then people are forced to implement a lot of boilerplate code, etc.

Comment: Are we allowed to *actually* treat the numbers in a way that their value is unknown?

Comment: If I've read correctly, I only have to count comparisons that involve list elements and values derived from list elements, but any number of comparisons having nothing to do with the list content is fine?

Comment: @Οurous That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score 244

```python
def sort_func(l):
	num_pieces = 9
	
	medians = [median5(l[5*i : 5*(i+1)]) for i in range(num_pieces)]
	
	center = median(medians)
	
	lows = []
	highs = []
	
	for x in l:
		if x < center:
			lows.append(x)
		else:
			highs.append(x)
	
	for d in range(9):
		for lst in [lows, highs]:
			if lst[d] > lst[~d]:
				lst[d], lst[~d] = lst[~d], lst[d]
	
	l[:] = lows + highs

def median(lst):
	lst.sort()
	return lst[len(lst)//2]

def median5(l):
	a, b, c, d, e = l

	if a > b: a,b=b,a
	if c > d: c,d=d,c

	if a < c:
		a = e
		if a > b: a,b=b,a
	else:
		c = e
		if c > d: c,d=d,c

	if a < c:
		if b > c:return c
		else: return b
	else:
		if d > a:return a
		else: return d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fL1Lr23HlaXXFn/FdblhqopWrXhHJErZM@CG4aY7iUSCIpmVhClKFimXsuO/Xj4r5vhGxEkUMoGk7r1nn73XXitixnyMx5//9dd/@dPP5b//9@9/@Ocvv/zpL7/@0z//9efvvv7pt3/31W9@/usf/@nPP/7w3Q@/fPn9l/XVb776zR9/@P7Hb39@//oP8cf29U//0P7jj1/@7kv7j1//@J/Sb//xt1/@@U9/@fLjlx9//vKXb3/@rz98fd7lt//4vsd3P/z86w9/@XiLeIev9Z6/fX/205/@237zjxf@y4//9V/481e/ed/zb@97/vRxXb/58Z8//vJfvsQ7vf@wf/F33/75zz/8/P3Xf/t4q9/88NMvP@yf7Pe5fxRv9v25wPV@1/2PP/3y6/vP//C@2zdf9m/@436Tjw/8@Nk/fP@PX/5@/@H/@z7@/Tfxr9/wjx/Xqz99o1/Y3@of/m7/5P1y/yne9quv3vutO/DxyvcSPv7nd@8T@PrjIv/yw69//cvP@z1@@iFe8Z//c/7H@9daPKRvv/nyh2@@fPfNl@@/@fLD@ylfffVe7rcfV/qHv/vy7Td/@P0fvvl2/9N3H//0/d99vPT733//zXe87OM2vl/l249f/SFu7b/9VW7ld@cl/@5bffz5Dx8//@7v9CW@43F80T/84bznx2u//3jtt7z223/72u//@49//PPHTfny48ej/vVPf/rpl6/0D7/868dd1J8/HuT3f/rjV19999O3v/zy5f/86x//7suX//nL93/68vOffv3y7Xcfa@@XL7/@yw9f/pe//S8fd@@Pf/jhLx/r8E9//fnX3z//oxf@@MuXH/723Q9//nWv5T//5cefPz7ih1/@@tOvX/3mfQD/9E8//vzjr//0T1//8sNP//zNl7/tBfT@@Xd/@/3feMl3f/yzX/Gnjw//y2/3Rf3rn/765btvP@7Ktz/9FB/1cQ/ef/xv3/788fa/@bj43@1L@0@/T3GDfv3XP//wdbzDl4@Xv1e6v@G7AP/y7Y@//PDl//r2p7/@8L/95S9/@svX14vfbaC7@HVc3N/vH/zub7/9X/UP/4V/4KJ/er/Vx5P/rR/I7/gmf/jtf3n8sh/@vZf93q/7@d973f90XvfD//PvvO7353X/9d97v7@/XvfvfY2/f2IbffcvP3z3f//Tu@N@@P7njwe/99OXj/@LR72Dz0eY@f2Xf93L4G/ffPzhIzp4IX48pj/@4cefv/31xz/9/PHL33zJHwEufn9/5i9//ePXeqvffvmP6XfPl//85d3M/NsOIL/56pfv/vSXHxTp9oPXn7/aEenHX379p19@/cv7wX/89s9ff/zxd3/5@M@Pf/7m3QC/@@XX73/8@V1@XjbvTfjpfYePf/mId18cOX/4f7/96Wve7w3Fd7TfgXl/OKHSb/jxs7hEfvI/uG@//eqrvUu@/g//x5/@2w8fUXT/xn/45ssff/z56/jtj9foJf/7RwB8X7Pf/X3Nt3/7Oj77t7/97/@QZvrmS/nmS@of//N882Wtjz/n/HF30/zmy5jvH7758vE/5eMFuYz3lR9/SvXjJbN9/GF@/FJ73yB//Oz9xfddUvp4m/xU/Wm8L6zv75aPN0vr/U9/P6i9rxj7t/mt@GlN7we//1af923fv5aP1@X2vtX7efn5ePH6uJT@8bP6vqbH9e7Le/9/LF1Vigv9@NP6@MX3C9eP1819AW1/ufHxs17095x5@/S@5v3ObX@dj5@t@f7reyveK6/78vefVnzxfRHvr8cVfPz/U@Jf48U9v9/w/V7lvaZ9h973bFnvvd6vkj7@Vj9@p328wXt/y/tVP17/fqP4eu@bvo8gt/e92vuYZtzn/TFr6A/vLXw/bj@L9@m8b/F@0L7fz76Q97u9/9n367357x16P3ZfTHs/7/3nlnRfZ9UDeh/m@@3fu/dewnvz3ptQuLrCY5vv136/43tL3v95v2HcixavT8/71vumj6G/9vmPX/3DfsX@mu8tz7XFrcj5/c/7BfZ62yts35qhZfBe5PvE9i1I@zbtRfU@3H1/4ibxs/L@aT/U97rfO7sf0L7e9zfmx3/6E19pdh7duz7e27EWv5CXVta@t3X/@6N1OFgK7@14723n677/8N7o97f3ReyNtrfl0Kp5l@/emO/@eL@89tJkQb3PJpZdqnFz931670HdW0qrdlQ9nX273vVftNvf3ZT2w3ifZjyH9wV7xX38Vt1r5v0iPbbRfjax8TsPoa37V/dNee/b3syxs96VGuts6LLen73bOB5FyvoOEQ/e7zC1lvZ33EEjok2Jq197Ze01tu9S0e/srxHLputbDW7Qu@L3lt@P7f3q@8vscPNk7vz7cEtWuHovYT/L/WVTvEd6v85@@/Su1j7j0UaoZPulMrVaHn703qy872gtWs573zz8JwLGo51X9suXbsoiqO4r3TdzB4M3brwL8P20HY72@t3hpLAf3q9T91d9r2LqkTY2UAQ@/ca@b/tK91Ia7OIdgHew9rPaH6BA05Ie844r8Yh3ZNw3Jut98/6VfQVLYXzoeewd9l47we59n30P302xt827YXvc@TgKHq2ofVhoA@2H@Z5sNT7k3V7xvTm@3gc/WZAlQu5@yV65@zQkTrwXtSMtQSFOqqb/vG@5V92@J5l18N6PfQOWzqhZ9AvvX/JenStuzd7Red/bfQf3NcUZsyNeZt3vn77X/H6IjrV9v99dX7rfqSr65Dr5044wLb9L9ZlaQG8w0FlQecxxANd7V8f1vCthednuW/FeUycm7r/tiLX/tO/I/h7v/76RIBGl81klWhYRyN5t8m6@/Ze9E/Yqj@toWgN7Y@wtuuPhXidEkEx43ldROOd3qvKu7EV6sx@tV1NcYdEy3Qfk@5imTsu4//txd63X2DCF7fnen/fpTsWafdcfbdUIgDt2xRrryh3ibHu0wCMQ6JCLROz9l7a0vd97NR7F9fdD9nW8J8s@TofC9H6/vfF3AB/E1vej95bZG3p/4/ff52I77t0f3y3rr/vJxLHZYifGEkkKVHu9T237zsm6H1f8aGnD5Xct7y2aSOXiT@8ayXoS9VOqNB4dl/vZ1o9lWzgrZlZEfKNGHF2xE/YSTfHYyET28Z0UtnfAipvz7KshuO2ref@2c0ft8xX/tMgxlVX4tJ37zZZiw1JM2WlVLNK9wrW@Yv/tI6MqUdjxjp1SdZ1xc97v@h6li3C9D6x9qKUIOCmCQo@PUXBein87FcoE4Pc5O4fbKeDe9/uGxMYtrM19IETWn@IDp4@swe7dW2r/ToTLqZNoR7zCvd1Bbt/SpscQD67Ft6/OaKvW47sI9pmwn@KObPFUli9W2WnkdDUCyT7WYovuJRVn9KNUaa@sp/Ne@/33CZF1P/YefCNvUVyKROoEpkJIeD9iv3Aot6heJe/V7SP6feH7qPaCfZfF5GnNyBe7Q3GUAQ@7OxGMIsXf@ywCFEfZvsfvY9n/vFfFvhtv2J@NsoYvuLMUfjy6M9rCU9mJPzlplGJJJ9u7leMwco2ROMuazvD9o73nH06dwnbf3yVNXfds@kMllO0L3G/@/iyW5kO032no@/zez33X1iJLfX8h9lT2oyQL2ZXZXn97Nzh7aLq1e3sN5drJCcobld8F2DkRu@5xLMt9LZlqZa/@OFqGjsFdOe1irVC27pWexh1fd5W8P/RdnFENEQ32C/ZZF3tFz2KwcfZhu3@lKj/d0akrZJyTbi/3OAMcgbJuf9r3eGc7jcL1Xarv2nh/tCItKJzWT1SV79ffT30qHO0/7F0cld7Qu3oz7@CoFfb@IErMqbUcC@991O@t2cFyaqnus/Q9PXYSs1P7h3S26wvsRcFX2xt4L93Fg4yk2k@MQzeir@7XjnVxO5eKyt70IUW5LXfzfbu9yiJw1rjSCHo7iE9dWAQlWg1xAmedq3uxxh5OCt87GCTKl6XDK8fpTa6wN@JuoTjWL5blXgX7MIqKKrN3ZgTg/YQim086nXaQ5Ea97/1e6d6ZERbISfZX3SdtpdQpKuv2auB@FmdDff/rUjdAiVHmse@rnN48kQI/O4HfezeOGT3Y4uA@lCW/7xZ7eD/S/rFMKR33eZWdsO1vsBfZUL26H/57Ryq1fjyUphuUdLvfa6oqVmuE972y4/HtTbHv3Puf6sR8n3/vZUYmV7SiIrfei7nEJ78LZOeOO6vNlBGdVoorzqaWwv7w96LiYFvssaTntJdpIScY1RuCvkRX5biP@aEEIppzTYdMo0G1r2w664qXOouKYr2zvBqxd0eeHWXit5Y@sFAbvY8901Xbp1qlORfv6ef2qIguWiK7jZTjaeyFE7t60VXbd7qTIp8jP1Lavcjes3MHhT4igd81/qDv8PiQ3bvHUW9H26l4ED9PCrKDhkvlHisRThEo40AbHEjvZ0bF/qYBsRP3W1RFhhJp1t4i74n0ngbvC2LjVoXDa/MkyoHeVAXuDsP7Qfvh7Tw6eiiPc4YScXYnRIu7Hst4kCq893SS2@4Vv/fQvuexyLj7sZpoUe30/P3l/aGZvlfWLYh2MYH3jSUj4k/Tht7H927MastFPZ61jltiA2fi/P5ZHCCZE21/j8pNUxHL89zvQySL/6hRvbQpZuYEV/M2spcZ4b9H@3tHlve2N6JHYm3sA2BQPGb3dffd24fCXo8qYqLN3LXkCEGRjUZHVJcUTzPR99mbPo7OhyxnPxDvqziNp1ZedPR0urNbdv6yF2JkMg6e0VjbBdKz21iLKyEr7Nkt9enEfxJ6Cp2VeNqVR7N7z5Vdm/QAqZ2qSwJ20G4jD3ZXbJRGaKvqkUVQSFx7nOzFfZupJbybstHkWGrBxc1yj33/1j7Qht51H6xDR8JejJ3zuLvftfu4btO@z7KyRnOheNs3bV@tg1zzJ7yX5/5afmP6Lq17LBEy2RThu/B9aEK9f4iCZCkHia2jFZuch@033I9gH99RALvb/fSrVf8@2R0X48R/9DX9hHYk2rFiJ7x0ZXe4rZRZk4lLBK7IxhWuxokFTguamzuFtDLu8I4tU1ld9Aje77q/9EMvJsLTIHq/d3APDBo1FD2ZWOdVkTLOrr2gWoyOovQZWhn70nfiHXle4iwe2vg7z45BkfKGdwksJl5zukXV1FeNeFKuQ2mvhzhcqxYMO3BxKjzE3Tj/VIXudCESyGiJtzhRT9lTCKHvpb/r4BSvO5buDKfpVEh8q3h4XQOyKIxp88WUoWq0EfVPuz5y0EvbOfKOSo2m0dIAYaqH0TXCiJsS7bRKQNoBZWcFTZOKwbkW/dOk7l3kGS0@PkZeXY8u@cx871lXTNRJTWNhafW15FOBkUplyUUq5Uxnt@1jkDW5Z/sO60vt@FV5CHuzxn6Z@9jbX/e9rEiDIy7u5cpcJqs62B9U2OOFY@596/fXusYtOVq0WUdDdzMn9sZQ57LoPHbPZqitMz@d7ZFkZI9tHvpDOwYWl25FVfJiJJy4lTFMme77DhYd2/HdYR7P7D6mPnxSQO6Xxf5b@u1I@U9/d8c@SrWobnehtZPHoZC7n@xUZhCZlOu8eMNB7R8zQbp3VV0z9bUfl0MaXuz9k7Sq4xwYyij2Y9kn3T6P4rKTFlbz1Lhds@HI6jNfXn2h/RAqvf7G8NAzoHznGHtBJ5LIffsfXWJVpzsm0HtBJ5axj4P9dnsT5Ag7sY0LzSd9HE2z8rFgq9ZiO/XUE7/6/mQSmPaK6v3anfFWTZXrIJN4mObuwDbUp9LZ33W8vBFjR/H3HuyQlKk/q3oH@8x6VC3ug2P34jVfmdQGidZVpIgxCye7XLRokxu674fFYbVcuTpT3vuwuLs1FKvIePfL43N2bbebcExvGWIkn3pd0@ypiLILFec6@/YsyoSqdkJjft7VZkoMqHean1TR7scap@a@AdmHWXaZ2Dl482l@fBr5REDIJKO9UY4KdRGnfiz/qfl19Zj08bKmmtxbawf6QohgrbxbJMo0Mo1IYR73R2OqUFUE7zprafnNQDS8RdfSY99n0vte77qIJ0nhEIfniOFgNbKgug1z6qdMy2knC81jz6oB6g43ifZu0VGZp0EATflaLJWo7J0C8f6Fsiz@Wt3vdysrUbC6ibg3s3NwllbRQGUw2F/6xPfMmg8tw/0J@w7Ri8s0t@KYyzyEfcBEru3G9fDY4HQDk@atMfZ5v2drBlkk5WHrmhYXoD77Midfcp6pNVN0Gq9sey0OCr@dI0W@ReK2H9hZdEyk9xvtjvo@0Jwcx6CuczrGXMjZKnP6AECppivGKD3e2j489tf3pCf2UFVTpCkXWnv69U63SJLfJVFcmUUwoRo@6WzRvUw6fyMWjWuIGl9uMqvT3sixJnYA2Iia7lyMdTcIbZ1JcAVwEKEiMxSjho52d3Qsi@5FnB@PUD/7Hr93Zw@2AHg8DsGrfNqUiai7jxImCoEZY4a5/1QjPnWOwP2oorlEu3appmrFEIQcjcwdHgcfT/9jEa2KAAJxpi1qc0YiFcTKvnGN1CvWcgVEtf9p0TRoFDbuo1bS/Oi67eS6qjUbT/BdIYMYXHj2OzFRuzd7bpMIHc/jsZciWdUEIbul1jTuoCG0P6TwO4vlIvSBUSLtbRNExyDrLIpzt1wR8lH8iVtSgFbsoKBVQgdCM8oCymWwgnZutHFWDytox6vdDDrtHrfkAylGl3RPj0AWtHmjpuKwdInT1fN68kHypcCR7agZE5GHAmM/huYDquq4m2RPBknu618@1wCyxdLPAKk4coT0mIzXhKyLNCUBitjBtBK/Yns9FKTRaNxNlPfF@yHvZfKQBrLo92CX0Rhjlb3k3vfZTynRyCpq7gpCFRGJ@eqka5@dE8aISqCaffnDg//3c8tjGB41jXt8UX1Ha4TmSY3zbakUngr@Wf2ivgDrNOaZDIU/TkpNYaNLlVVjx0jGqcT7mIaHoYurSDRegDzFY9qHYSb3PciUM@3WKso0SZr3eVSOlfKRuqPx5Aup8Y7YdQBOokFQNMPotH1jbpS0j9V0jlIkCgdN4T0e4CWCl/bnHsSDLBiBdtO5xmY582Dfp05AHORMO@2cnqADInkfUI/T/akeMmqetBf27jMMIdgi482MrCY40qptUBR16ZSVdM@UNX8j1tJzr8tNVUdo5@Y6AgdNO/KcXQBFvjTVpxK0BPRZpAqgmygGGjlS1JuPJq@dBkrkB4nnkXbKWgnIILOqtt6O5Avo0fuMusK@wC70MoahIIvqVmhGekDq0Kqq3WMvQMuxTB4OgizYaiufhu0bNV4pXCqZSWSFg1xvn1EdLEFn1QxGDpFh7XKn3e1KhVFDt5va2KSPKzoJU@mTivsBBIO5S4wM1R6LxUbUWmyvyFB9T4TxAA0VMLaqFtIOGGAyT3HizeYZ/U6JaYs34Q/dMghE6uNs@qHJrHXUSVV3T0P/6BgdF1bdyIxA2nSJ@4ayKqp6Y/lsbgFRJt1cnRjNVe3ygOgRTODhi4KXCmxjjKLeBVtofO1nvpy8x2SJ5sz05LGyRvbyaJ9a@LsB2ahM4qgthNChjXHqjKzKYrcls6bBhQp/77H9vaebXVECu4Gg5PL00I3oXfFulV0/dODHzeqk4F0zWQ6meNszikykeWyEBHqBwk87LBrNmdSTg2JR3AqXqNZgpu2nGQFJzT5EGtjQuIRA7Dkz2PkICGx3MhINmDOdbRSB3R3VLppAczIYlR5N9go7Yz4uCtnK/UDF6l3gxJAdqOoGftIjyYbzduXxXTDB3cCYSQD@Dj6BmFwgNugA2oF/g1tIyIU0c6YdffjsTkVjCrCD4nKA4eYL3w9EOXmyD3UgUhNScY1zAWNEY3J3Yx/tOo0c/RsxTY3jRC2I6SL2PQnicImSJfC57v5rrNSMzRI8@cxMNSUDcLkX4AxARpy/8C2MAjDjYIAQGKyUfWTECXi1fqLNuVzGVy@zSEF2BtmZh2R1DCpoh/j1vYPpopdm6IyS/84AqXFM7CcRhWiBwUJGnbiMMj1EdsmYlaBQl0f4eoAWnelnv0b77aHKfnTD9zVW4xenplYqhR79cNEW2SdPU3kbz6OQ8889zdoZfqZ1Otrnp1jYTi07DVAkUsOGkeguWObhFe1/LBpXLZ57xIl9HdEV6Z5NR3/JoaWY@xTfD4BMcd2bqC6MFo9YNenAeU7USA0O7SvO9YexArjA2EzV3cOq@7/b6b4Ho@oRXq2RQwJ7t1xwGlqc9Ub3Jhp1j@5XU4zaZ8Ti97va/suA0nUg1RGjo14T2t81zzQaZTA52QfqZNBykLqRZi3tlm5IZNU1F49aE7FpEFvVVmGE0knYBEo0@@xUpQU8gs/fM0oaZ2QOmQVUaqCWyr2ZyngX7TUZOpg3t5dK8Wmv6WTlMHjuzuw@DyARRefgMRYrOQWsjD@m2VMmf@2Lq8XZ1WkwtYMR26NlDpLdvy0K1oUyab/t5rmph7wT4mWoF0Cq2ESVBHd5eJWUJ3gwu7/demjPZ4pgg9QbtUGc7k9iBD118qn8ixKnUVIbybUIaJn91B7n3YxZy4KQQoUetCEKnKh3pnHD4KgHKOCddSwohEnBZX@5xu8e9l7RRGuHmaVhZAQZYwLjnF2aJS33zYEoDcFRRTrZpTORdOP8AEhOWqVZVLsIj8amPG/2GqwerxmdKftUzmA6d5Gpr1mmEa8pjrFGGjRpUrLko1De@@ddp@QkYznlHnTuk3lLGl/utbhrccrYdghykNliZFONtxRy4P39QFmzRB6CYAcmEymnBpG7@krNFJNTsZp2ArNnmh9XDYSq9Mca0aZnV1ZPPMd9lc2QLQ/HAmjQOYXLgXQojRhg51fzSBbyYOznQ/raC3LfODheKurUvy2CrqQz/8zkjotjN7k8yeDdYhsm@qzGnWsVDMFFi6a4ySCsnTosoNce1AzXVCW73tIAp6oHtxdZUSWyXxfw7A6gySSkAqxUeKDnE8osL@P6i6FoNWo7s7om8Xr3PaC77HPJDRxNYAXUEBLOZc9k5lFBn8zIo/b6LZCS99G9qy3STs9xp7qwAWkwP0FxM1FZpENqexycDWcnDdi97uyvurg5DyDhSs43CguguSaG2ba7ivA446QX4meHcGgPwy3gCm@2QLLdj7EXRzk67C1RmoqHuqM8HJkFF32BlWraNE3slwKVM/LkCsxWW6/dgL9McgDJf6dSxmD7fM@ghBeD4cjFPAo6bDw1iwXwqMbyUprtNOD9Jg8dzKLWwKOY3Ynlqh6qW08iS6bsWT493WI0cpywU@@5SQyAeDKdrhhu5gV7FTxBJBpL62Ip@j76ddO5YqoXJRJTvcVqrHSSdx3YIDkHvirdDf9hnHyjHRJL/lDpBcgoxdUhPYS5Lq7X4j5F6yNZNeGc1swwG0h1nfKDWQk5wUNjcV/jIpsN5GhQv5J@Os2lKBVc8HSz0NUagNFAMyYtrsFI9xCqdq20BI3b0VBdGucMlSF3M68nWaigcExXUqu9R94vpGZbop/ZldzEg2rqSQMUc5M4bRhW8cBsZxnF2PJYEGRNMEiCbjGBvwAQDPhzchPa1dBjeGFzK0HiEjrquHdVQXQv9AX2smVP5FXtJhdGuo/RJ2ri1TTVYkUdReMqd/CsWsgtXSGINDiBK4xduSEpNHHqjX@JN80eCTMia8Z6GnmdScSWYX@FVvmuFh54EY027EBMpJsyAat4QacvkFQjbFRojVEx61fG4zk4AFJLD4gQOAAYPvfMhztWgSiVo7bggjEzTE6gkQ6YtYtZdQC3@9bs5xj46KvtpV/J7IAF4c1Jx6wkoLuZVayFsjM/ASL27U7S2jCkNiYhzdoSE52X4Fo6uU/N7FC3cMkpu9B5wYqglohjyS20B6mPLvbYGexPescwTjZdaJETdmNuF7RrAotP2Ny1qKrDSYLGZARS1kChqENz4GzvZRbN/ae6atFDU7bZSAuaelEFvv16YPfS2D@qGg1EccSJ09NLFfkVtW6GQfFN0JnYY1U7px/6tTt4zVwvB6ZqgnaCPRzEM0bTCaRo/K3SGazN7@Papeq@FpMUd5AF@NBMF1hSjtjvS@OumeLmFnNcCmiZYIRv5CCI7p0GtUDlRYnt0Yn1h3bWsayfUmnpZapxQrJ0DR4LwFTL3TCN3pGkUMnOcvdxt2bOPE2AEGxQzjdgH1bazc2SFRY2geYcb9wZiUbpwzBHqPOuvHXVqzkzlM8ZodWMMqxiI0W/tqV7yrgA053uWJEwxDKdI441@oLiMJZ4foGjCIxhHFeJQf7@KgFKFFEuSop4PPRYNt84merSnWo3WjXQPzLThr4uQE4@SEgzsRpV2Z5@DMYgj4WBwOzEiTEg8uwZIcCQYA@Z444IknhWBYWpZAxN4E7vwfRH6vsOt3I2Ds8Z1jxyDk88sZHvolLqAfni6scsch/0VQJFIbPU3LFFaqR5YMVgxAO9SBfbdTQmiGb75lrRRDAitBXiiG7KIz3s6iDoihKrCBjTWhAAHLvFkco0bc0jEVfIogBkZi8mo8S/dcaRVgkQD6qZ@0yNWRB2cQYuqSlxJN2aGkKyLepWl1qxiQw3TvQSJifqvBGwCdTilESFcEKklBu5Sx2zv@cCk9DPZjVA1XIh3WBuNIyGik8A5k2JU2iadUEbGNQZOtuTkbGWjYkTp@i5x6J96y6nEUE@gQZJsKru3hgxeEpjk1@WGsECz0ZDgdZNGQ7AlbensRAYlUptzPhCpMygMkeQXVeykotZEcl4J6nbZJVnyUdFgXm6FyrI/EzbVqvxYA3UVo4bXhnJVDeuNdIMfEvEvdWc4LguK16zWqN0mIKIp00RA8tplQOaMnEMMGDucLc0MENoqoGx4Fdi7PQ8VgVqwt7nenaJ9sX8NLTM1@A0tu9jWM1@gj5UQ@CNyeKOclXouV2jN3EJqtuPKoPWado1wz@AK4iPZ77FY0zgoN3QptbrQxOtWmxhlgvhnbNFiaBLG2iQDVkEFBzjo2S8X2dsJYSRz6YsKPg4NezUsQ8BIFf6wQR5sY/ULYmivzxgNSQp0sgyuoHdNd@ySZZy4ZxrntedydB7t0j6LWa2gY2d6amHvskZPhQK436Yv@QjHJfgcw8NvGJuT4E4JVs0jCeqVxEWJIDgBwELKcjXVDgnoRWDntwEmLvK1fvfk1x02aonzgL8CALGo3XRctQXsggRrsxO2lWbicvVUO9MtPPgt1sUoyqX3vfG5NskdkvfDe6N0EIGBfiJJmlafBPkDKX3Huwk47UPknRReyWLscUTqtUVOFs6mR9rHag4fpxvPsvSEw91NvO0KbqWBE3E8mjGvJuZSsBxy69RtMY9ZV60SMGdzEm408POokVEZaNINaASOgdKdDzFGZuUwxMeIvSb4naTQXLmV2YrR71LqQF0fqxGcwLU@@711DkUKpG/eqKm47/rZkiWYVZg84OJm2Z4A3nLwy0/W9OCCoWR@1YMtaoKYxlxLvPNGKkWEAyKYUysJ9@5DVPCIcUWD8nTnnFlTrAj0PNMf86RFiEP3XxWF2tGiGsGbFG1CbssOgwpk4eNa2oaubzFGzMvqBxji3F60hA4GiNFHWp1UJrr7EApsTYGKWIx0b4B2y8QJCP5Y7qivFbdwHqDmOYneEWf1lyiMGnWIzsktGrydWkmeLMhK8DQTAkZkTQxl4g8QEC4ZFqnit9kZrmyH03DdiazJseM53dZmCbojQ2ZzBjruktorZQKMjEBCGURZQOMJEJKm7EdXvVzYWb2yYeChu6x68aHSNERXNuLcsIcr0d7LOR0d5xFhWcnBk@58ahu9OwVNS3PMq0VFrJZ/WqXL5@gj/DjgxZrPhkysh6jGgiXfLeSw2@1WKjTr3V6hesWn2u@m51J1ppSQQCquej0NARu04FXiQCZToI0gQQswWLjFK@37mYF9/s@gQolbUembC5Z4mzyyZTOZNiSrY/W56AVuO9685cORKZSzdj/RiRISWqhSxYz8uGSt8fiO0lG6JpoURQ07I6sSfyuxSMf47Ifi35ly6K1w/v13hvpSsb3sxrqDnSxpuupoZMlarqRKO5WvrF/WQWncAKULQVLn5Fu4FxQpisSP9R/yLmFiiZqzt2LrceBH4NQj587FIcJ/sIqQxb5kh5lt0bJGkzkzgADWND@oqXdwmRxgD4UZl3DtMiMpgbi68jpNpL5/Ysd9HGEFtWFqSFo1lBPMQfqucUuYucuDmljD3yUD6mB9CM1qB7PXryTMYPGi0IKS3NB4sFWnRzoYNXkKuaQ1BrZKJs8VmC7RXKrotPU6Gy55G2WNJlXNAwBhceDseSqdBkkJjhbpIl90oxJuoDTwQ1wBeq7CGxnpodZkNG4OWrhvJOvBv6kHMEN2B5WU2VJlOe6vcGNdvo8JrwJuioDMSZz8ZznjH6RGSN/MIOoiaO7ACwEwN8KDgfPRUqaHIm8lHZ@QajssASShVguQNjst@KHernRBe7QraqqpCZEBBSYaoARSzHryRgzX@CTG7E4LXaieDgYWbljN0kGx3I/F4GFocEO4W4elVVEZKlLJ1jHqgnJ0BaayI40N2gmuy13zy8Q8zYVNkldr0m4qAFBBEaEon0yjHPSOA5GupoHwyvBnYgjXa1uWt6a2oOWWkhQNIPGk0JnpLDNII65CH4PYn1I1zNROsihKLv3SIlmTAbPjzZcl/hC43pD@4ZsAhHhKm39sqzMsKxJR9IQojF0QQ0/b6iCmFA6XGLPx6qpJsY1mo2LTk8wrPWYSzcFGV3tGvMW88Qeq683yL0HGbFL0YCewriPeTSyeg80sYaEAeBkUauNYdDT6TFmeH@vxnSwuqok72vWB0/0ogSDHDd3QCiKiLMdTLUojwy4Ioe9IoTpNzuutnJN5AQ1EmMryt7h5iA02GndamfP5XH7S4Li423ADsOysuN@/5S5PNX1E1CXfLU3562vli0hlKxKHHczWZ51IrkW02SYjckyjPkcsWz45eFu8vgms68a51mRZFt00/bh46lgQbpPTT5g1nldEJCYnh7CCAJWWedjp1EmOTGlY70gpN8M46I8QVpz1xANlF5C/n5D0IwC1PHT1cE/JZyU1sVen8YluIG4i9CaTj0ce6O2S6k@dBYYv0t6hrql2ggiAF3mRz6WHFygd0NFA4J7Pateq3IJ1dbdU13J6e4Bk1bi9CnSQCWCJdoZb4EXE0XcVii00CH6ADsZWc5F4gCC@FaKM1OIrjuMLksPZoOwEozoT8JhGf0Lc7IsLG9hyy4nE6gLVo9PaAtNBt8asfoOPPSWcnRbl4Tosyf21W0tiLYbh93cu@QOR0S5EHFs4dzwTUG/PKud08lYo8jAgsFFtVAv6ejs7scVMss3MCuyzg5SfLqTbrTXogfi/miFFr6/ApK8QzSdTm61FVez1LCsE1E1pu2kCYU5cEjgHcJDtq9HNYCXaOqDcB8G43YiSGeYtRD9nfkCah8YOPPTaspxSHRsKCzuP0uXgXqUQgY9Z2Gu7DKTrdmSkAeZ7sgALekVNKoYy8NDb23RSJe6ecJcajeSp1zVzQPEcxra2rFBWi6aHw4pE5s06qKJXQihHYrpZWSUT1M5Ye/TOcgXRZUFCONkY@60RDIsLgarYORCsKNTkiwKB4Tgof9w6jjjfVvDncEA3iZKoVGHuR54MIEqXdnxDuzxDIe3ufZbUW9jeej0aKsv1C3qdPU@GDSMezwd/YGGBJN6S4KEhZZPu8U9tJKpVJGATbZiED852vabI5vZF0us@qRme5eFh7a0jQlqu4kR73rab6qhVLUWj/VuVT6hitbAcD9U8pbKzuCpYwxlkbluRRicAiyoFkmvR8kD7cwj2Xh0q0u/iuuBeGWjvTFEZehUOh2c/I71haZnxDJNUIafSBKOfln9vjudt3cHJTYsdmia7lwvMylLBfS@FObtIXbwq@gyJ@RT91eajgTZ2rxqvi90IB9Xx8bGesLWPnWrspvpBviUbrCJOkvCEyRSMvrWDqgWL4qjS1iK6FWR0XgYJN1HeGc7fX0HXIMmPF@wHM3aJNqDw81w0/OBESjRKKm3N2l5duhrlioeTD4jNEMkglYtBwhA3pUKcFkB3QB/JzOZzD8dnfXo4DuEQCi1mdHjCsCIjQfHogxQQAhPGEn7OqDhNeivE@W/7Bym31lNkpOQ07@dilWWx4NALxs1mGMLvcdp7RtkyKTWeSmWKa8XjnZe8lNdJ2Sl1dBtk9E9sGcoZT@Y9WkSn6z/WFHqEb2T7zLUEVqMnAK5ljMh@niKTVoX1cdbmqbRwFHqoAw6k8V4ljsDsM9Fq1d6@BwQC1Q109CiSBnJWmpoBgU2voFMNSehGtEJRTlyw@ymXALymyb70ki4tKizHuP6ZdwzxOOLBnaSXFs3XGrS60iUqpIjilRhLoSJaD88hqh09c/AZFt37UDFOg3cAYbgeK81NCes0q0aZxWP/opuUizeZNCCZ1uVKJbhl3Rq8TM8OjLUmtk0PPCGCfXMQqrLskpvZ3/mxNpvcpRy1k42PiIMqV24m@mKWUjGoeNjmtOTYD8fjfsovHv@hHP6BL4XMrAdOa2dnO2ZQEeUIbeDYmhgJpi/H03eCmvYveMFt2EinU3DyoonuRtp0JxY5lh0vqOLWY2wNT5qHmV15BXF0jKjInMfIlK3hde@O93SP2KzyrpocMYWGFPNUbAxZYOaN4hyMb82fZjAmFHYpVo9fGArByV3xyYthSbyVjfSPTPzkR5ity7DyVdTg8ZqRGenw1gY1gaOZWnaY4ZA5bY0WZytceEMQ7zYqNZkvUFkNAShr6yMOMwHStqVDCVCIoYF0@QIiGiobg3xepfAI83CHgF6fs995wQjQYY0Q1C5XEZKsifYK1yXbhLBd6LI@@jTwysQeLisEhbjzicb/fRYGxP5lx2mu@N1Ep/Jk8hk4qMZeKE3gfhYn9Tpdv5ZF8brYB/tFwvic5gAVo06L0as@mCOXBrkVQbTsMsTNWAm3fzhs7HaWhEC5KBLU1UYSnQt2yvn4UCktpF6zkCLKN0Hkzp6Bm@dyjOzGS2kkThk6L8B@ztitgGzPvWgm4zZ54y78Pan9ODfFmQLmf@F24bHffOWiysBypQ6dSI5ecdW3bpNzfCh@5yVQOqx8ZJZ5AJ3dwR4LzsJDjgVDImuS/UcRfDdum5l12w92OnBXDJh0bRpDH1yZiDvEtiGVUZ3aBgMuqDCY0ySrzlWyolJEzhWLYZFLbs6AdgxE61JM3gqqtYVT7PHal9NBfak4bOTsZ5cA7C5x5UIt0DTLrrTA3WGSVB1BXnM32yzUt0OaVxPRTRkYfmJEtGQVSe0AbmlqEwaLjHStN4vrZWz6TuEEDTI13Ua5nTPcLqcz7Qv2q2VrvGS7vhIWyEr3WSr3RkzVQrXUNGsNC@cJFnF8iwLLWERuApH0Lo1KWNJJjeOAgtUyViHR50VD7GY8BzJ6OexaYT1EqbHFZOuiiZWln1BVaQSozCvXgxDK3H/pFKDFtGx@0DoYH1ymjYObRxvL51FRyjZykigA9RkmlZbSTqKk4XCnK/sAFvQJ4vtO7E7elzGDRX@gdA6Loo3eb0SunpD0MkQMTOLK2yTg3y0uXpxJOuX7EgmQY9EkGx/B8EixKodNYZO3xIsfKbDyTCSZUz@lOz4flZbYsDKiM0yuOlooCoTu6gN7C3pT9TM0dyvimRvLE6VoJAxy2uWAezYyaJujdlBHpfpQOHY2luoV2u8kPQDJRnaanGAP9MYck/3PDkMUHdzh3Q/qGlF6o4fN4Fc45fE2JuBWpEiQqnmWxrgrebPKcmMSE@4eY32SV/DVL1KutjGp0o2GdvVLj0QcenIhTh3ZX6@THzGzyhzQgfRzZocSPx07gB4kGm7QdBczbD7yr1a5bNvmL3mjuSQJXFzs5Yd3zKpk6thcLsko2e@KqvNLTRMIh2V3zFvtNqO3E2U0GKjFg06xMVexI71gA3lBlvRJeZkZvoP89zo9ZVxY9FlZQ@e@qidPRKsSJaWFi0fH4TqRH/cMgmoYe4jYAgoNvEJ2M3ZZj3pvS7pgeZ5muXHDfqxxs/jEj4LmTP9PkvN4bQwlZXpg7pgdj7ZXQwXYQBaCnrJAwthd36mjciPmFxSPZ67uTTNUAJaybFHO/ywWm28I/Tb0OxaYWoAUhr3jEiSzM2uMRNbmILcMqn1o@HyktWh3y0lj9KtPzWkqx78RygK@V2sQWn8FEQiZw55TYtcNQB@1ViQpx5ZsqibSW4fVw9686HDrhXvWN9fmzQpCXEDaCFmWyCOZM1NGSAtIewiv3wU6zvoUKMEkrxkKW@GGkjpGCkg@kArtjGsOhzUvjx9VRhtp3efXYYB9LqcjKbyQca0akQa0o2iQ1H2wsGdjIVKGKcsW50j5LFMV3nuVHFfLm62gSWU/Sy66MlWz9HBwz4mOnNRLwAIHNkYYyt@OPJG48fOn1L/1cdH@vbc3cGJaNIEFdE/yYoxwB4CMUSCEIPWZ9msC3hkV0FU0NXKwGOrlUASNjXSkw/h0ZatVNJIHo8mRoeZCWk4s5IZCOTDLl9Ak5mwVp/cNGZkahcIgGxx1iPg3wzmWQg8nJ7wSfAKv@7EvbRP2ovZsMCMB1bpx3OgFGfp8kCGAEAMqdloq6HedwDzwR9Vol1hZjrGrfG6v85mBvvyquaGdTo0IXFeJGEZwCtwCtJ9eTdwhXqz7Lw7TQqHMOqWXzsACeA@p01QrYKbsRIXircNz3I6spACUuJtoSkIOJmQNeLCh3VwA1tXd3SFrTcPKRlpArVQLTiAI0rmPJ@XW0Lsu@np8HOQwAxNGRl5GV0wruSFFtP/CWySJZ9xTUjL@YM2pmXUgh3ubp/tzC1zsNwza8CVxPCQ6imAg262TyrGoQ2DoVT@NMPAHlsNZDt7gWR4DHyD55ULvqh6bi1rWqFlsux5nAKz0Q/xot8esrGvU3MGR7bvxqemwvmxrKxVRO2bGCotVO7FPswHL6oDYqLmEG3BGijc1S8sW6BveA4Idps/WmJ2l4/1LALBOmoAlIzn1lHIm5wlDvCR4UYmuXWZpgDnnBmqDsOUxFx0uhtVDWWZFpjf83wkPSLbAYk2TXKxriCFyX6YwxvNNrEVBWpL457GqHitU1KQUUkWYkhZDqSAMLI1fZebx5bBOdISlyJRuQn1fVoS1XJQfd7Sd2I7I7mRuPmdJvkbHoAoWW1oR1nucswJ3XRygpmo509xGp2k0q@6YcrNPDQYTdWxrsxzGZGHHhstmn1fm9k4GW557ze5ZX8b9BIKNmuP0ZdCQVmlWNPRqTAj@cPpiVwejELAb1s1MZqGb0aQrcInESI48NE49EB9sSVrvtw1i@Vu3YZ5PNsDB5YsGLb3ZS@2HlAjvILkr6d3Tf/KVnMX5tIYP4PWbGMFPNwiXQH6a48JQB7uxVSHiU@sxOWlQ2@70H/da34ZijCO3oSNNIZXFqgXWyjFw3fNk@37tU6CVmM6CQtuP5kHVKxldS4IuRsYCKmuo47s54ljqMjtzP8nzZo1b77colk3bRvasfOx9cGEBnQiNi3PmELSMTtdydlswBUR3wyETsu52VgjSZJpVXcFyS8XKmfzhbcUWKfLPgfTuLJMYwBj0YxqV9MwdOncaFT6jcJmMg8vLr/HcU5D/jEeXucArPQDLORlyUE9q05ObRDQ@mS2XUiDZ75MZ4/9ABm0vLv0wtrQUjLt43HTaDmtmlzMtOZcR1tz2pLXXo3YLA3uv2lUVSmlrOOB8ptIYxnKZGj5MLgsMZ@TbLQRxqhDMJ6097N5OweoLYR@I7HbFzBgLps4fxnBxI0fxCBZUVtWMXVjvFEMeUBEeHYymgB/AHc6zEkQTAac1ENzrfbVs81WoweQj07InqBS@BW6jot3lkDeNPBmXW44Cffiie5btfRccVmKlXXI3x2blBY88IY214GBIesYM5boLNiEWVfk/k7U8BWseUh9rQPVisjwkOsOy1dx0s9@I22n4cdzIWZRcbl@pLBl0Q3qvXmNlJOlEC7pmILM4ZQYwEO@NepdgtbnVnawqL5Eg4jnUkhzItaF7cR3t9Z7/8spKt9UlYojonJ0xtQDqFh2x@@5naeTyfCHfHDkasLiftytjlrAYcx7MjTopCUgfDsv29aLG@2qPLN60peODUOpqPk@/C4AqlEv6e7gC3azdjD42BfdrKA4hCgcyq/rYwciFMGK925jBF8H0ENmiO4HNTD3k@YhSVv0XYr92kyci81wSTTRgSjPJ11Dd666hcrGuOazUmYbly1rgi1mGFow@amJlxQNpW5DkA0JhuIhHtsVfrVcbB5CkAEx6bkB0/m5RWxsKgF9XhBvOXI2n2vuW908sAHitzMGn4@xxPKfMxZjJuSADCibDLa7@tLD8oPRV7E4Uw2eZrMUfreytR0x43nOXYDZeAG1KeuLde3NhUypDUmOF8kAZTaE/thP0mZka30i1tmmr6IMMwIqOpvLExY6YvIFj7nqrLawNo8u1jIpXU3b5mG62xXRiMvq@Iim1PBIZRTWafBJcFDByT5k4jzu5Bd2WK6WGKRnk5FwTwfmaI2AswjHYhxue5Vmmapm7y1zZm0wWz21S9iMDyf3ia58N3ffYp@aLi1sxxg1HetNaArr09DT5nypG2IzgT4wkRMeCTW/WW9HKsMRMsr8x6/D3ETN5z18f/deQTZjbX@NA8tK9wAtWr7PuGVYCxgvhV47skMWbHgPZLM6usUzwdYb4zcx2psczI6nXbVYOMpq@PCG5TXUCerMKq1jw@hFEAkOVEJPNZFjYnt@tHx4HPFgYwSQ72ihCWm9bTcL0PQmftIhWyVmezLJVQEwnyvoT5rMDniPiQ1kWKEAggdqtb5udSFX8u29VdT9WBQNPfbVstlGig03AOd2em1JsuD7wBmk0tONLhTiNDSaqPLlefVEu/qwcTrQ2dgPuAG8HshNCeUGxHTB14Ev3Xd74GFbbCAQw0DrDrtGsoxhgF7odwyaldIALp/9nJNae7GZ59Hbya5fF@taqaIxAJVOes1A9OADFvwJstMb27I8w@KfbFO7Wj/SS6@02LIqnG7QwVx2C5S71GNRU5WV80CD7UPYLNIc3O0Z7YtuXJ/b02bAF/T@7LZ7kpFYVsVuHQ1soiACHGABEnngu9OYb@OW0Q7XjQYCiw96rITm7qJhP2jKacSGIGOSTFgjuS/zEhKOKYrpwXEsAZmxLLG46sw8ajF2wvDHMgBMZcy1Tqlgt8ymTnWVuWibd@JtY4/4dI8rzXQroQ@xyMbHfYAKGA8/00zamKn3G5WRn1s5JjHt1KlAzj8@SXQX9DWSYbyTup0Dax2VRuIfc8/HhAaPto/TSfdIeJkm12jjTXZxtQ1SlkTh6JYGRTrItqE5nUIHXZVksNUkjx62lqZxAMp1n1GVbxuRZSGqnm4NdiKoFAbxfJmGexUPPALbnhESq8NqE6yEMY9ttVXcr55/Mirk3oqA9yNdVOdhR4eqkLGqbYTXBZJQfHxxA4scEQ@1qDhd2mTTO4qwsvlYoldkEY9oPWDyfMYsVAuTiXMr9yQ846GbbN@3u54W0VOr1N0GOsOSHTM@KAuOQmouuPDZ3fMWSFBB2y5brgbOtBdSWMJzyXSAgTeVqw5RjkUnrhYnJBMYTcb4yfC4AgRvmZgOZrVSqjzwlAdi/3tWsoIxgvUDHJ8DHsjDowsXwQXvm3zkmI/li1v4IjpY@q5DUnQ8KtfJX7I9dLCxAYK6D6/WbjXa/bCkBFHIsDpCo9WsP7u1L3us2lNk6wvpiURSRfPtaBMd5r7rlcefUm4OgmAch@nrgjS53w5QTyanDS@eJEj77guRNE9Qd5V6shKTW@Q68TUap5dRX6pfLts6z15MXs/eANHUs8n7sIzbY@V2MJ7VS972q806u24tiH5SaAlWsyHBKjdRnQpTEpxxqCwDogy5snvgN9CnPBS5YtVFFB4t70P3rmOY1qG@BZLyrOB8gU2qDSTDZLJdCphNsOCjtRMdLYuoWJJJyqVLQkSUCo21lkX5ncn56bBJLKq0PXmGvJFZC6oXCrVHCX8hRdeP0wOKRknPMNskRgJiz83Jc4u7dyY0tp5bliFVvDEgPz1IIM/jTGpPwBBNGJ8UfOptH5Sq@WPZsgpuch4P7KP69EAlK1AU8zgprlvwZHnRBzhWOYjRDdo71T/b0fgZFn0/QJuzpywX9km@eudPbVymXZqtu4WZtQxFx6FoGcafFFRPpuCdNqLP7p2MIpkiTqMqOYo4GUu6tRc9O@/AiT9Z3h0wUrIRVe42zDGYtUmALjvVVHutQ5DdvfdhHj@cj2jIvEZb7kWVu4uaTaCWG3sn7lq1wh3P7uR@71kUfMNy4zm8AATNsYvuzSIOZNFwk3LxmPeTCn6ypCSfUsRRH1btHpDOgZ7Y7t6wJLcZohu26SPHKQTxujgjNH8ah6Gn/u80qeI03B9lzQLXndYAQKKziIUvibwW5tHFJJoMIeZdSE34QwvsYLbq2RD6wPKGcj8C0NfQHAprY3VjKiOcAnSmwo3g4J/t9sySCFk8GARujlfg6XUm45OGlcQLqOBSbu5chqTX2qXkEac9oBJLZB2NKxnYiUXeOS497gzj@GldQYQjs1GNByOBYPMONN0Z1lxeyRPF7ucyX87HGkenydFSsEFjDBFx2YBqmp1@VFB7BvEK1U9btTJ0H@mTH1ejZxaog0JRH5OIqRF5Nqhi2uK6QHoQVIFD6DlSD3buQ4UodoQFXqKfXBzFSrnVmgtFeNKNPQIsuJcEbJKORFyzPdDTuq0JPOFqorAptcvs@maYk4@hKl1B9212QkWW3ozBWvQ7E3pOYWWMpHVlVl2O3BgkltZ8L9dF1XQJPk71s1GvG2MIyjW6uEg7EcYtNWK4ktGiFeJN9clq8q@NjiVp3q2mayB5UROltAtN2CiNEx3P@mAVhnPKej65EU6sb@bxQj2I1oKdHSiU7BGLzzhcJJslNc1VKCgPPdYuXxX@YBY2kHQ3SEthcc1DnHjkDiJbtzN2htjbTjjX99hKrB7CDjNStFZrvVqljeFk1d7s6Js/d0k60@VE3czszGfczBzwAC1o4tbFuJPDu0K/ncqZLMpfmOQMJs5TdD4VrN7rRzUzLxs3MSwpHf1J@b23mHGdGYVPvIelV8wzySyz3p1uIz2XjZC02uajcnPOYzwcjeecLkky5VRVDNJAVV9HT7u12OymYUG@6Wo2yaPX4jMP@oYNa@aE4NO04ObTL@XpbAH@GcrZFvI@BMtsYljGovAaLoLo2fd0sqnmNRc7CICpW7FQ3CsSoh/OzJan75bzo0EjjyoMiTgKtVGK5yMGxL9bnGlH6Z8QpXle@qJdk5OOS4in0zlf4f@0imTIQgNWj1zQdpu0RWBZ5aJyn9pxqsNeuNVLU1TB/l5Kd2P@I9tReT@x@rZiPPq5W63K3gPPkbd0U7Qfip0cAiNAF@B1RbypOKayNBQWTeQizb4h6kajmprII5pKcznTooVFv/dw2qq8oIezVDucdEv1f7IA6bTqj/9fViO/G6UUGrKU99KEyxYdPqmQJeKsmlM/yx@VgiqQDtyRILvqcRaRx2waGbhsxGAUnzKew@Dqc7UYkGPyc46rUAqJuoXqfXnoydgHAQtTY@ACbYcSYPx24DBEpt4ix0UCXI@wWgZ4BwJ629EW98FxIo6MNaFmVNU/zscJIYgfpifaJ3tKqq@ChdrjHmjNfvZ7EQ33vTMEhi7YPkCnAoQ/OjMYjXSqjnr8GYo9n8QxaWixx/pniDDZWYulN8EdUNsj95GYySwgykblhrsmI6PqcVFrn8b5QxOVyVTvjBrStLiKRi9RvDRkgnw2eWuoKVUs2PVQw2Suy/70uyU985mHhjW7Od9SrkDKXd4H08J2PFDCq8aRrrKrNU2VBIh4HXo1bkbkS/iuubVoaEyINFeD403kSU5vH86VApyk2xA78udnc7jpxfV1ySfsM2tR7k80u8tzM@OWcRguNAYyOCxMx8UFx6UZw0AH1bP4hZb5Et1iLJh65uLXfosZIrobFazmLRY7DoU4fZNq/eSCjOwOead17P1c0tWXF7aJ/N/1@MoXPC3yprw@@fIWlDQM8owcsTAJe0SnqBdVX8xhXfRD2ZMNDxxQgsO6XPP/hffOkUrc3T9SQ4hSJl1NHT2mdWcr1OOs2MpdCh7lBfqHXQ0FacWooW6sSMwRnQ1CwJ9YpuyRwjFkcDel1Ru9GFo@JhfOI/BviBoqKUeUsyot7CimhDkXaYPtw9w3sVeFxhGgBCasUiLCTP5o5PvsP5rRIS7dvcbmiQv/5DuS7F5JpjYcl6rtRvE@E83fUC4AUViaVingDA3zukZKFU3aLqfT1Z0@6pEMm493CsflvGjQW/DgkytesEACUDLt0WGfkyqdB6Uj02LNk58WtH3nEaNFTTHBTijq2HUjhD1ErMLeNTpllrutGMdVnvg4LqNAwkf7VO0spscuAAzbPBVPzcZx31T941IqkYGQWEQDshp78FjUy/CfZWMuXU51BLOkgRDd9KZilxTUjNzvpgk53CE6Gk5UiPP5JDQN1JdWZ6CeIteatMA66i7N5s/LWrzmt8X@WK4@1rigPTvA7NMVEJ9NKZvPSJlbxa0sAPEs9qrIZljdsFlzwjK@HxOyIpkh40f3PVrZrrJqe3ouvQCmwUKKPvRgYy/bV@di00G3sSum6gWERMdb5EHEvqhROUwVhaFkCEyrhKlPkcBCRM9NAVU/lAKh0Sk4JOE@rmQjK7RLU2C7D6GBQH9vKqG3zXe3QFdRo8V0@GN@gP6Ikui17n55KLSYo7voKA/AKRPD42TNymHf00tNBuoQFK2BL48HYMntCauOj0tVONq/5R50L/eWM2zk3ZLK6Bi4z73yzfI9WkWenK12TUd3AKjTRC4bTuy1Q1vMivx7fS70kJCwqyaQN3cZzaLfxSavFNdQmGmmi2PcSU30GMony6Zm2KKdSDLt0@E56so2eIHALCo44@xIstctoGAkQO1GZagpeyQlashGVFON0Si0dnRMZN61apbUUS0eIHaNPFSynVzeC7IcbQEg2asbDRj6Y/GIK2lqtn9ETcYjUL@mYv0ZoHtVyrkN@laF9rp/YRiwlOldN9Dz4ySQStksrz9C8LIMO8l1K2agtkS1zoCs6ggsoDQF4Y6uGan67k52UFJrWWSFrZXcdlMFmVUHzXYj1g9bj4aBXSsFvqDIPOKU9Z5VRIdyWG6xudN77Kz2RAhVxgb6WDDb6HkgBlsfq1vROsv2j0bKstyKSV7QIq9QYTvjGUD4pyiKUf1WLCzg/i5yk9I1az0mRdlDIzqzxwfgk/X4vgkTeEip9kgPvbJxJPir2aHlwH4NV4owQWYRuI1I@auH/VsHgNl0Mr7FCrHdejMtMW1MJLoLv7Bi4cWhGXixPnYx1qAdsT6G7EhFVMr@npzYMNOP@Wjib0ZnhL3b0XWxCVW2lMOl1QkDqVtl0qlFsmd9SMMzsuyQfuL7TSSOm9Z0DOOGkwWrOJXj3nF8zSWhWejf2goeW4ehvdknA@KBOTDtvokFSMGWMNnQIdlcOA/bbAqSbFjQemiO2GZXnybJ9k3JsktBdqe24DZPACnTk0hg/s3Eb2nxL1jTNVS8Ywx/4NcF7Ymu3lg3BLRbZMCqr1kvx@51MMwu9AQ2iM@aWeng4jpqLbaLFeZyeV8iTWHlpKDjdelid7hTNhdT2ANeXDpYJQ3RoqK2IoedGrqN3gvK6wAXEn1sYS5tumrvZfvLgHS2N9XzSAANS4IFPYT2TnDYMFacDYTe0jawDslkdJcO67gM21rrDQZX3iw6X29AY@KuRCndbMmq@VsB/RUPtzp5Szdmq1fmod3GCvQ0JS9AU2Ua9JyQO5qqsaiIj1@e/ddD9wb/KI8/Iuk@wipUpH0enbl96yrwbQ1YoBELPLDmTcKtoZ6R7Yu@o86aR1c7VeBsjDKKpNFWwWdWdJlpc9dm26XHWgvdPQbbuQYphz90wXIm/Zy1LPZFr@cMyAsGLgNAtNF7CfxsoCLm7UV02tQYJVleZn9eM6rL81ZP2PcuPG3bhlfprHYKtulNU2EzYK4ukFloCsgqheHBsKvLiUQoFx4vFCMNYl8cFw7k4wOpPGyOi39WQnygpjuL2QpZ8UA1K23Vgpm@1W4YFW5fR0rrWbaOLqYFxMy0XIMkmez6q3XjTD3BW4fZiJtM4/xVtlw0ojembcfiYbnoMKSyRFc0/JBcPJlyJuBXTfCKRTg2msx2vAP8VbYsElwbU2ULct0o4lldQDpf9Ko4sNKxGrEcYSqeJEhAapGpYHfwoNRc7PJTPG55jL4dShPcMhV9YxLOcugXtenqB3IU7hdchimcURilI1fPnhakB37s8SOdFFtdlA/twmze5qpmA7spLgPQRkMjGA529dqdgeZubOEgawgTLYfsBYEeslYMtayK2iSLsezRW20oMjUnSvgUFooaesA44cjecboeO0LjDfMqENGh/Jxgmp/afz62tC4X8nVBQ@4GXaR/Y1KwCkQLERknwvcNIbbdPvOGzrcebuCcGcZOOVw2EzHbY6a6w@o89qc10vSRj8GY2vzWLUrlmlyJDlYxxtVcT8QgZMOPIMpCM3gzYFjN/eggm1d5Oc42zIBRybaET4Rn28REKpRJZQtAzJhbotmcOrw64x2L5LNM@EjnuLWOs1zMw@ZtWLTW7psBq8XsoB8i1BE@xboQNW0B4is96um4/Gg1NPuEMjkcuKe73dKTB4DUq4sG9EgGkLgnvRP6hxohUfE09ecLgt@SZVKpIAoWYc9qHRmI8wHtoWGOUbrm0TDNhuU8GjlqY8jQDs1AHdIzqXgmjBcwPY1j0Qaals4cKpwao9IQu0kaIRukB1Rd@LtxCZcl/HXz0WdK1jKR5zAIgOf41Rx9Has5tfnZJZ3K6fphvWfN0R8cHjMYVacSG7RycDf7xcEVupmBQofLPeYmaRsE1xn/jkPn0iE/EQUk8GdomfmIsDzI2afhnFj0T5kRadssS5WFlls7kUYWntaoeKY3lCwUq9GJDLUmXX2rawvAvliZ485a7O0oaqA1crppurawoqFZp0X7QOsf/ffDb20WCGjrE1ftCOcxJ2lqCzVrCSGOA7dUOGdD655lHaZlEIUdp4QXWMWoCVpA@XiNwMBfmolVnWVq9MWrphsfD2NpCIG758zRaUHzSIOLkUbP/RQMl5GgBQHI2IvHZ8ZQFbM0uyjIayYUDfaUNpHJ5n4ZDywjiSqzsgbC6CglxIHY9QGLgvKBqWeaiWcaMi/m8ILc1LDLrRwyDZezLHOAaRZfs/eYDdLn6fQaX1GJOfhS1EcfSFOqqtM5EKt/iO7J45p9UHd7SUAjmp5u5vKprlFGO0Q3iRnYALXRMlCzZMoc6jQwdbvLDmM8i7ukKKkfDPSjXNouktFSs6Dy8LAjN@tV23a3VwPV0q2eM8bFQkkHdllJRwcc1irj4tnseq6@blcxiU1RvxmmsZIKTnQDCaRh3cj6CWfPITfe7KBauMiZ7kPNaCXFYTeLBpL4Emo0aOGZSNWhm4GcS7d3bEm3kQDaoLIcjRDW7WbkgUTWcV8pc/u6/QQyb2/S3F4QQ83delSEgDkV5tIVEFUiRuV@cTH3852nGZOMYLjEXOThuD4ZFz3gdptp/c02jA8d0Xx0Fw@KPaGGhl15s0potMrpoTAvsGD@tPJC92fNe9AqfQ5GkztvL@AwSBNbVSe2mnrjUq1aw8Gku4esNV4Ll04ybU1skG4arMnyQ@XEeAApp1tVrpoJHfrhb1LQBBuqdH/X@AQoe@hML1cDS1I38wh7ca0xA1Y5OPqlwpygE0voSWQ@IQuQdbAyrI71M7SkaddheQTa17jGpVVrgcasZuMw3nMYIXm5swh0HILIraGU0N1bcHH8UMdMJxRojR/5dhbYDmrPhXOKdyuemuz7qjJlYGEb3f95oeHiLEie2dgO05CpGOxaoX/owFNmI7Rnx7YFZMW@0iHc6nwM3bfd77C6XofzABSg2JnHAN@1TEhxW6Fw0OVqxyU6QW241WFYYYPfqa3w8AWCIB6TjHfeBSto3bJPu@jshmey9J5qUwkO02HXXrN1H5y5S7404cSVNWHW3U2ZQY4YHcdYxg0qBi9mDmYS3@7IAlQ8296nl1u25lk3@zv77huo3d2O3Nk0sOAuaKSAZtKjPm2sfaMLUJpi34WW0KY6jtJD3jD8y3SyPZmvjltGeoeZpcMhH7ghpkoF37Bo2TzH4fxY9XIGj0sZyLJO@9V77jE@WRFXSDGVxVsFsixOOo@hAGbhC8jEsKUnoKiO08mopmFZTKyAPnwex2fmQNKGeyy8GIOrPe2Sqf1S0M7IBPdbOhwvzTLvrpRwR3cHWbNsgSyCMISmR2XqExUeo69FhtVpvi33wDONJnNaG@wCmsbb5uxgEuEsjXyqGG1jGtmX0Jnu7vTEaKmrVdXL6mJwd04hq47IKJc6YmT2iQi@YACXdWKSb9kon9giS6m/5RISYBRbp2eD/bQR7WktpOM@Vspj0c8b0bWUw8MaPcIAsfhbR94IWc9wGsPUN7qMyHGVIz@e3b9jtFIfd8Q4TVU0ppsRpLaau0i2Sjje28NyA4d3tGXgxTO2X7Vt/KRAqpSxH@ooqt192b6Gnq6Ke1R@OX4tvX4cmi@7RJvOFi0yJOqyByYZ3qbdXEu1CLym3YdNnFC1ivhqk/uJJO8wuNK@34MCO8j5atrEMzNFRNXrXBfxeaIHtmihzYOCBHDczWLav//cALHsBxAOi4uxGpojVT3LqMBZ8GNZLncBlLE3cr9o7fXoKRqOqqRkAP1bchornggNX5NHUY9MxI8krEmU9TFZ2abIRL2aPYFXDpIxBcnHkbUYxmvcYDaF68jHb1TU2jwDYHNdXxix@VgD3f7IkyXX@Cb1BGLLKmTHiKxBWn/umYmI0d5cR4VT5ErZoZgz1dT/n@CHHg9xRKppwtCq8S0CVWgWTQid0vy@pC7z7SX8WLI74aVK2zJzwc@0Qpl1wxwDbVSvvzbpnVN/NYP7UPmqVvOitRSnkIFkOd1aR5PqKxQ5xNSJb3xk4ZURuEezQG0WgVeX22ddfcWkrsioFwdepIdOZlYkTRBFW0u2QFOLNI2TOMtglMzXZtiB0gbdTU0aDVYLANinNR39203XlgSlGW9VfPQkLIiYd2fOqv54WEcYRbpDE3W7bfHse6MMRQdkY4LLYt/3qABvycuO97f95KR6tbIp9Aqxt5@biNPs1pnYzt1db4N@TsqdXDw9CFMEqh126kLgqxrv35@LI6RJOjAypGyVrkFEC06@RRuO14w9A45E2HQLZNpopF760KEUKkhTiIjiXivHVcRNhk16ptDMcQlL9946y0@38QKBxRajU9VCsatTS1i3DHcZ5V8U2Hm3wlO/43sxduJZJuKk27vd1g/KV@c80Nct/O5bk8tVkUfyMO2ha6sMc0sas4fc/y2zL1uGVG2GYclTsvgl74Xomck0YyqlnKjktXE8cIzajmmkU4NyzSSSO7qwdhqO4AC8m9t2jc4hLRcseXfi09plni14krSlGkf0EZIoxxSuHnDstH5eEycz47mG1PgUoBwwTwbIe7jfBb2sbIMU/NcqpLSoTvTC6Ha@m/WJh2kt@NjnJ4m282@gy2AmnqnD8RRLRIIHx8DAjB3IG23ShkLkxG2jVmvuGewBFzZ@jwiYhk0NEOzvb4ugYKc9WGPDNleSomZy08XE9ohKk9lQ1iimxbnPsIAfnH03warazQ7zkoxe6t6p04qIhf7H9OADmZK8jCsFwJ2t4BZVSeMbVZ@olbHtsqlquY6zoxWZLGsZJRaDuuJsvxPJI19GzbIigLFoyXQrQ9I0SbelYPoM0y8WdE6HX3fUoaLxM63xBn5DAH4OtoFd0u6xONTlz@Y/xsAPuvmj32P9fBrYtrpcxVJsSoDHDcJvWFY9SIfXebkI6Z4LDT/p8E3Gxovyt5HOVCkl756WFdHIzWwTD9avaWLRsRgzRPKhMi@@4fYHSAkkN8PuW0w67oVgtD1d9iVdkcqLouXLtbooYkpmDEH76OyZ1mF5MlOLBracgqwtoQekpZ1JXGx9J3wcxcKkPaL7MKm2p9SdO1L0NllaCyKd5XGSx7XZ9mtTengI2x02TbP8gM2W@FuIpnrEZkyssYmb7wWh/7EhmvXVlXB3zKBi7GWiLGp2JULzPREQVb/Iez4/hzvJW5gOtvO2bvNUs2dquWdp/UzcnG/t2PQmq5Pp5yMUrlTrhZWelmcPpxCXcQnSLu7zEaePwN7BTRwNvmqxEwtDDRK1hqoB@hRCz6ZL5HxnQAvzz3iKCGucdpq9pIpZXc8n9aky/e7d7n/Z7Ppkq7hh4R@VwcXcduu9pbt8Lsu3GrEiD567sZLwFmOVofAeXkJgJppfY0NEL7NHndLwUTYj3wZesfdvIJpKeisAWtxF2UuVbKphmMWouhTBKcg1gl13e0ki3RbPwkgIpgsht9kuDruTAzjW2SE2SGLVrPUGnNOJ1Z6Zbs33oucMKPDSZHlub/LIczzts4zbKLeQ2CqffIimM8MAwxznKhdWJgbGuEs88FFEOQNFeNpz9cqAkG13cZWOSJFB08vU9COPRN2yyE07eugeuImr63SD1LZ9qhqr7dRtPG@JlPrcIgcabILuMoMqjj4oqGJWBxjuGJMim5MkvrxXkzUE1yHgsfyP7p0saToYuzhCzLAOrnC3DAyi6OpXqkfQKLa86KM6zIWBdLlHhtVdqDPS1vChwepYyJt9Hgw@9L99bBaNPOKydu5Kypo9pfPhWDV@v/DPhmJ2D1ofKx2cFnIzeyXYfN02fIhw27jciCJjE8ugfUFFWWxPdlwIrExt5WNNoTpAxnL3CBd2l02mDcjkLFAx6vStirpqsaqTUt8Kly/68FYW32hf6s5rtBEzGyJljA7wRmsFGwOSj0G@XUPgC@uNFkqVCy38LJs/Z38B3HfrDurwWLd23jLjsduJ1Gyc7MEbqqcDao2lURNS1fnRHBIaZpYEVucBFxWX01PMeKT0MO1RPhDIKi5CBtizaNDiFZ9w5o717NVWJJVjHMOKQf0w7SM3UOiebVjWdICg7BVFj4yyDs/HYh2oHB2XnJwlZALkp9rCoFSEWaToHJUEz3QUS6rZqByZtGijVgSQrXBXJc0U9UqnC5QspOEB9D7qzAdFyEY7MxZW4dCwl8uBB4kG1G7N@jnucF4PytJ4EE9FkmTl9FCWUPnpuTlAjz1JpuXcgUaUDvYNI0vl5Zlmnh038rH7OzzrgvDzMLf5qRfR50z@PRHoDwpaaFtUT0qayeQPj7cC4mlMAptAgx8ZwR4K9Kv3EIT7487jziXVaOZUn/SvH5suVPpzBdByELQyXB2IshW1yUwzYncqhiSz0zGQwCgVnlGzYlfHx6@dPhlDwiNVMc1arY1nan3GYYKd5Beyd3MiSHvO9dzuCRMO1oO/agNIZlM3iwbmdakPB1aMfqLVu0K@xJX3sh5rNO@0v9SaXo935LT2EfPu5JQpshVK3QlzvQiiVAdCrQjfTYswugNq@ZvHbuHcmgmAfrfu5icZroBPgPCYTAUGOBTB/IeqxaVDq8xP3hgdbPFGJm56waw238qXZnMUKfYl6CYqPPPK45KI3tOy2tjGRW/k4EgGfj3PulQfF7ifaGbqjpfH@jVndKpZYj8PLHmWvZeG5VDsmrU8Au0ZQ1EFViD3WcZMy3426B9J/gdRTcCIQQ0miEXENIfHC75ar@xgnLIhhdkeMLFSlYfEEQWwYqDmUdUZaXh9NWHKM0s6Sr9kKaMhtZnZbZroEp1MeA5rnYN2aepgHLFLTE@3uNU8nd7abxRiZHIP7mhiADdkpVDePhpnGT6V19mADitbBOqI8FDdnm9GzeRuS2sNeE/K3LUbl7fyEP8I@QjdDzI8jFCPR6CdOJc83bJz4yJLvAYKJia/LuMgoNNlLYjYtMcFM7W5TYwLA5/MtBWC4T6uZjPO236qkK2fxV4zqaNAEzUVBriAQAmU5gx/qjZVmzfOR3WkSc6ZHBpvHHUuJiT0fvs8BanBXIbT4t1/tV1S9MUQbZMTWxXuNCA8Zklnhdh0tP/yYHCAOWeBq7PZPZa@6PkenFfm8hOn4ciR4OrOYwhqQFeCxHa8exJiP@aJ7gUVCg@RuALfPvJoHjCUhkWPgBz7VcNq/hklaVTY3u9Q8k2mzkeUiFvSreZAn2DzQE1CesDhVWCg6UD5ke0WE1QlSTlTUAHJDwDJNzgZAvB4rov6UPRRFFCGA3sF1VvN6dCppbzvMUOdiVQBA12IdsNW7E62vEaCtuoUVyTf0o6xz5LP8oQrG0kfXd7IpZdR4dUIZwsljHK7W8V2x3i2rFN4i7miYVBehpwYaWuVukqnZDoxL7fGu@mbmupCPcSdOVDXtCoOeiBwyY1RhyqzwNO/OeugW9fs5UMO@1hChivp1hV4JOMbzC0N30cyOt69qW5nFEtfPPZsVFfgpJAFMMBDC3T58tUQCLkpdS6OuMrssCcARhkJfvSBJ7PBnm2tE@djleSgtdcOFb9VTAqtbybptKUovm4R@q5O/FTnmG80EhrxGn4keDBYTdpmQ87pxsoH5i0S4k5jtpPz1@rYOm9H@5YMri@3aILz0IEpNVYwMRx/Phsu2zagcfKgL1uISIknVtQFkREDU6sx7uVgartSDRPh1F0vzf24F4bdT1Y8bSeTVDikM8I3HqYaA9QvsV18fp9DvCQRsjF8KuajMmHurMoLcVFpdbd0WVF2hgdFg4hkqxSvC9mFWAqn3ry2RRVGMK8A0qeNLKCElc9ydOiNmZeaL2PCrDwgGjw2SsZNT@12wQOnO2AAn2gwWdCJzDe85CnvZ/YQ/1gprYupkvstWVc10ylHn1aY4oU8RPW42zctCzwIXCX6ohJXz5dKcdEObZcWSnswPcFAPmp5Js8l2T5IBOTiJKZb4P9Rx2uHkqijBAmqwy4tCFZkmNDLfmBF0I9uUyA9mWpwuJnAEim0dbUFTAb4spj44NCRmNPkad6Rh6YVAXaDMijdhptZxn0vG1p6ioWi0YMwUmUAQx8hcvMofp5bOG1vp3a@sa0ajq/sg6mOFCZ7OUrswk7ZrL5qBWRwMO5Eyf15xAJoLtppZcVp6UnasoIjrtkxgmrLmwTTtkPtwhqyoI/QLaK0jpUpZI0pqOtePL3d8DN51YMoOQqjgYIExZ2mlfYOk77TXaRnuJhNFJ07HWgBjZAI@TGLfsdWkrbW4DLfum1@10iekzzDehzHBaHommDkoEem@YKXjMvfXS81W7dV0zrN1lpcALiu4eEoSEEnHgvE47JGYnuAsqskaILGlCAGVA@fWzJJkz7Hcro2bs/0yoirHHwtVUtuAitC2/DZ8iBtgbZosddhxRRnFJMX2uXVl7kJ6AsNj6YSlLa9lhvGgdEzpvxyo6dTBWu@krtFb/ReOmOyg0vl5k4wHqZENup4s/h7@SRx6HZwkYlwjhn1aFejOdHkyTpZiuU5EQplC532v71QonXBReRjVmt8izJ@mnu6vZWKYSJt1mBO6xDMNAti7x2TgKmOUh/oyhRT17oT5mnC@dEwUs0RENAGPU9VEaP5gdtuIke1WUM8UXOwF3iXZGnACr5w2BjCSNPM@CLqT7TnKr2QZSBNxd@g2Qc3kUGFSkix1y0GqxY3XOCgqrVWMRDZX2JmFyzldr2Ox5Eu8W4rJmckt6cfsj2PFVxRlq0XZlqeMZNKriITjs2cGxhnYDIFiuuPZ3tC/IlDTyM22cxZq8CeTe7ixWS3bLsh5Ub1kTYafLwEw9/1MT1/sBn7qy3Taoyjx50XgJ4lHgaCB0dm0iOzVO4hpZ6ebejXNHlyGUNP6ZIg524ZpcmYYlnE@pasqBpUOm0p@H@FLIdYg5Ek01GI6SPgwQbxs6kSteYQVmHFa9/kr3TbT4QNCG5so7nRazBGcrMSPFjsw@ne9KAzflOVEkO65NtUjxtCP7DKAANUWooJVXP8VMXxNTWCxbmOT/yNSOomJKZ5tyGz035pIqBELZKtkEhuRkfPgKzRCoRhqQ1i/SExHOMalyfx1i50N12Rlm9ck5yYqfy7@RrVWtrlCFZ1uHX12Dpgq9NhBebQVJ5nQsxpMfiFBeCsuqEedLEj0wWDZzDxt1OUxmnThJFy3KOSZfQftlAg7O27XPA2G8bjZCxiB8nJdOkN8uIxE1ilCmqNzRQshjVFx1h3t6d4djDSJcqRMtrGppjWaYhntrMsruoViRPgBAYae2CwL2Vh1NWb2yfJ0dzfPeByFSchjy0tYdO89wqVR/Ok1mhEmudK9JLHJudMrm7lvCsXQb78XGLUrRhlG3LhIT4lJ9sZCMbjJWTn6lIvX4VkszVYg8VzrCPEXkl3a7dfGnQ8FRDu4kJYmpfeGfq1wyusKi0SkxGzIHTSjx11cVI@af5ZDboxCptkrO3SWlrL9GdLWFobPS8jp5mIJ3T8S2S6C@ua4lZtk5F2ct9tTXxhm2ptKTyd4Ww53XQIdZGMJAMIC7rQtBSzUfOJGFxIVgb3yIlfabdHcmI9TSSYlnVKuqrXSZ8RAYniQ76hBlPhSrd6JRT5iGIY3Rc5524NJGyr1Hdh3KRwna0AWzyAjty8W4E/Od2gw7dEO8cEpdhZULXEZVnpUoemFiCQAhu6DqvinpEKVfqy7WIjbd3BkBOtC0seK9n6qBNOYn7uySSd/TceLpKcBdCsw3NJ5SbGRmpurYCTtrRj0xatyQ0vgJ@fGbsI/NQ@acMhC1cBD3xyhqvd5Kx0Ca@m47nsgWWAxg1Br4eZZ8pPR40KdzfBDOcBj02AN4OTpkzsdguiDfq@@OcJQIaa3aPtuYpp6Ehky5e3@jjzgathbF5bOsAuzSZsgBGrnypiw/6tl5HxBM79kwXpgEB/fDQ9qXhQ/Vze8uMKllYrjDSPvmh0oiswXTPRPuE7wnxuoueGE24iGUVoSo6CkdSAL39smZyFAWUWM2DT2lVdVOtbb@r0jpI3xoM1h53Ys8n6A4nK55O/TUk3EnX/dXFgwiKwPJQsi0EpZ/KzWMNJJOSYDGt7tMechHELTU/28BGWKHaYqobHUiPT9KiIHxxBFjSSmvqbiyrC/rsuvbJzqGPbZShaQXikIdO13vaAoJwmoSEqV1AnrPQi1WCo3XhEOruHcmbVA8lWDvdJ16eaCWFhMfqMVS4Da8h1dQg7ufPxZqnTllxul9lyKQJDgnkZTrrtlrnNxSJ@KkknqPWHCGVxq4Zu0uQys9qgQ/KI8iJfB@EfmojVcoYgxRtToL0JjNZFVOxR2nF0urJViaLfUDBqGIbmPJ@@7Dn@F/iPKmTz6GBAI3UGkbZgXz@6qAXCA0XCGBhgdJSbVZwSVMpDfp50n1EtntN1FBbOTHas8lyrMger/xN6gwe7uawH9lA@TyPxjz7y15YaBzKyhQVJ0RrT4nmsK/Ltx2M7BQlX3uAnATmycX6VaZ@QpcbBNE9jnaYV23lXq7TWo3NFVnI0tJZkBSROc1xcnTsMFLaKGxEoLVXUkiPYVFSTDHwsFm@HuzgED26URJ3BZiHWLtHjBwDv4BOtT4nYg5pE5AjM/AR@s0Dnsalv@ZNOCriYghxYLdduteKuPf6mOq6WD4vmyPQAZ1rt3@rE7tAU6tvhM@5K8w2h4ZQKyA9AoSrOcASmR/MSzLU29Kq7WVEknNMimgovnC1qYtXnHJ0trabjxQsU0iSALcMTt8ealQP/8E6StgmQPqGuBKRZRaZbfFWo8mJqtxkNg@a29NQAT6jXMuhXLPLBoRNkuttttMb8DODIxI2Ji4GVctIRYFbzSRjGCVlvqNm/nL5Me8uggjzug7Pg6GZW9Bw@yRMCq9ZraxDjltO40g8isbh2VwpcRN1sYHqmEJcuz@EGNBNks/sytvKZGAIvbk7ilWn4MLJS4YNGPX3B6gJhWH/oFknUPKHi79JNKDt27JEWStBeShsTWEgG1XJMnBr4x8dsDzvCDRhHtqpNHtBbNH1pANGZ8p75HP4@wpshrGd792aR2GzPb5ruNgt@MAG3kArT2IzyvRdqzMU9506er9ej0tKUFxYtq67H1Dh@B1yGjn1awoM@ebCR1pU0qDtKddutqILAenFTFaBIxYz69K/xqItxJtTJZ1m6WpJxCU@/x2i85@a7R57labVuJdyzgr5o8dTTwpjRZXkuVGbluy7rPaSISMUcp5WNm6eTtzzJAiAr/OpRfDtpEsXOUA960v9OdheFvylvdFm0pW7PIJtRcO88QOpLlcxzs3uKEGcNWL9d5AOAMCwl/NhnuQLtiE8aUVIVdSMmrFQ8zB6v13lmJQbsHfweVA0fdsnPaqnXVq2WuPCGEJBCHOaZ7055QAIsubywmRqsGyMfrT8uyYxOXJOKP9kCfH1NZigpZPIIpqoetZt8z@4PBqPrJLSe9F58zcITrvg7tVQw4xGCOCK/WHQONziywaKgOJtd6GuzVqZhuE3JWzjL7ZBKql0NcB6ib3X1VHW@G11SDahKxKpMe34o@pZ1GXMO4HoJP7ymcZM47TZhTTSjE2VJwxYgZEngCHVj932MgyuOdIzcLkYzzKftxVncxJagvMzHxWuIhbRxJdVq9kyfChjROZwikEpFivS4LFOvFyanzR2HOJajHeNNq2k202kHazVd6gJmCtd15UbKdjRjtZJP7bdlFHobzWWV8FOVb18mwr52J0jarU08PHv9XFitdbHoGFLI4uk02MjZcFbMNn5LkDlsFCCMyu4uvumpNKkRrNuMUSRbrJ0O6fyhsdks1FiOiUM2YpV43EmdoiZKnCkmEhZaevW2ru7DSG4qqCxP7WjqeZFu4GjVpxWep8E@blZmdDyLJPbVogLPnwkvIMKTwXNNqbQFg1oFaSIPu336geHKldBCv6YdM15nTIZKgQDP2Ism6w/Ez9yURm44zq5JDOp3Iyoyqn5D6iOVKcyIhu2sFlRKpA4sOhohbUSPelgZxZL2D6o7IuiicbgfSasHcxaDu449MV@gGnT4wImHW615IEza2I1lu7wW89chjncebC3GdXSotMUNS2bavXvVfeo2At5GLD0qB7utHRPHRMU97Ak/ugHuVOG4KO1dB98oJTOmEIS6RbKTm9FdTZ1uDgZj2zhZ5Y4nKJSby4l9gNTOsGdgNo7yUW1T29F6PVsk@O062rVpZVA3fH8TplNi6UvrEG@@5Z6OZS9iWU3PFJPhW5LkiRhh@4Cu0Qhgp4ZK@TD2BRrAUFywr6EmsHYCRUA3IyoBkjcEpp3xpoXoSvu3DNbYWwp4a9zU9n4Ij83bIA6Ct7fqo62tuyE9yWvmLfQWmGd7BhoLHl0wb5rBfKQ/9lV6TNa2PRY5a/HQybyOBTTpNJ4qqNPlwBH5ZonaZi6Lbz7W3Lydi7IzD4BxBz9r1k2g4fD5UXZv8JLaWC3Ojm4p@WSpNZHVgsBbY8kVUK@yXnO/OHdPCy1GRxyDTxzip9O4ZDscPIy/GNJ1mp22YH2XWMs0jV0DHF9MiKWKvjJNsYZV9njCLf6ghgimT5uy9sM2khgKZLPnIXQQCLrHQkWG9sv5ZfJQpBf4Cuue2T9bj7Uca28bHpsNAQw8eTm2dLu0uQBtGv8tmzMjsh/J1jqy2sj8JbNO09Eb2FdIXq6Z7uLFxfljRXA1OlCQzaf1Lcm9Q/KCkdbjtr1dcLIB2za9FKCESVyzR0Y6kBLEeaa60MizTAsHPM/BVMpsESZSdV1RRFQzQixj6mHlwOGzxIphgXbISHUU3OoH5yssyCXe7noAEXtRZdhzZZnG5ljU5wWqtPJPdNaKfPjG@hQdAsB5/FJRj4Ul8WAGYAfW7B508MtgTU7zHRaw3uT@R@Svyb6dk/Dc6uWwVQ25upUfpnK3lq5JdkL7snFeTDWCV7f@gZo6S0OLtS5b9H2jsxDUxbKMOUHrkvXXkiKWL0UVNHPeCWE0FJ2q2Qjg8UwRacnKrgViu7btZmQx3hA9/bE3INj5btLic/nwRdTYyZJd5a0Vn7FIw4VILCBnosjk07QOTqwGbYPeyaLaLizjgpOHBH3xvaim4ZsJ@Lh1n52H4UQ9B@KgCYxXOSxj1WXWS9mVBbpcQ6xGg2FCqxZwsf3LFnlmc4OnnyF/FMTRdt29K1TTC5O6bIUGasthYij@g9l6pJ5FPyCPig0CEA6MIzEOQlsRkl9Vg@Cq4ECx4Z7zNW2OUNUv3c9y2CvksaHy8wm3rsMdrvNxhkvzlvs96WsFoeiyZ9qLhPZkfy7DvQJ8c2MvswMznK6ORnDzaAuF1iJMklgEIvF0iS8fR@1YD0PLuakX0Q5WAjXVAot80UWciMJQkaVpgYWJ2ri6HwuV3kbECVU64bySZeiPiPk1QSvGVHjRdBPRKjP6cWSlXD6OWBuYWT73Ho6pa3uP/@Md2Z1TZdQEbS6Qj2j0w5B@NxkZGPaD8ogU@iFsd4r77s3wJCQwpw9VpKzsyhYDDktSGc2eIcoErgZlpBl28HGhDw@hsnJ6vtXrrKD2JKd8YraOYyd2rM00AIKlPa23lstx5T5d0CQby8Pbs6tznSxZJ4rTqUFnjVWwYMLWI@XkjmwkXo9NCbN0KPa6GJBrE26hjg8PLeDarHU1b0SNwMCMtaO/6za5KGxQKMITfV1HbLayq6N2n7eyVls3YuE0HY7HtX26xJGj5Dyg6Gdnre7oZ1pN@yZWeBHTiirTALPCCMz95AZZk3y/WkyIbCmX278tcz6GYC1nb6YV1lSmRBej3hyhtqDo2sWq2eAIHZ5Bn6S2Cz8pghSOdrYnPmCwgHS6UZir5S8eICuUr/W5Tu/Y@9kJMl3QgkBryMKQ2jyAZ5uGF5acmWKWtm5hzcndG0I7HnGKqN3EHYgKUVe3IM8PNSCrOiMTQqHpitXkm95vj8PHXdAHnfXlKq2uS/EJIrtSMQLahM2ZKaYpFJeAhIt@0xSDTTKWyYPCcE00H@sxiuqxSnw6agdTWeU4c@5wWRJ4Zlw2t91CNQUVmaoeea6WbGPvIEX0MBWuNoXvVlzJbj5Xz00WwmFVHaF85QvpMzzXvMWR/v@qzuxKjhsIgi7hPoyh/27wbaMigPnUE0XtznQDdWRGmjwgeU1u5EbQvtD7IVj0RK2Gv38hbcmEXYVftBINAHZI6rdbTJ6vhoi1iS1pxNi04IGsosAMi2k2T@iMsfymhgqctn6iYSa6@k0YANSxIz61glPBbTBkj7HXJqb3rE6a38dwnbO8tXp/JjVVCfX3Oddz3Rs9NpiZafSVBYyieLheXLxVtX38oIxgKuTiXdsJ8rQK7/7CMiqJ0@ZefhPR2JNsup9CCFsWeByZdT@/ULhkwgW0fq0ER4NrE6X@jOEVafQt2TCRQbIpsi0aipDZxni@4bmONeoGCwvqP9979Ho8s8YDgRw392VGzdmlAhTQhidoSfeAyptoJCA3Zrr9LARuvXjVEVaCGAImUz2YX31HERLubOghaeZnZFAZnAu8q5YHN2ekDq184EYC4PqbRJbCV31ZR7cWlWp4djHmxENTWf7MSbG/JM6Kfmt96RdJAwR7L7SoPl8VZcys7zi4T/GsGDIrIBuSZabXxh2GIxNv1oQb4QZf2AA7ysNezQjIyIMurirnEAOj8tMT1vAk2/83Lv7FB9/CVzeQ2S0JxJc5NNnJuSFo@Q1FOQrVYHRuHpWSnni3a3m/0AoLlXOAf6rmdbuPdM0P9IaDzqYbhjg2Byaz732DtePg3uys3XRGoDvzhflmRcfWhX5jQRO@yGjkau0HTbbWRUF3UCP9XZwU/CZZpbeYrQJCoJSHfRFd3d8Mq10qNO1whesWaRFHPlYo3nZIpLeY@UTs2GTwGFnsd1CaxDVkDZiXsZhjvntO/s3x0ejJN7fPx3HT05K8cb@3FKv7uaqPX3EiYDSw78La4nhpzALOsGp1VW7INraBJmj6TooSPZgb9Xx9gIn6OJsxtAKNcfToKyrfud5sy9i1KItwW1iOznIHP9TO83JVzkI@MSDVF5Rxgl1bS/@dNbOl3En1xn6Dgc4x3t@Y@TNbo0kc5uQ2bVvogcoNRxzjqTI61v1kOZKp1Wag0M6ItANJzW6g/8qCXahLr9GW1FqTWc6qtAyEIwwd00@P2ehga0V9EUVMibn6FMZrGJiL67CvZ9rpAe5@9cdIg8XGC6u4jE8BKmhoK1rMQx1B965voIBH0Il07EvETgdb7649T/NsKM/mqprZzvHmowu68j22R02@HXMJJI0B6WK/Nynw8hVNdiKHZnieWxNVu/VeQ3NEbS6TbTLYOuiQEl5fVJKd9@uR2p0TSzsPnVdkeFa@7ICmdxSzo7@pJwUP@zG/0tottfoBVbqz9q0UqAEaOMa6P0wboa6kMmXINLFwq7inxtI@xzhH7AJWjyGpSMz7YGBO8NHUh3sjkBzB@@xWL8rqE6gO/XrWpwak1i2O@SkGnpJxFi03v2R5D5mY2QEgX6ptIDsn0HT8abu89XCwOQQmseJtkTRTQqOvdDufgW9HK3seYGa9vRgTBliiGXtGddUDnbqRZZxPrsMhyfaZBIyFF0P03j6DmMXbWgOSpjiXKOQReXvnlqzpma7GW2rLtwl3SEjsgyLGhLizb5t4BTgMKsqtTOt5hALnjvkTD3Sa6KqjdrGMODvWr7AzTzKjmsw3oX5dqXPQLGJ5tLPBNfzZG4/ajOiILciV/EwM6rMTdCCoSOBIRJ@faI9YB3ELXx13m9x2tK8kKZ@ntULbyWd@b/b0eb0zD4tqEIFI7bH/RyBUCPVWM60IZT0jpMmwMA9UBsmxD4CULl843V@mheOr8QUUpDDn/8IXPE09Rr7cbu2yY@NxrYEL3F8AFc@kSmlcZa9VXb61HwFdIZBkV/br6uTNQfzKanv9s1SpzNF3U/sd70XImHnzfcX@6gCjOhv8lYTpx@icivhPoU4LwVGEFJB4seBsVapdzUZniWjzciEGN1u4u9cQIsJCWWCK8988mNWTuZHJdnPa3bK58Uha@3m8xyUyIzUJHPTEQz7iIWPf0dk71Rf2pTvr1NdQcnt@sgI/f2sYPmFGdsL3JtFhLUtXhRvZQSK0/rJQFmuCwZQkJYXh2LEqfp06oTuGV35Jv2nmLCUK3S3uMqFZZbg09001nU96U28uQufjSAu3n0PUzjdeKwSqBDbYxXjuauT5yj9H1RePxVxzlDdqJesHipx6f5KYpM6fDV9YFgIRRql5Pg6EGTFcNUFDwxy4GqWOIT7hEYaWCtBsT2zdivo78@oRk4zhJLExxq56U9NlrI03lXSLSF7PZpO1wAhhQwlGCIRrXcXytzLe/z4e/GEx3/37lAoyjc7G4BQ8OgdYHADDqvJjQwfiOH8hIWwOjpJH/rz5a1379AYEYGh0ghiz46Hf6Z0YYIWrZqv5iFUS7iipbyZUXvo9508GlkzH66XMSL6me5pYbH289iWu3EARQZpHBfyDRN260iah1PXnlDz131bKmt/IpVPtcC7Lrj8PCfPrak7tpDAZV6KPwLaZJjlu@BEJ3gOM2JYGWd/juiGJ1Ey84jy8CbGzv9Ilw1dzJQ0Qgl6lZfJGboiRpopxG88RZp4dKkRzbIrsshbhcM295Nk4V@wsUi@9o2/M5bS3Gq8NVVLI@fg9S1lIfQ/iDnt6z1o2GE4evd8nKRLHRTWlsaEwQF/l2QR8X0sNgGUl94lk1BAuJuYH58WcqvRqfYDpX836HTjDRqHFIHROkMiclcvMNQhdD17biKerCs56pTd4CcbAjbtr9De3K5wdpCh1/B@tmKk2HrZRxuMQrkK5/zF3@D7pqnp2xmpaIkWshBYRRFe4/nCIFxkpJwY6K@gk/yg51qmxomtg4hPVEA/2E73pC2d0MrWawdsBlhdq1YY3Kc6EK8ZfFOv8qEl8aF6Q1TVNBkhgXsYq@hj@@v3j8WpHDvEVJ0osi8qyZZRVFuVQONC66e/dizZ1i9ym4LwJuM7PTLtFSWyYzzy@Ak3OiTNiKt5AkbCtqS3Tk6DcSATY154fZa9ORUUuNca77dhs63x1hiWM1D1qgxn7u8Z6d@pAWVbh4BJuLnHnPEpcHKvaUo8XLFeiBwppjK6AhtLmjCCP3iCa8UERNHidon6Iw1JxmvqKs94pyPu06hbtzimGBI23J7MG2zmqTeOrfeXQTMnsPbNkUhwX89@vjKLNXofMv9K7PCrTYKl8nb3BcRwmZrLoamimT1Ow5utjiYmumoxBGQ9s98ZgB12LCQJTvMwcext/8v1D0IbPIudCIucDPht4M50stR/4zWNqtowasu0QueRr8z5HXIpMvNjiSggcnEo9m8aMjYaooh0lf5dU2Gj4iszIvmVgIDaaIhtJI6yG4mokCD8G5XF1om1wvDuVEuqjU90LpNANtRgAuJ/fuqRjmFt1VgQvh5HFpSjYsHGmjvK89OG/wXBSAM6q4rkj5cuKHDpaCI4fFwQrD1S4qNHxx6MjS6zKqOa9R2YZwoO1fCJcd9yNPGyqEdS00CDJAPwe5R686WO@/RsLVMymTVrcWT8Z25kIcmHSOFCED66rdscbWl2uiC5ZzY6OWYjhb8jWVDAtfHMx/uvPSnTY9@LWGA75DR/br8kkwPBEMXaTlOJx73wm35@u8bAMJ3Bz3BjiHtGbG1POUGkYH@jmHmmqs8ev8B4ZR@D/kIKOYihmvrnv4b/ijenucwc0lB1ZUSF8qc/0Yeg@N6SRG@iuOxu4H7KGD4kv1PN1G3pnLGZyDTJor5rboen2y7FWZ8@z4rRc3dmYaNsFZLcAPgERF07r8RGHz@@66AGv2RCBwHQAjhaDuaDswoLRovGwZxvfiiwV22IKyQ6Cz2jL0FmegheVfMyX5kt@XMo69n4xMsVw2xLRnru4NJdClGMwnFgoTnQRiKGPzZXR4XiChQ9zJGJrBo@@5VfxLW0XNi0BYzPKmRz1EmRzpjFJD9pvt0e52sQAn7V8VSnl0VqijV4EupD7U3H572hdFt7NU/1RVZyyXP/j93Z1FjG0Zc0/cumEBi7OnyKLBnsMTy@eME@j74V2oRKomEoAXg7aByfqLC@0PmDYk0VBR8ixeSC/rxRVx4jNVZQ0rRoNEVSlaNToVY/vItOT2oxduU@5zpKt26dcDuNBwJjdUcar6IiHvyJTE4l0tpYNuyD6t5uCk5GmbnR3mXwh5RaMLld05UeBkCCFHYOnGw/GfYU860m5WcNScz5XTYEz9u@nWfKX66H/PNWHI4Z@vtexHnf997Y0Qm83YUznYWzx71/jXYTAGQAuQyaRxI6qLVVPoEwzGZv189xUTF2R5gDruTKb5BkcJMVZW6qaP/84w3jTrTRPZ/mludZnt3LkFaJsOguACB4@jU0ZPlQwc0JeRMF4JCpzCxGFwdpoeSXb31THFGXi5OivRdmQ6lXwT6cO1GWVoRVtBsaT6JXaxTkQD9RIuQWmeood8rtMpb3dW0HBstbzwA/d/hXPhEaQvm4cmgimobqYkXSPQezmbXrC1pfl3QHFbEmkN24yE4PFGudwSLAXjCjU2o0pGELoWfIWkmLVDYWUFm2qLNR8bbypvTmCl1CU0YbPN1E1x6RhkNPSWIDlZUlrGhTa/FjkRvLs2YH9VQMhgL@WXkKDT11e@T0XROWw7DaJMkmTceEJaNHYv6119Mw@kSm23Znf55RxLkptEsqdWwLL/R6/U26GSrPeWBZpewmUWlK7VVWTHGak09/GHGxmnndwKOq7RyXtzdDloEKeI76afqRqU5B77lcziF69k0pZ8tPgXP9TPQOn3cSiRLzrtHyKvKAzd68vpfzctFyoD@PrM8V1xPoEOUDGVBL@3R4tPdyXCU@/knkTZMP4jBrAq6TKzpN9Y7i98M9CcHwxECUTbN6DJZziYTve4/LNsDpxB@a7NI28SKV3AeW7HYUXxPgxIpt07JMTw2TFMp3pGLmS32SP5gmz5kW9GB/INNcQoMmIYA43YBdzgZSoy6kq2V1/QZERAaiBUVZn8L15o74JdIaHV4IW2LEPpz8DFc7NwvteiR6Gl0qvKET4yk23zl2djzEBwAyItY3d8pVfj3SXxJXjc7MNn1hHkTJPbKeTwmQOA8eDV7IeJMcw9usAP@b4GVdUsMATW//SRJWVL3FzjNDWRoIRtUYx1in2R/NeXV8R0JgURv@40VsD/28/YQUkJgfmJHrvRnxbMrkaimUBwBf2n7AJFogALXg73YD4Hp92t0i7ENMJ7GOEdWQAlCyx2T@CDG7ZVjWNFND1TKoyMt3GbMIsvNHdsxCeKLIvh/xmyXZbTL34r0Dcnowl17fVsmcaIB8/xtJ2@kuLhSVxYnAxucf5VuQJ3YrhnKIv8SaMcomPGOdLCiZVD8gcEcs5ip22f8Df313ZXf4bMewtxphmJ0NafszJm@IBhMjMJI3EGZjDekd7ezyENm6t2U2VB2lfmik1UWfufHNIxgtE2NFOS049ClrSG1d816u@/PVE8OWmRZ26DrvAOUbJ5Sfw6CRio4UasANWJLJEcb2MLM147nt7M61PBVycCXEkkppY8N1PivExHrJqUXm0XcEtuY6LGeN2e2pkSo@woZGunfoaC8CgreRppXs0vTO6ILUT2H6KmNKFYeH1i0eX7Wm/sxWXpY2VeT9yl1Vc2S842Nhv1hZEEh9rjhDX7@9agk43SBABqaRVbW6oHfQx3@jUb4/1UQWr/RNOm86MeSbhE/gZHPsutbSpmEIbUp6@3LdZJxdALTM65y09XQPVNgpqYYMxZ0my3n5XlE2pxnIyFLlXMxZfbZsNwB2wQpqqFi7mowN3xAre1TbnqmgWjClkQ9E0dZFTQ824xCqkvjNgMrXiDeNmlNCOTxzJaKhP43np14/K4VjIZjmlH8bvFLoT99Iq3r4vp3dUF@YpJ/A/sbmregUrwRjf925ey9m3XvPlpyjMLwLnTEqIg1bJ9l3Nk8NVqJG2wCtokOl7vAGfFqDpTUp3YYy8sSYVr@VNXtySqJfZCBdqZzjYeA7CcenUmG9G8ObOQ26ywBn4yGjPES40mccfNQABgt3Axeaj3L2gznTAMX0zIPOEqJHTOu/QInqRHjj2OV9W5tEA8HmmMPGEGAGevUKZ84Z0SqbNjXBWCbW546siOQhGqubhbbke3V1E1tJryN3CezSVHM1ojFNYJFoc2B2SRQFD2YrCDYaPrWvzqYaYuQzOXIS9PpEbm5LrvgCMPhVRXdJcLAbR3s6K0EC2xRKJqSnoiGwEYGWkZTfLUVvDWXUbgRAa/@WuJ0Wppt3OscG6m@Az5ixoKoyA6ciMByGshU7z@@56OM6noQqmjQX6YLBSVJ6a4JkyIttSpedznxdP/LPvgopTFLX2UDUU@bhNafgoP5iaO3lZjRhvmrkWii5Fqi0KtPRkUYhnjnIE7MiMqnjyPCA12aprhM6N0xU@C6aLUmTRukzYMWkJlss5Qo2YudXpfNavhzYVD2mnJdowpWa9ut1ucN4IrVUF53/c/WfQW@5qfXOxnyGAle@nD7y0z1qVZhXJAqTSb8078/69y2/nFgQIYJqvccaXvtrrdMhC7Op7bs@sbY2W/@Z2peXqI3bhS/v/kEBgk9v0C3pRTONmIhFvooTq1zsG/qn/PJFUyl9VBitzxN6gyqGulUFLkpwsXq0repDOFLYvwdz9RVt938mklZlyj7laqumP1VmIhoK7UqoWmphQI5wyfCsmJJnDMNkfy1N3Hrsje5zWpUuCaWy1liloRc/i1ZqyturMuE80clVUOonDO9PF6VFwlC7p338) Thanks to user202729 for making the comparison-counting class for verification.

The algorithm has 3 parts:

- Estimate the median of the list (~76 comparisons if unlucky)
- Compare each element to the estimated median and put it in the low or high sub-list (150 comparisons, 1 per list element)
- Tweak each of the low and high lists by swapping the first and last elements if they are other of order, then the 2nd and 2nd to last, up to the 9th and 9th-to-last (18 comparisons)
- Output the concatenated low and high list

The idea is that if we knew the median of the list, we could partition the list into its low and high halves by comparing each element to the median. Then, putting the high half after the low half, any comparison between elements from different halves is correct. On average half the within-half comparisons happen to be right, so a random comparison has about a 75% chance of being correct overall.

Sometimes though we get unlucky in the random comparisons for a given list. So, we improve each half a little by swapping the first and last element if they happen to be out of order, since this is the highest-impact swap for one comparison. Then, do the same for the 2nd and 2nd-to-last element, and so on. It turns out that doing this for 9 elements on each end for each half is enough to bring us over the 75% mark for all the test cases.

The median used is an estimate, since finding the actual median is too expensive, which also contributed to getting worse-than-average scores. It's estimated by taking 9 groups of 5 elements, finding the median of each, and then finding the median of those values.

The median of 5 is found using an worst-case-optimized algorithm that uses a maximum of 6 comparisons. The median of 9 is computed naively by sorting, which is surely inefficient. There are algorithms that use 14 comparisons in the worst cases, but I haven't found code for one.

A potential improvement would be to used the information gained in the median-finding step in the sorting step. We already know how the median compares to itself, the 8 other elements in the list of medians, and the 4 other elements in its group. This would save 13 comparisons, for a score of 231.

Further information could be gleaned using elements that were found smaller (resp, bigger) than a median that is itself smaller than the median-of-medians. We could also put each element used in the median finding into its estimated rank position in the final list.

Another potential improvement would be to use the full `cmp` comparisons rather than just `<` to better handle the case when elements are equal, for exactly by putting elements equal to the estimate median into the middle.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score = <s>172</s> 164

```python
def shell(a, cmp):
    for step in [148, 138, 107, 43]:
        for i in range(len(a) - step):
            if cmp(a[i], a[i + step]) > 0:
                a[i], a[i + step] = a[i + step], a[i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb6swDH3Pr/DbgsbtpQPWD439iL1WqMpo2kY3JCgJuuXXdzaBrtWWh2Dj4@NjO90Qztbk1@tBHsGfpdZcpNC0XbJlgOdoHfggO1AGdstincIypytbpVDkdQTNQEUoJ8xJci0NFwn8GZOTbxgddaQCXOxUnQLe8Dyi6gTeIXuE0vmBg@reG0P1VbWddQFUkC5Yqz2bfqCcg20Zo/4a4aXnkxpy9s6ckC1iFh/jh@frsiiz1arYFJt881qss@Q2iv13h8syu@trUFIfYDeTLohSmcCzFF7KMvktuZ5EnWXzb@9RqzwY6T3XE62TvtfBo77dBd4qGEaSS4oG8twaXTS2/VRGBGUNJmM9ZI75oXcGfN/yiSqBv0CLmd1JgO1NUOa0p6UQ/VT/pO2n0DEcJ0YWPFewvOfnF1zbQKtG6w0txv5b5wPqzhgjyTQUkvw4/pGMMOTZnmwCYDvdwOPE43vEWPogMgaF9ziBn@NDOD4kJF6syntghMRwVc0ulYx8naN9kT9Vi7/nXlpx4aN9i7KY8eQb6@T2KY3Q5PoF)

Four passes of [Shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort).

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score = <s>229</s> 196

```python
def insert(x, a, cmp):
    if not a:
        return [x]
    m = len(a)//2
    c = cmp(x, a[m])
    if c < 0:
        return insert(x, a[:m], cmp) + a[m:]
    elif c > 0:
        return a[:m + 1] + insert(x, a[m + 1:], cmp)
    else:
        return a[:m] + [x] + a[m:]

def ford_johnson(a, cmp):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
    m = len(a)//2
    cmp1 = lambda x, y: cmp(x[-1], y[-1])
    b = ford_johnson([insert(x, [y], cmp) for x, y in zip(a[:m], a[m:2*m])], cmp1)
    if len(a) % 2:
        b += [[a[-1], None]]
    for k in range(m, len(a)):
        l, i, (x, y) = max((-i.bit_length(), i, t) for i, t in enumerate(b) if len(t) == 2)
        b[:i + 1] = insert([x], b[:i], cmp1) + [[y]]
    if len(a) % 2:
        b.pop()
    return [x for x, in b]

def thirty_four(a, cmp):
    for i in range(34):
        a[i::34] = ford_johnson(a[i::34], cmp)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNc5swEL3zK3TpRGqI488mYeL@hB56ZRhGYNlWAxIjianpn3d3JWHjJC0HkJa3b9@@FXSDO2q1Op93Yk@kssI4ekoJT0nddixLCFxyT5R2hIcdXka43iiSnwofasmWNEJRzh4flz5SQwQIPFXeFmzkqckrmX/gmdTNs7YItck9pmahgmh88vdPkjEFsIsCblMiH8wiWSSx4tN0TIVeLhUTNGOvza78pY/KaujsnR@hW/K6hRIfGP/lSdstMMjbascJaByy4FH@sACZAz6C0ApgN@Xza2P5MPoDCM8CXZM/sqPRO2xh@RU8D7gFe6f5C1leJVfkfkvynAcJP7QSRTAcyd@Q2XB1ELRNYzq75jYpkSlBTQMDwS0/UfogZ5V0JWAP7kiZR7ggFVdIKFTfCsOdoBUbZQFkuyVLdtWVZzIMdTsOFQaU@vjYFw4N3Cj@29@s0x0NvJdDOzoHYqo4bHeUxg3lXvfmdtZe@dWH1XpiAM9llq3WxftpjfHAc5Ztpw207qALrRubxAAw7nQb6tfcCksjN25Kow7AGzCzn/5BV8@b9Wb@9LR@Wb@sXr6tn@fsIrK8ilxs5hOVgxTNjuQj6QwppXJ0npLlZsM@S46m1EdRv5UWtIqdEtbSJtIaYfvGWdAHZsI3MNycxUujs1q3lVTcSa0gGeqxYjoJ27c0UjHy6Oc3bqMA3Ssn1aGMv5Ih1j80uuJNeB0cwxUe5cWUn57ghwFn8wFXr7BKkt/aWAe650mCktEUlHxrvydDDO50j2sEQDvdEM/S9LwAIr2RGiDc4rH9aCLAGfkO9LOnzRQYIOE1fAxxi4UDX2dwariP1UJ47Ag/P7@@vE1Cxp2ttRHZXRqg7PwX)

Consider the list as 34 interleaved lists and sort each independently, using the [Ford–Johnson merge-insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge-insertion_sort).

Comment: I know it's allowed, but can it fail on some other cases?

Comment: @l4m2 Yeah, for example, `[-(i%34) for i in range(150)]` is not in the test cases and only gets 45.7% sorted.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score 757

```python
def f(l):
	a = 0  # we are going to sort the first (a) elements
	n = len(l)
	while (
			a*(a-1)//2  # there are ~ pairs that is guaranteed to be in order
			<=
			n*(n-1)//2  # total number of pairs
			*0.75):  # it's possible to compute this in O(1), but I'm lazy
		a+=1
	return sorted(l[:a])+l[a:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVRNc9owED3bv2I7OSAlLjEJNAkDubUzvaSXTi8MwwizBk1kyZXkxjST/nW6kvnIIQMzYEk8vX27@9b11m@Mvt3JqjbWgxV6ZaoMpEfrjVEuTbujvkNcsdv70XCU390NH4YPtw9fhvc5T9NCCefgqanGABewMqCNB1EUSKd@g9Bre1BhtUSbJoVptJ/mHwGlA2wLrD2UxkJtpSY56Brl02SFJSwWUku/WDCHqsyg5eM0ScK6307bA6So6iPCUHDLo6itaaAQmr5KdaFkGQ9fhCb6hMT3o7Sr6YC29Kff1sg6BiB4UBoztEI6hF9CNfjVWkMpJRZ9YzWwTstjvNRv@ef9weRwcNCoQhIiW/Lx/qboH4Qv@SQ/wvAcbHrE6XO4Tycc/j6Dm55w63N8j@9w59J4zNM0wP4IJVdMUa@APl07HUxh1sJkCtvY6jajhdQnz1ErqqXUwkujHVMZ3PD5/n4M5JqK7ak4XINCfdo@Qt6/G@1C7DLGTQSFi4Z7QRAWYW2kXoM34ILhg0FLaZ0HJjigwgq1d2mi6VYgVtS2l41UCIxanYhLJj4P@PX1TWAMje1I/0EtiIVOhA9@WTeC5sbTzIRISwz5GbsKI5Akk2n41ZdMv6MyXijQTRgTMGVHF2CXIZ/OxdL3HNTGObkkPcRLdaobj3tHa/jBBjyDZePhe68CJf5uiUFETx9KRznTHKvZWMz5lZqJ8XznCkMZUJHS0I1FICLta2SDUb5v3HE@IuzUStqWbPYU@tG9JcKDBpfl1LTRiHP4gHLOI0OccFb2fiIV/3XxlkEn5PUY7K3XIQ8CK9GyuM5OgjrERRhQ7KofLSf9FooNFs/gxTM6EKBogqmuoWTCSkfOogqaeJteX@S8vVe7xHh6kPeNjKg6CWN4jU/StfsP)

The solution simply sorts about first ~75% of the array, so that it's guaranteed to be valid.

Python `sorted` takes about O(n log n) comparison.

Comment: Can you use a custom array-type that counts all comparisons?

Comment: @michi7x7 Currently I'm using a custom object type for that. What's the difference?

Comment: Ah, so that's how you computed your score. You didn't mention that

Comment: @MishaLavrov If you read the code instead of the explanation, you’ll see that it actually computes the smallest a such that a(a−1)/2 > n(n−1)/2 · .75, so it sorts about √75% ≈ 86.6% of the array.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thanks for spotting that! I indeed only read the explanation and not the code.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 669

```javascript
cnt=0;
function wtf(arr){return arr.length*~-arr.length}
function finished(arr) {
  x = 150*149*.25; // toleration
  for (i in arr) x-=wtf(arr[i]);
  return x>=0;
}
function cut(arr) {
  rnd=(Math.sin(arr.length)*1237812731+127317823102)%arr.length|0;
  tmp=[[],[arr[rnd]], []];
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) if(i!=rnd) {
    cnt++;
    //tmp[arr[i]<arr[0]?0:1].push(arr[i]);
    if(arr[i]<arr[rnd]) tmp[0].push(arr[i]); else
    if(arr[i]>arr[rnd]) tmp[tmp.length-1].push(arr[i]); else
    tmp.splice(1,0,[arr[i]]);
  }
  //console.log(arr.length+','+t)
  return tmp;
}
function nesort(arr) {
  e=[arr];
  while(!finished(e)){
    x*=-5;
    t=0;
    for(i in e) if(e[i].length>e[t].length)t=i;
    for(i in e) if(e[i].length<e[t].length && wtf(e[i])>x)t=i;
    e.splice(t,1,...cut(e[t]));
  }
  return (e+'').match(/\d+/g).map(parseFloat);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XL3LrnXLlp1V5ylOEeSDFPeLwE@SopACIxkJbCUWFR4e1ojevhYxs@D0Pnv//1pzjhGX3ltvl//jX/@ff/2//9d/@8//9b/9j//Xf/nf/tP/97//l3/77//P//Tf/vU//8f0P/3j/MP/nDv/@B/@w//wj//3v/vXf/u3//gv/5JX/uc/6j//kcff/5f@@Y@9//65lH/@o@T1z3/M9f3DP//x9//Vvz9Q6vz@5N8/5fb3R1b/@4f195f69wPK33/7/uL3U3L@@zElNf3T/P5g@/5u/ftheX//Z3y/qH9/Yp6/zd@K/9ry94u/f9fS92O//1n//lzp34/6fl9Jf394/32U8fff2vdnRnze8/G@/ze3PlWOD/r3T/vvL35fuP39uXU@QD9fbv79t1H1v0vhx@fvz3zfuZ@v8/ff9vr@7fcovk/ezsc//7Tji58P8f31@AR//y/V@Lfxh0f5vuH3ver3mc4T@n5mL/rZ@/sq@e9/tb@/0/9@wPd86/dV//78943i630/9HsFpX8/q3@vacVzPr9mT/3D9wi/X3fexfd2vh/x/aLzvNP5IN93@/7PeV7fw/@e0Pdrz4fp3@/7/nXPeq6r6QV9L/P79t/T@z7C9/C@h1D5dJXXtr6v/X3H75F8/9/3DeNZ9PjzOX0/@jz0OfU/x/pf/vkv50@cr/k98tJ6PIpSvv/zfYGz3s4KO49mahl8H/J7Y@cR5POYzqL6Xu55PvGQ@G/1@6fzUr/P/T3Z84LO5/3@xvr7PyPFV1qDV/etj@9x7M1fKFsr6zzbdv590jqcLIXvcXzPdvB1v3/xPejvb58PcTba2ZZTq@Zbvmdjfvvj@/LaS4sF9b2bWHa5xcM9z@l7Bu1sKa3a2fR2zuP61n/Vbv92Uz4v43ub8R6@P3BW3N/famfNfF9kxDY67yY2/uAl9P3@1fNQvud2NnPsrG@lxjqb@ljff/u2cbyKXPQd4jz4vsPSWjrf8RwacdrU@PT7rKyzxs5Tqvo752vEshn6VpMH9K34s@XPa/u@@vky57hJhSf/vdxadFx9H@G8y/Nlc/yM/H2d8@Pzt1rHilcbRyXbL9el1ZL4T9/DKueJtqrlfPZN4v/EgZG08@r541sPZXOonk96HuY5DL5z41uA3287x9FZv@c4qeyH7@u081W/T7H0SjsbKA4@/Y3z3M4nPUtpsovPAXwOa7@r8wt00PSs13zOlXjF52Q8D6bo55bzV84n2DrGp97H2WHfZ@ew@37OeYbfpjjb5tuwI558XAVJK@pcFtpA52V@N1uLX/Jtr/jeXF/fi18syBpH7vkjZ@We25Bz4vtQ56TlUIibquv/fD/yrLrzTArr4Hse5wFs3VGr6i98/6Oc1bnj0ZwdXc6zPU/wfKa4Y86JV1j3579@n/n7JbrWzvP@dn0d/klNp09pi386J0wv31JNSwvoOwx0FzRec1zA7d3V8Xm@lbC9bM@j@D7T4Ew8/@ucWOefzhM53@P7/7@TIHNKl7tKtCziIPu2ybf5zv84O@Gs8vgcXWvgbIyzRc95eNYJJ0jheD6fonLPn1LlW9mb8ua8Wq@m@IRVy/RckN9rWrot4/mf1z20XmPDVLbn93y@t7t01pynnrRV4wA8Z1essaHaIe62pAUeB4EuuSjEvn/Tt7b396xm0rn@/ZLzOb6b5VynU8f0@Xln458DfHK2fr/6bJmzoc83/v792mzHs/vjuxX9z/Nm4trssRNjiWQdVGe9L237wc16Xlf8p60NV761fLZoppSLf/rWSNGbaD@l0ky6Ls@7bX/LtnJXrKIT8Ts14uqKnXCWaI7XRiVyru@sY/scWPFw0vk0HG7n03z/69SO2uc7/tWmxlRV4dt2nR@2dTZsnSmnrIpFela41lfsv3NlNBUK57xjpzR9zng433f9rtLNcX0urHOp5ThwchwKI36NDuet8@@UQoUD@HvPruFOCXj2/XkgsXEra/NcCFH15/iFy1fWZPeeLXX@ThyXSzfROfEqz/YccueRdr2GeHE9vn1zRdu0Hr9FcO6E8xbPyRZvZfvDqjqNmq7FQXKutdiiZ0nFHZ1UKp2VlQY/6/z8c0MUPY@zB7@Tt@pcikLqHkyVI@H7FecPTtUWzavk@3Tniv7@4PeqzoL9lsXiba2oF4eP4mgDErs7cxhFiX/2WRxQXGXnGX@v5fzrsyrO0/iO/dVpa/iCp0rhP8/hirbyVk7hT00arVjWzfZt5biM3GNk7rKuO/z8p7PnE7dOZbuf75KXPvfq@ofGUXY@4Pnh33@LpZk47U8Z@r2/7/d@a2tTpX5/IfZU8aukCjmd2Vl/Zze4euh6tGd7TdXa2QXKdyp/C3BwIw4941iW57MUupWz@uNqmboGT@d0mrVK23pWep7v@Xq65PNLv8UZ3RCnwfkD566LvaJ3Mdk457I9f6WpPj2n09CRcW@6s9zjDvAJVPT483nGp9rpNK7fUv3WxvefdpQFlds6RVf5ff3z1peOo/MPZxdHpzf1U72Zz@GoFfb9h2gxl9ZyLLzvVX@P5hyWS0v13KXf7XGKmFPaJ8rZoS9wFgVf7Wzgs3Q3LzKKar8xLt04ffW8zlkXj3OrqRxdv6SqtuVpfj/urLI4OFt80jj0ziG@9MHiUAJqiBu46F49izX2cNbxfQ6DTPuydXmVuL2pFc5GPBCKz/rNsjyr4FxG0VEV9s6KA/i8oajms26nc0jyoL6f/X3SszPjWKAmOV/13LSNVqeqrTurgedZXQ2N82@30AAVRoXXfj7l8uaJEjidAv7s3bhm9GKrD/epKvn7abGHzysdf8uU1vHcV8UF2/kGZ5FN9avn5X9PpNHrx0vpekBZj/v7TE3Naovj/azseH1nU5wn9/2f5sL83H/fx4xKrmpFRW19FnON3/wtkFM7nqq20EYMoBR3nF2Qwvnl34eKi22zx7Le01mmlZpgNm8IcImhzvFc81MFRIBzXZdMB6A6n2y56oo/6ioqmvXB8uqcvefkOadM/K2tX1jpjb7XXkDVzq3WAOfiZ/q9JTXRVUvkwEgl3sZZOLGrN6jaedKDEvle@VHSnkX23Z3nUBgzCvjT409wh@RL9uwen3rntF06D@K/Zx2yE8Cl8YxVCOc4KONCm1xI3@@Mjv0rA2Innh/RdDLUKLPOFvlupO82@P5AbNym4/DZPJl2YHR1gQdh@H7ReXmnjg4MJblmqHHOnoJo89RjGU9Khe@ZLmrbs@LPHjrPPBYZTz9WExDVKc@/v3x@aQH3KnoEARdz8H5nyYzzp2tDn@v7ALPactGPF63jntnAhXP@/Le4QAo32vkejYemJpb3eX4OJ1n8HwHVW5tiFW5wgbdRvaw4/kfA3@dk@R575/TIrI1zAUyax2Jc9zy9cymc9agmJmDmoSXHERTVaCCi@kjxNjO4z9n0cXUmqpzzQryv4jZeWnmB6Ol2Z7ec@uUsxKhkfHgGsHYapHRgrM0noSocxZD6cuG/OHoqyEq87carOdhzY9dmvUB6p@aWgB10YOTJ7oqN0jnamjCyOBQynz1u9mrcZmkJH1A2QI4tCC4eljH287fOhTb1U8/FOnUlnMU4uI@H8a6D4xqm/d5lY42WSvN2Htr5tD7kun/D9/GMr5XvTD@t9YglQiWb4/iufB9AqO8foiHZqkFi62jFZtdh5weeV3Cu72iAjXan8UD135s952Lc@Elf02/onETnrDgFL6jsOW4bbdZi4hIHV1TjOq7mPQtcFnSDO5WyMp7wOVuWqrrACL7ver50AouJ42lyen9P8AwMOj0UmEys86aTMu6us6B6jI6i9ZlaGeejn8I76rzMXTy18U@dHYMi1Q3fEthMvNYyRNWFq8Z5Up9L6ayHuFybFgw7cHMrJM7duP/UhZ5yIQrIgMR73Ki37akcod9H/9bBbV7PWXoqnK5bIfOt4uUNDciiMQbmiylD02gj@p/@/MoJlnZq5HMqdUCjrQHCEoYxNMKIhxJwWuNAOgfKqQq6JhWTey3w0yz0LuqMHr8@Rl5Dry77zvye2dCZqJsaYGFr9fXsW4GRSmPJRSnlSufA9jHIWjyz84T1pc751XgJZ7PGflnn2jtf9/tYUQbHuXiWK3OZou7g/KLKHq9cc9@P/v7a0LilBERbdDUMgzmxN6aQy6r72JjNFKyzfu72KDKKxzYJfOicgdWtW1WXvBkJZx5lDFOWcd/JomM7fjvM45mDY@qXLxrI88di/2397Sj5L757zj5atehuT6N1isepI/e82aXKICop93nxAye9f8wEQe@aUDPh2sntkIYXZ/9kreq4B6YqivNazk137qP42FkLq3tq3J/ZcFT1hS8vXOi8hAbW3xkeegZU3hrjLOhMEXkef9JHbEK6YwJ9FnRmGfs6OD/ubIISx05s4wr4pF8HaFb/FmzTWuy3n0rxV7//sjiYzooa49md8aO6OtdJJZGY5p6DbQqn0t0/dL18J8Y5xb9ncI6kQv/ZhB2cOyupWzwXx8HiNV9Z9AYZ6CpKxJiFU11uINpsQPf7ZXFZbXeurpTPPqxGt6bOKire88fj95ze7oBwTG8ZYmTfekPT7KUT5TQqrnXO49m0CU1wQmd@PgQzZQbUp8zP6mjPa41b8zyA4susuE0cXLzlgh8/I584EArF6Oi0o2JdxK0fy39pft08Jk1e1nSTZ2udg75yRLBWvi0SbRqVRpQwyfhoTBWamuDTZ20tvxWMhq/p2nrt5076fta3LuJN0jjE5TljONjMLGiGYW7/VICcTrHQPfZsGqCe4yYD71ZdlWWZBNBVr8VSic7eJRA/v9KWxf9sxvsNZWUaVoOIZzO7BmdpVQ1UJoP9rd/43VkrARme33CeEFhcAdyKa67wEs4FE7W2gevpscFFA7PmrTH2@b5n7yZZZNVh@5kWV6g@52MuvuS6U2um6ACvbHstDhq/UyNFvUXhdl7YXXRMpM8POoj6udBcHMegbnA7xlzI1Spz@iBAqaer5iglb21fHufre9ITe6gJFOmqhfaZfn3TLYrkb0lUd2ZxmNAN33K26llm3b9xFs1niBpfbjGr094osSbOAXAYNcO1GOtucrQNJsENwkEcFYWhGD10wN2BWFY9i7g/klg/5xl/T@cMtiB4JB/Bu/5sysype64SJgrBGWOGef6pxfk0uALPqwpwCbh2q6fq1RSEEkDmOR4nvx78Y3NaVREE4k7b9OaMRBqMlfPgOqVXrOUGier8qw1o0GlsjKM2yvxA3U5x3QTNxhv8VsjkDK68@1OYCO4tnttkjo6UPPbSSdY0QSiG1LrGHQBC55dU/s5muYh9YJZI/2CCQAyK7qK4d@tzQiadP/FIKtSKcyholYBAaEZZYblMVtCpjQ7PKrGCznl1wKAL9xiSD6YYKOmZHsEs6OtlTcVl6RZnCPNK5TL5cvDIzqkZE5FEg3FeQ/cF1XTdLaonkyTP59@@1yCyxdIvEKm4csT0WIzXxKyLMiVDijiHaeP8iu2VaEgDaDwgyveHz0s@yyRRBrLoz2CX0RhjlbPkvp9z3lIGyKoCd0WhihOJ@eoCtS@uCWNEJVLN@fjTg//v99ZkGh49jTG@6L4DGgE8aXG/bbXCS4d/EV40NmSdzjyTofDfTakpbKBURT12jGRcSnyvaXoYuvkUGeAFylO8pnMZFmrfy0y5026togJI0r3Po3NstI/0HZ03XymNz4ndJuQkAIKqGcYA9o25UdY@FugcrUg0DprCezzAHxG9dKR3EA@zYAbbTfcam@XOg/2cBgfipGY6ZefyBB0SyfeCRtzuqXnIqHnSWdgHZ5hisEXFWxhZLXikTdug6tQFKav5nSlr/sZZC@betkFVn9CuzXUFTkA76pzTAEW9tIRTiVoC@yxKBdhNNAOdGin6zaTJ6wBAifog8z7yKVkbBzLMrKatd07yDfXoe0dDx77ILmAZ01SQTXcrNiMYkBBadbVn7AVpOZZJ4iIooq32@jNsP6zxRuPSqEyiKpzUeueOGnAJBqtmMnKICuu0O/2FK3WMmrrdBWNTPu5AEpbKJzX3EwoGc5cYGQoei8XGqbXZXlGh@pmI4wEbKmhsTRDSOTDgZN7mxJvNM/pTEgOLd/EPDRkEIzW5mk6AzFpHg1L1YBr6lz6j44M1A5lxkHZ9xPNAWRVN2Fi5m1tElAWaqxuju6vdHhAl0QQSXxS@VHAbYxT1LdgK8HXe@XbxHpMlwJnlyWNjjZzl0X8g/ANAdjqTuGorR@jUxrh9RlFncWDJomlwpcM/e@x872WwK1pgAwgqLi@Gbkbvjp/W2PVTF348rEEJPjST5WKKH3tHkZkyj42QYS/Q@GmHBdBcKD25KDbNrXiJggYLsJ9mBBQ15xLpcEPjIwRjz5XBqUdgYBvJyAAwdzrbaQKHEdUhmUB3MRidHiB7Q52xkptCtvK4VLH2NjgxZIeqeoifYCTFdN6hOn6IJngAjJVF4B/wEziTK8IGXUDn4D/kFgpyMc1caQcOX4xUdKYA51DcPmB4@OL3Q1HOnuwjHYjShFJc41zIGAFMHjQ2addp5Oi/EdPUuE4EQSw3sd9NEJdLtCzBzzX6r7FSNzdL9OQ7M9WUDMLlWYArCBlx/6K3MAvAioMJQ2CyUs6VETfgA/0EzLndxjcvsyhBTgU5mIcUIQYNtkP89bODQdFrN3VGxf9ggNS5Js6biEa0omChos58jLo8RHbLWFSg0JfH8ZWgFt3p53hG@z3RZSc98PMZm/mLS1MrtUJJ/3EDi5ybp6u9jfdRqfnXmWadCr8Anc7@@xYr26kXlwE6iQTYMBI9Dcu6uqLzL6vGVZv3HufE@RyBigzPpgNf8tFSrX2K7wdBprrvzXQXZovHWbVA4Dwn6pQGV/YV93pirAAvMDZTM3rY9PwPnO5nMJte4QONXBHYt@VC09Djrje7NwPUJT2vrjPq3BGbvz8E@28TSvelVMcZHf2a2P7ueZbZKJPJyblQF4OWy9SNMmtrtwxTIps@c/WoNXM2Tc5WwSqMUAYFm0iJVp/drrTCR/D9e0dJ847MEbPASg3WUn03U53fon0mQ5fzZnipVt/2mk42LoP0IrPnPkBEFMhBMhcruwRsjD@W1VMWf50P16qrqwsw9csRO6NlLpKD31Yd1pU26fzYo3MThnwK4m2qF0Sq2ESNAnd7eJVVJ3gwe77dTsDzhSbYJPVObxC3e8qMoJduPrV/0eJ0WmozuTYHWmE/9eS6mzFr3QhS6NBDNkSDE/3OMm8YHvWEBXyqjo2EMOtwOV@u83eveq9qonWOma1hZBwy5gTGPbs1S9rGzaEoTdFRJTo5rTMn6eH5QZBcQKVFUrs4Hs1NSV/1GqoerxndKedWLnA6T5Opr1mXGa85rrFOGbQAKVny0Sif/fOtU2qSuV1yT5D7bN2SxpdnLZ5enDa2X4EcYrYY2TTzLcUc@P5@sKxZIolDcECTiZJTg8jTfeVuicntWC07QdmzrI9rJkI18LHOaTOKO6sU7/F8ym7KlodjQTQY3ML1UjpURky487t7JIt4MPbzFX2dBXkeHBovNXXCb6uoK/nOPwu14@bazW5PCny32IYZnNW8c62CKbpo1RQ3m4R1SocN9dqDmumeqhb3WxrgNGFwZ5FVdSLnzwU9e0BosgipQisVHyj9sMzKNq@/morWorezqmtxXh/cA7nLuZcM4GgCK6KGmHBuexYzjwb7ZEUdddZvRZR8ru7TbVF2eo67hMIGpcH6BJ2bmc4iX1Fb8uFsOjtlwMG6i7/q5uEkSMKNmm9WFkB3T4yy7aCK6Djjphfj5xzhyB6mIeCGbrYisj2vcVSfciDsPdOaSod6Tnk0Mhst@oYr1bVputQvFSln1MkNmq22Xn8Jf4XiAJH/KaXMwfb9XmAJbwbDUYt5FHTVeAKLRfBo5vLSmp0y4PsmCQSzChpIOrMHZ7m6h2boSWLJXDzLB9OtZiPHDbv0M4@IARJPAemK4WbZqFfhE0ShsbUutk7fpL9uOVdM9aJFYqq3WY0NJPn0gR2Rc/Cr8gv4T/PkO3BILPkrpRcho1Z3h2AIaz9ar81zCugj2zXh3tbMMDtMdd3yk1kJNUECWDyfcVPNBnM0pF9Z/3VZS1EbvOBlsNDdGoTRYDNmLa7JSPcKqk6vtEWNO6ehUBrXDI0hd7euJ9uooHJNN0qrs0e@LySwLYNnDhU38aK6MGmIYgaJ86FhVQ/MTpVRzS2PBUHVhIIk5BYL@gsEwaA/Z4PQ7oaS6YXdUILMJXTV8eyaDtGz0Dfcy148kVe3m90Y6TkGTtSlq@nqxaoQRfMqz@HZtJB7fo4gyuAMrzB25aGkAOK0l/8SP7R4JMyIrJvraeZ1oRDbpv1VoPLTLSR0ER0YdmImMiyZQFW8kdNXRKpxbDRkjdEx66/M5Dk4BFJbD0gQOCEYpnfmwxNrUJTqdVtww1gYJmfYSJfMOqSsuoTb82jOewx@9AN76a8UdsBG8OaiYzUK0ANmVXuhnMpPhIjzuLO8NkypjUlIt7fEwucltJYu7nO3OtQQLjXlEDsvVBH0EnEtGUJLWH0MqcfuYH@BHaM4OXKhTU04zLndyK45WHzDlqFF1XycZGRMZiAVDRSqEJpLZ/s@ZtXcfwlVCwxN1WanLOjCoip6@51Q9wLsX1eNDqM4zomL6eWG/Yqgm2lSfBd1JvZY084ZV35tBK9b6@WDqVmgnVEPh/CM0XSGKRr/q4EMtu6f496l6blWixTPIQvxoVsusOUccX4uwF23xM0Qc3wU2DKhCD/MQRjdpwzqwcqLFtujE/sPnapj2z@lAekVunGOZPkaJBvANNvdMI0@J0mlk131xXGPZ866IEAYNqjmm6gPG3Bzt2WFjU2QOccPHoxEo/VhmCPW@VDdutsDzkzVc2ZodbMMm9RIgdf2/E4ZN2S6i45VGUNsyzniWgMXlIaxxvsLHkVwDOO6ygzyz1cJUqKEctFSxOsBYzl642ypy3Cp3YFqkH8Upg1jP4SccpmQVmJ1urIz/ZiMQZKNgeDsxI0xEfKcGSHEkFAPWeOOCZJ0VhWHqWwOTfBO38H0X@n7DbdKMQ/PFda6dg4p3tgsb1Mp94DyaPVjFnku@iaDorBZ6kZssRrpHlgxGPFAL8rF/lyNGaHZebh2NBGNCG@FuKK76kgPuwYMuqrCKg6MZS8ICI7D5kh1WbbmkYg7ZEkACrMXi1Hi3w3GkXYJkA6qW/tMj1kxdnEFLqspaSQNTU0x2TZ9q1ut2ESmG2ewhMWNul4GbIa1uGRRIZ4QJeVh7tLHnO@54SSMu1lNULVdyDCZGw@jqeYTgnlX4RSeZkPUBgZ1ps6ObGasbWPixql677Fov77LZUSIT5BBclg1ozdmDN7W2OKXLSBY5NkAFIBu6vQB3PjxAAvBUWn0xowvJMoMKXMcsvspVkq1KiKb7yR3m6L2LPuqqChPz0KFmV@AbbUaL9dAsHI88MZIphm41kgz@C1x7u3uAsd9WfWa1RoFYQohnjZFDCyXXQ4AZeIaYMA80G5pYIbRVIdjwV@JsVNKdgXq4t6XdneJ9sX6GVqWZ3Aa2zeZVnPeoC/VMHhjsnhOuSb23OnRu7QEzfCj2qB9Qbtu@gd0BenxrLdI5gRO4Ia@tF4TIFqz2cKqD8O7FJsSIZc20aCYsggpOMZH2Xy/wdhKDCPfTUVU8Hl72KVrHwFAaeDBHPJSHwktiaa/JrgashTpVBnDxO5WXtskW7lwz3XP6@5k6HtaFP02MzvExsH01EPf7AofCYV5P8xfyjWOy@i5pwZeMbenQVyyLZrmE7WnCQsRQOiDoIVU7GsampPwisFPbkHM3fXB/s8kF1@25omzCD@igPFq3bRc94UiQYQ7s1t2tW7hcjPVu3DaefA7bIrRVEufZ2PxbZa6ZRyA@zC0sEGBfqJJmhbfgjlD630GO9l87csk3fRe2WZs8YZacwfOls7Wx9oHKq4f15tp23oi0WczT1uSa8nQRCqPbs67lakcOIb8Ok1rPFPmRZsS3MWcjDs97KxaRHQ2OqkmUkLXQBnEU5qxRTu80CEiv6mGm0ySs76y2DnqW0odonOyG809oL6f3m6fQ6MS9asnarr@hx6GbBlWgzY/mbhphjext7za8rs1bahQGbkfx1C7qjCWkeayvIqRZgPBkBjGxHrxnfu0JBxRbPWQPJ8ZV@EGuwY9afn3XGsR6tCjZ3WzZoa4ZsA2VVuoywJhyIU6bD5T06jlbd5Y@AONa2wzTs8aAgcwUoVQC0Hp7rODpcTamJSI1UL7Dm2/IpCM4o/piupaoYHtJTGtH3rFWPZcojHp9iO7IrRm8XXtFnizIRvE0EILGSdpZi4RdYCIcNmyTjW/2cpyVT@ahp1KZi@uGc/vijhNyBs7Npkx1jVKaK@UBjMxQwhlERUTjGRCCszYr646PZyZc/PhoKFn7L4xcVIMDNfOolwox9v1Hgs73XPO4sJzCoNUXz6qgZ6zopbtWZa9wsI2azxw@fYNmsQfn0Cs5VbI2HrMZiJc9tPKPn6bzUJdfu2LFe7XfK77aQ4mWXvJBQGq5gbp6Rjc5kuvkgAy3wJpQQnYosXGLd5e380G7/d7Aw1J2jmZirVkmbvJN1O@k2FbtiatzwkUeJ5695cORqZKzdj/ZiTISWrjSxYz8umWd8Tiu0VG@JpoUVQ87K6tSfxdm0cm87KTTb@KbdH61f167838FOPnXU2hA0Oq6XZ76GyLmmEmitHK7@zfdsGp3AD1WMGCM4IGro1kumHxQ/@HnVu4aOLmPLzYRlz4MQj1@HkgcVjwL@wyZJMv@VEOe5TsyUTuDjCgBZ0vWvtrTBYXaKIxGxqmRWW0NBDf1063U8yfvzhgH8fRor4wdwzNOu4p1kCl1@widu7mkjb3wFf5lBvIuFaDwnjO4l2MGTReFFNYngsyD7br5MQHq2V3MVek1qlG2eSxAvtrktt0Oi2NzrZb3m5Lk/WchmGgkDwYy@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@VS2run6C6lAfeXK@/WrGFULYrcTzNbHvWheVaTJNRNmbbMJZ7xbLht4e72eObwr7q3GdVlm2Bpp3Lx1PBinWfQD5o1mU/FJCYnl7BCAZWRffjACiTnZjKsVEx0u@mcdGeYK15eogOSy9jf38oaGYB6voZQvBvCyendanXl3kJBhBPE9ry7Ydjb7T@ONWHzwLjd1nP0Lc0B0EEocv6yGTLwQ17N1w0ELi3u@q1KrdYbcOY6s4udy@ZtHFO3yYNViJcolPxVnQx0cQdh0IbHeIPcIqR7VokLiCEb7W6MkXoeo7RbevBYhJWRhH9YxxW8L@wJsvG8ja2HEoyQbpg9/iMt9Bi8K0Rq59AAlsqgbZuGdEXT@ybYS2EtoeH3Y1d8oTjRHkYcWzh0slNwb@8CM4ZVKzRZBDB4KZarJd8fXbP6wqb5ZeYFVXngCm@jKSb7bXBQIyPNmTh5ytgyTsl0xnUVsdxtcgNyz4RTWPaQZlQmQOHBd4VPBTnejQTeDlNfRGey2C@SQT5DrM2pr@rPETtSwNnftosOQ6LjkOFJf1n62PgHqUjA8xZnCunzBR7tmTsQZYRGaglo8FGlWJ5euitLRrl0rBOmI86zOSpT3eToHguU1sHMUjbTXPikrKwSaMuQOzKETqQmD5BRuWCypl4n8FFvmmqbEAYNxtzpy2RYXUz2EQjF4Mdn5JsUzgoBAn84fZx5vv2TjqDCbxdkkKzDku79GAOqvxUx@dgj3c4vc2136qwje2hU9JW37hbtOXufTJomO94OvCBjgWTsCVRwsLLp7/mHlrJdKpYwGZHMUifHLD90cgW9sWWqj4LbB@K8NCWdjBB668w4ltP54dqKNXsxWO/W7VPuKJ1ONyJTt5W2QU@dYyhbDI37AhDUoAN1aLo9Sh54p15LRuvb3UdT3M9Ma/swBtTUoZBpzPgyZ@zvgJ6xlmmCcr0G8ni0W@73w@X887uoMVGxY5M08j1tpKyNkjvW8e8M8QufxVf5ox96vlKyydBsTevwPeND2Ryd2xurCds/QetKgbTTfCpw2QTIUviE2RKMnBrH6g2L4qrS1yKwKqoaDwMku8jurNTvn4DrgkIzxes17M2S/bg42Ya9EwoAmUaJff2Li/PgXzNVsWTyWcczQiJkFUrAQKSd6MD3HZAN8HfxUyh8s/XZz0QfB8hCEodZpTcAZixkUgsKhAFxPBEkXQ@BzK8jvx14fxXXMOMt6rJShJy@XdKscbySBj0slFDObbxe1z2vsGGTG6dj2OZ6nrxaNdjPzV0QzaghuGYjOGBPUMp58Hsn0l8tv9jw6lH8k6@yxQitBk5BXOtFI7omym2gC6ar7e8LKNBozRgGQwmi/EuTwXgnIvenvIwXRILUjXL0KJJmdleangGBTe@w0y1JqGZ0YlEOWrDYlAuQ/nNi31pJlze9FnJvH4F90zp@ALAzrJrG6ZLLbCOTKsqO6IoFdbGmAj4IZmiMoSfwcm279qlig0A3AmH4GavdTwn7NKtHmdXj/6qHlIs3mzSgmdbjVOsoC8Z9OJ3eHRtqDWz6WTgTQvqmYU0t2UNbOf8zkW03@Iq5a5dbHxMGHJ/eDfLHbOYjFPXx7KmJ6N@vh730XiP8sNz@iHfixnYr53WKc7OTGBgylD6ZTF0OBPM368nb0M1bOx4o21YWGcDWNnxpAwzDboLyxKLzk90M6sRt8ZXTVJVR11RbS0zGzb3YSL1RnidpzNs/SM1q6KLJndsRTHVfQp2pmxI8yanXMyvLR/mYCw47NKtXj2wnYOy0bEFpNAl3hpmuhdmPvJDHPZluPVq7shYzegcIIyVYW3wWLamPVYINB5LV8TZng/PMMyLzWrN9hvERkMU@sbKiMt84qTdqFDiSCSwYFkcgRAN160pXe8WeaTb2CNIz9@975pgZsSQVgiqlitYSY6MeoXPpYfE4btw5E367ZEVCD1cUQmbcWcqZj8le2Ni/3KO6eHzOkvP5ElktvDRCrzwm8B8bCz6dCf/7IfjdbmPzouF8TktAGtmnVczVn0xRy0N86rAaTjtiQCYBZo/fTc2RysigJygNE2NoUzXirNyEhcivY3ccyZeRPm9mITombx1O8/CZrSRRuaSAX@D9nfNbINmfftBg4zF94xReOdTevDvCLKNzf8mbcPjvvXaxdUgZcqdOlOcfGOrYd@mbvrQe8/KIPXGeCkscsO7uwa8T5wEF5wahgzq0jxHEX237dfZtdgPdnkwly1YtGyaQJ9SGMi7BXZgldkdGgbDLmjoGLPsa26UcmbSBI9Vi2HTy@7BAewzE69JK3gartaNTLNkt6@uBnsB@JxibGT3AGzu@RTCPdi0G3R64s6wOFTdQd7wN8esNMMhnc/TMA3ZRH7iRDQV1YlsQGkpapOmW4y87PcLtHI3/UAQggf5fm7Dkt8ZzlDymfZFf73SNV7SE5/5OGTlV2x1kDFLpUgNlcxK88JFkVVtz7LxEpaAq3IF7deTMpZkNnAUXKBGxTo96mxkiMWE51pGp@TQCPslLI8rFqiKJla2fcFVpHFGEV69GYY2zv1bSk0gohv3gdHB/kmaNg9t3mwv3UXXKNnOSLADBDItu61kXcXZRmGuV84BW/Eni@27iDtKbuOmGv9gaN0UxVe83ji6RsfQyRQxK4sbapPLfHS4evVJNh7bkUKBHoUg1f45BKsYq07UmLp9a6jwmQ5n00i2OflLtuPnXR2LATsjdtvg5uuBqkrskTawt@Q/0QpX83g6krOxuFVCQsYsr9sGcBAni7s1YQdlPqEDlWvrbKHR7PFC0Q@VZGqrxQWeljnknu55chik7m6E9LyoZUfqQR43B7nGL5mxNwO1KkeE2qy3NMFb4M9tycxIz6R5zf7jr2GpXqNc7POnk83mdvXHD0RaOmoh7l2Fn28Ln8kzKtzQIXSzJwcWP4MnAB9kOW4QNlc37b7xrHb9zQ1z1ty1HLIlbun2suNbZiG5Ggb3xzJ6laezOtpC0yTydfmd62WrnZO7SxJaHdSiQYe02JuzYye4oTxgO7rEnMxK/2mdG1hfnS8XXVH28Kmv21mSYUW2tbRk@eQgNBf687VJwA3zXAFTRLFFTsABZ7v9pM@6BAMt64LlNw062eMnuYUvYuYs/5wtcDhvQmUV@iAUzMknB8VwEwahpeKXPIkQNvKzHER@zeSy@vEyrKXpphIAJcceHejDWnPwjthvU7NrHVMTktJ8Z0SyZO5OjVnEwlTslimtk4bLW1GH/mk5e5Ru/6kpX/XQPyJRKN9iDUnjzyESNXPYa9rkqkPwa@aCpHZtyaJvprhN7h70w6cuu169Y/18HdKkIsQA0MbMtiIcKZqbMkDaYthFfZl01g/YoWYJZGXJ0t5MAUj5Bilg@gAU2xlWXQ3q2J6@6hjtF7svbsMgej1JRkv1IGNaAZGmdOPoUFW9cHFnc6EywSnbUecYeWzLVdJbKp6PS5ptcAkVP4svenbUcyB4xMcEMhf9AoTAWcwxtuOHT94Afpz8Kfdf/foo39KLDi5MkxasiPFjK8YAe4rEEAVCDFrTdlgX9Mihhqjiq1WgxzY7gWRiauQnH8ajvdippFM8Xk@MgTIT0XBhJTMQKFddvqEmM2FtvrkBZhRqFwyAYnPWa@DfTebZGDxcTPgWeJW/7sK99h/vxWJaYCEDq46bOVCrq3RlICMA4AxpxWyrKew7iPnwjxqnXWVmOufr8Xq@zlEG@@M1zQ3b8tGExXmVhWUQr@ApyPfl28AN6c128u6yKBzBqCG/fgkS0H0uTNDsgluIEheLt0/Pcga2kCJSkm2hKQg8mbA14oNP@@AGt66d0xW13rqiZKwJBKHacIBElMJ9vp60hNh3y9PhdJnADE0ZGXkZPTSu7IUW0/8FbZIlX0hNyNv1gzambdRCHW60z3HmtjnYxsw6dCUpPOR6CuFgWO2Tq3lo02QotT/dNLDkqIHiZC@YDMnEN3RepZKLqvfWi6YVWibbmcc5OBvjCi/GmyEb@zp3V3BU@wY@NRUuybaydhF1bmK4tNC5V@cwX76oLoiFm0PAgi1YuHs8XLZg3/AeMOy2frTG7K7c6FkMgnXVQCiZ6fVRKEecJQ3wteHGJrkPhaZA51wFqQ7DlMxcdBmNaqayLBvMn3k@lh5R7cBEWxa52FeQxuS8zOmN5pjYhgO1rXEvMCpd65IVZHSSlTOkbh@kkDCKPX23wWPb4FxriceRqL6C@rFsiWo7qLFe6zupnbHcyDz8AUj@HQ9QlOw2dE5ZnnLMCQ06ucDM9PO3OQ0kqY6nb1hKMw8PRkt17CuTniDy8GMDojnPtVuNU9CWj/GKW863wS@hErOWzL4UC8ouxZqOLh0zsj9cnsiVySgE/rZdEwM0/CqCYhc@mRChgQ/g0AP1zZZs5UnXrLa7NQyTPNuDB5ZtGHb25aiOHhAQ3mDyt4tdg185au7hXJrjZ9KaY6ygh9ukK0h/PVkA5OFeTHWY@MRK3F46YNsV/PWs@W0qwrx@Ew7SmF5ZsF4coRQv3z1Pce7XvgVai@kkKrjzZhKsWNvqPBRyAxgYqe7rjuz3SWKoxO3M/xdgzV6vXm4D1i3Hhg7ifBx9sJAB3RMbyDOmkCBmF5Vc3QFcceJbgTCAnLuDNbIsmXYzKkh9uXE5Wx@9paI63c45WOaVFYABgkULrl1dw9Cte6PT6Xcam8U8vLr9njc5DfvHeHmDC7CBB9jIy5aDeleDmtokoP0Ttl0pg1d5Qmdv/AAVtLK79Adbx0vJso9k0Gi7rFp8mGXPuYG35nIkr7MaiVmaPH/LqJpKSkXHQ@W3kMY2lNnU8mlyWWY@J9toM4xxh2A86exn63YuUVsM/U5hdz7ARLls4fwTBBMPfnIGKYratop5mOONY0iCEeHZyewi/EHcGSgnYTCZcNKuzLU5V88xWx0MoFyfkDNBpfGroI6bnyyDvGXizX7ScDLpxQvft2brueq2lCjrsL@7MSk9dOAdb65LA8PWMWYsgSw4hFmfyPhO9PANrnlYfe1L1YqTIVHrTttXcdOv8TJtl@nHa2Nm0Ui5TnLYsukG/d56RsrZVgiPdUzF5nDJDCBRb832tqAtvc4ONtWXaRDnuRzSXIgNcTvJ3W3t3f9KiiqvVKWRiKganTH1hCpWjPilN3k6Wwx/xQfXriYi7ucLdbQKD2O9k6EJkpah8J267EQvHrar6szmSV@@MQy14eab@LsQqGZ7rLtDLzis2iHg43zobgfFKUbhVH3dkhOIcASr3rudEXybUA@ZIRoP6nDuF@AhRVvgLtV5bRbOxWZ4LJpAIGr68TU0cjVsVDbnM5@VM9t8YlkzajHT0ELJT0@85WgodxsO2bBgqB7isV3RVyvFJnEEmRCT00uYLuk1sXGoBPJ5UbyVyNl9rxm3enVgE8bvYAy@krnEyp8zF2Nl7IBMKFsMtodw6Wn7wcBVbM7UQqfZbYU/7GztRMx4n@s0YA5ewG3K/mJDe3NjU@pAkptFMmGZTbE/zpt0GNneP8I6x/Q1nGFmUEVXd3vCQsdMvpIx11zVVtbm9cXaFqULtO0ephuuCCCuCPGRTKmTkcoobADwyXBQh5NzyKR5PMUv6rDSbDEIZlOwcM@X5miPgLsI52Yc7niVbpuq7uwta2YdMNs8tcvEjE8X9xlUfli7b7NPTZc2sWOMmm70JjKF/TP0dDhfHqbYLKgPTOTER8LNb7U3kcp0hIIz/83rsDZR83kP37@9V7HN2Cdf49Ky8jtAC8g3zdeGtcLx0tHrRHbEgp3sgWJVx7B5Jtx6c/wWQXuLi9nn6VAvFomyGj58x/KeQoIGs0r72DB6EUWCC5Wjp1nIsYg9v14@vI54sTECKO9poQlpe2M3K9T0Ln3SFVtlZnsKyVUDsNJz6C9AZh94ycIGKqxwACEDtdlft7mRq@XN3qpCPzZNw4h9tR22kWPDTci5A6wtyxb8XDiTUnoZ6MIhTkOjhStfWQ8mOoTDxu0AsnFecId4PbGbEssNiulGr4Neehx4ILEtDhGIYaB9h90j2cYwSC/gHROwUh7A9TfPOQvai828rt9Ocf@6WdcqFc0BaCDprUDRQw9YyScoLm8cy5KmzT/Zpk61TvJLb0BsRR3OMOlgbacFKl0q2dRUbeW61GDnEHabNId2ewV8MczrMzxtBXzF789pu7cYiWVVndbR4SaKIsAFFiSRhN4dYL7P10Y7Ujc6DCx@UbITmtFF037wlNOIDUPGLJuwTnFf12MkHFMUy4PjWoIyY1tiadWZebRq7oTpj3VCmCqEa91WwWmZXUh1U7hoX2/h7WCP@O0eV1rpVsMfYlONz/cCFTEefaaVtDFTHy8ro6TXOSYz7dStQM0/fyy6K/4a2TTeRd/OhbWvSyPnH3PPZEGDR9s36WR4JLwtk@vAeItd3ByDVGRROIetQbEOcmxoybfRwVclm2y1qKOno6UBDmC5njuq8W3jZNmYqufXg50TVA6DZL4s072qBx7BbS8YibVptwlWwlw3ttou7g/mn80Kebci5P0oF4U8nNOh6cjYzTHC@yFJ6Hz8eAObGpEMteg43doUyzuquLLlRqI3bBGvaT1k8nLHLHQLi4lzr@8kvJChmx3fd1BPm@gJKjXaADIs2zHzg4roKJTmogvf3b1egwQ1tP2J5erwTEelhOV4rgUEGHpTffoQ1Vggca26IFnQaArBT6bHVSh428J0OKuNViWhU56Y/Z9ZyQ7FCNEPaHwueaBMjy7cBFeyb8q1Y76RL4bwJXSw9d1ApOjzqD43fy3O0CHGBgrqubx6f91oz8uSE0SlwhoYjTar/pzWvp2x6kyR4y@kNxJFFeDb9Sa6yn33K8m/pb4aBNE4rtLXDWk23g5RTyGnnSyeLEr7wYUomhesu0Y/2TiTe9Q68TU6t5dZX@pfntg6z14sXi/eAAHqOeR92sYt2bkdjmfzknf8arfPrqEFyU8qkGCzGhKucpfUqTIlIRmHzjIoyogrhwd@E3/KK5Grdl3E4dH2PqB3g8C0gfQtmJR3BZeHbNIcIBkhk/1xwOyiBV@vnUC0bKJiSyY5l24ZEdEqdNZakeR3Zden0yGxuNKO7BnyYWZtpF441F4n/I0V3bhJDzgaZb3D4pAYGYilV5NniHsMJjSOntu2IdV5Y0J@Tlggr5tM6kzAME2YPw4@7Y0Pys36sWJbBYOcNwP7uj4lpGQViWKZt8Q1BE@VFzjAjcrBjG4C7zT/t3Map2nT90u0uXvKdmE/9tWnfurzCe3SbN0QZtEylByHpmWaf1JxPVmidzqIvhg7mVU2RdxGTXYUcTPW/HovenY@oBP/RN5dMlJ2EFUZDswxmbXLgK641BS8NhDIHux9WseP5iMAmS9oy1hUfVHUYgG10tgH565dK4x4Dhf3Z8/i4BuRG@nqAjA0Jy56dJs4UEWjTSrVY94fF/xsS0l@S5VGfdq1eyI6h3riuHvTkgwzBBp25CM3KQTzurgjNH@aV6En/HdZVHEB96SqWeS6Cw1AJLqLWPySqGtRHj1KosUQYr2N1EI/tOEOFrueTbEPbG@o9CMIfR3PoYg2FhrTGOFUqDMNbQQX/@pvZpZMyOLFYHBzswIv1pnNT5p2Eq@wgmt9tXMFkV7vj5NH3PaQSmyRdT2uFGAnFfnguvS4M4Ljl30FMY4sZjVejgSGzeegGa6w1vZKXjh2pyd8udxoHN0m10vBAY0xRCRlA6lpcfnRYO2ZxCtWP7BqY@g@808eVwczC9ZBpamPScTSiLyYVLEccV0RPYiqwCWUrtWDk/twIYodYYOXwJOrT7FaX7fmShOe9WCvAQvpJUGbBJGIz@wM9LzfaAJPuLokbCrtCru@m@bka6jJV9C4zSmoqNK7OVgbvDPj5xRRxlhaN2bV9dqNIWLp3c9yP1JNt@Dzdj@H9Xo4hrBcA8XF2olj3FYjpiuZLdoQ3jTfrBb/OuhYlubDbromkleBKLU/bMJOa5xBPFsiKozklJ1@0ggX0TfrZqFeRmslzg4WSvGIxXccKZLdlprWKlSch5K9y3dDP1jEDaTcDdFSRFzzEhcZuZOTbTgZuyDs7fc41/c4Tqwewk4rUrRWW3ug0s5wsmlvDvzN09uSrvwkUXcrO8sdNzMHvEQLQNy2GXdyeTfkt0s1k035K5OcycR5Sc6nhtV7/bpmlu3gJoYldeA/qbz3HjOuO6PwjZdYetU6k8IyG8PlNtZzxQxJu20mtZtr3eDhAJ5LfizJVFM1KUiDVf1cPf31YnOahg35lrvZrIxem88k/A070cwZw6dlw800HufpYgP@Fc7ZNvK@AstiYVghovAZLsLoOc90sanWMxe7DIClR7Fx3Ksyop@uzLan77bzA6BRRhWBRFyF2ijV8xET4r8tzrSjjh9GaVmPv@jQ5GSQEuLpdCnP8X@hIgWyAMDqlYva7pC2OFh2faTct3dcQtgrj3priira3yfp7sx/FDuq7CdW33GMxz/3uFU5eyBde0uDouNK7JQQGAd0hV5XpZuKa6rIQ2EDIld59k1JNzrd1MIe0VKaJ5kWLyzw3qtpa8qCnq5SnXAybNX/EwEygOpv/l8RkD/MUgoPWdp7ecIVmw7fUsgWcXbNab/2R7XiCqQLd2bErnqdVeIxh0YGLxszGJ1PhcxhePWl2QzIZ3K611U4hUTfQve@PfRk7IOBhaUxaIFOQgk0fidwmCLTXpPjKgOuJK6WCd7BgD5xtNU4OEnEUbFm3Iya8ONykxBC@GF5onOyl6z6GlyoM@5B1ux3fxbRNO5dEDAM0fYhOlUo/IHMEDQy6DrazWeoznySxqTjxR7rnyHCYmdtlt6Cd0Bvj91HZiazoSiblRvpmoyMmsdFvf@M86cmKoup3h015GVzFY1eonnp2AT5bvLWEChVbdiV6GEKn8v59AeSXuXOQyOa3ZpvOVdg5a7sg2VjO14ox6vGke6ymz1NVQRIeB1@NQYjymN81w0tmhoTJs3N5HgLebLL28S9UqGTDAdiR/2cjoYbLG7sxz7h3Fmbdn/h2V3Tq4zb5mG40ZjY4LAwfS5uNC7dHAYQVM/iN17mW3KLuVHqWYvfxmtmiOludLCat9jsOBzi9E2a/ZMrNrLnyLvQsfdzzQ8uL24T9b/78V0eelrUTWX/5PJWnDRM8owasTIJS5JTtEeqL@WwPnSi7SmmB04kwRFdrvn/JnvnWiUe9I/SEKGURVdLV49l3cUO9SQr9vq2gtd5AfxwCFCQV4wAdXNFYo7oahAB/iIy5YwUbiCD0ZTeXvZiePlYXLiuwb8parikXFPOprJw4JgS4VyUDY4PM27irAqNI2AJLFSlnAgr@1dj3@f80YIPcR3GGrsnLvwrP5Hs9EoqtelzqTlulOwzyfxN5YIQRaRpkwPO1DBvaKTU8KQdSjrdw@WjXsl0@PigcdyuiybYggeffOKNCiQIJcsZHc45afJ5UDmybNa8@K8Vb991zWhxU8yoE6oQu2GGsIeITdy7DlJmu9tGcFzjjc@bMgolfPafbmczPXYDYNrm7XhaMY/7lerflFKZDITFIh6QzdyDZFMv03@2g7n0cZpPMFsaiNENNhW7pOJmZLwbEHIaIboeTnSIK/0YTUP1BeoM1lPUWgsIbODu0h3@vO3Fa31b7I/t7mPPh9pzDphzu0Licyhl9x2pcKt4lBUins1edbKZVjcd1pyJjB83hKzKZsj80fOMdnGqrGBPz6U3xDRUSIFDTzb2dnx1qQ4dNIzdCFWvMCQG2SIJE/sqoHJaKopCyRSY3jimfk4CGxGlVwIqPJQGoYMUXJHwmE@xUXS0y1PgpA/hgQC@t1TQO@Z72KCrCmixHP6GH@A/oiJ67xcvD4cWa3Q3iPKEnLIIPM72rJzOPX3cZJAOIdGa5PJ4AJYNT9h1fD6uwgH/1nfQvY0tF9TIB5Iq@BgY597lVfleryJPznZ/pqPnAGjLQi4HTpy1AyxmR/6zPjd@SFjYNQvIu1FGq@hPs8mflNZQnGmmi3O@RU1gDPUnsqmbtugkkgJ8Oj1H3cUBLwiYJQVnnB1F9n4NFMwEaMOsDIGy11KihW1Es9QYj0J7R8dE5lurVkld1@IJY9fMQxXb2e29KMsBC0DJ3sNswPAfi1fcKFOL8yNaNh@B/jVX@89A3Wtyzu3Itxqy1/MXpglLBey6w56ft4BUyWZ7/RmGl3U6SW7YMQO3Jbp1BmRNV2CFpSkKd6BmlOoHnRywpPa2yQpbKxt2UwdZ1Aet/jLWr1oPwMCplSJf0GRec8r2zioCoZy2W@xGem@c1ZkI4crYYR@LZhuYB2awLdndCuisOD8aK8v6OiZ5QUu8QoftimdC4V@SKEb324iwQPu7qU3q0Kz1hhQVD41AZm8OwE/0@HkIC3pIbc5ID7@yeS34m9Wh9dJ@TVeKY4LKIngbUfI3D/uPDwCz6Wx@ix1ih/1membamCl0N3lh1caLUzPwan/saq5Bv2Z9DNmximi0/SO7sGGmH/PRzP8yOyPi3a6vi0Ooiq0cHq9OFEjDLpMuLbIz68ManpHlQPQT329hcdy1pmMYN10s2MWp3vSOm2suC80KfusoeGIdpvbmWAyIJ@HAwH2LCJBKLGF2oEN2uHCZjtkUJdm0oJ0ARxyzq98my/YjyXJKQTFSW0mb5wCpy5NIaP7dwm958W9U0y1cvGMMf@nXFe@JIWxsmAI6bDJg19eiP07c62SYXcEEDonPnln58uIGbi2OixXncntfYk1h56SQ4w35Yg@0Uw4X07EHvbgOuEoaokVHbUcOJzUMB71XnNchLmRwbHEuHbrq7GXny8B0djZVSjJAI5JgIw8B3gkNG8GKq8PQ29oG9iFZjO7yVR3X6Vhr/YDJJ@82nW8voTHzVKKV7o5k1fytwv6Kl9tcvOWXszUa89DhYAUwTdkLAKosk54zdkdLPRYd8c3Lc/56@N6QH@XxRxTd11iFjnSs6zN3Hl2Dvq0BCzJikQf2ekW4LdwzinPRz6mz1/XVzg06G6OMKmu0XcmZlVxmOdy1O3Yp2WthGGNwnGuIcviHIVrOAs/Z22ZfYD13QF4JcJkQos3ey/BngxWx3iyiC1MTlGR7mfP7ulldnrd6wn524YVtO1mlqzkp2KE3XY3NRLm6YWbhKaCoFIYH06ku9yTCufBmoZhpEPvipnBgHx9M5elwXPKzMuYDLb9VzHHIiheqWWlvNsz0ozZgVHl8AyuttB0dXS0LiJlpfQZJCtn1VxvmmXqCt6@ykTSZzv2rarlqRG9O2zmLp@2iI5DKFl0B@GG5eCvlwoHfNMGrNuE4bDLH8U74V8W2SGhtLJWt2HXjiGd3Afl8gVVxYeUbNWI7wlw9SZCB1KZSIe4g4dRcnfJTPW5JZt9OlQmGTCXfWBxnJfyL@nL3gziK9As@hiWc0Rjla1fPnhalB33szSNdNFtDkg/twmLd5m5WAxsUVwBoB9AIhYNTvQ4y0I3GVi6yjjHR9pG9EdAj1oqhll1Ru2wxtjN6mwNFluZEmZzCSlMDBkwSjuIdl/uxazTeCa@CER3Ozxml@e39V3KkdX2YrxsZ8jDpIv@7kIJdEVpIyLgwvu8YsR34zBu6vH64wXNmGLuUcNktxOzJSnUfq@vGn7Yo02e5AWOC@e1blOszuZIcrBGMq7mehEHYhl9DlI1n8FHAsJrH9UG2rvJJnO2EAeOSbQufOJ4dExOlUKGUrRAxY26JZ3Me6OrMd6yyz7LgI9/r1j7OSjGPmLdp01qnbwatlrCDcYVQ1/iU6ELctEWIb2DUy@dy0mrozgllcjhJTzfcMrIHgPSrGwB6ZhNIjEmfgj7RI2Q6ni58vmL4LVsmtQqSYHHs2a2jQHG@pD08zAlK1zwapdm0nUenRu0MGfqVGQghvZOKtFC8wOnpXIsO0LR15lTj1BmVhtlN1gjZJD2o6uLfzce4LJOvW64/U7aXiTKHYQCkm1dz/XXs5tTXb0o6ndPzH9s7aw58cHrMYFadWmzYyqHdHI8GV@xmBgoDLfdcR6RtEtxg/DuvnEuX/MIUkIO/IMss14QlYWefp2tiyT8VRqRts21VFl5u/Z40ivC0R0Va3lCKUGxmJzLUWqD6dtcWgX2zMudbtTjbUdJAe@QMy3QdYQWg2ZZN@2DrX//3q2/tNgjo@0erdo3zmJN0wULdXkKY46AtFc/Z1Lq07cO0TaJw4pT4AruaNQEEVG7WCAr8rZlY010moC/@1DLwkRhLIwg8mDNXpw3NowyuZhql9y2YLiNDCw4gcy@S74ypLmZrdlGx18w4GpwpbaaSLeMJHthmEjVmZR2G0XVKiAtx6BdsGsqEUs8yE880FF7M5YW4qROX27hkOilnReEAyyq@7uwxB6Svi/SaX9E4c8ilaEm/EFCqCemcmNUnTvfscc25qIezJJARLU83S/3pa1TRTslNYgY2YW30AtUsWzKHOw1K3eG2wxzPapQUJ/XLgU6qpZ0iGZCaDZWnhx2l26/asbujmaiWX/ecOR8VSr60y0Y5OtGwNgUXr@7Uc@G6Q80kMUXjVZjGSqok0U0skKZ9I9sPz55Lbn7VQbNxkSvdRM9oJ8XpNIsOk/gxajRpIS2s6vDNwM5lODu25jdIAG9QRY7GETacZuSBRNF132hzx37zBAo/3qK5syCmwN12XYSgOVXm0g0SVeaMKuPRYp73uy4Yk81geMxclOG4f4KLErzdbll/dwxjAhEt13fxstgzbmjElXe7hAZUDobCvMCG@cvOC8O/a72DVvlzMJo8dXuFh0GZ2JuQ2GbpjVu1Zg8Hi@4SVWv8WbR0smnrUoMMy2Atlp9qJ2aCpJxfV7lmJXT4h39FQRdtqIH@7vlDKEsg09vdwJbVzbrGXnzWmAGrHZzjcWHOyIll9CQxn5gF2DrYGVbX@h1aAtoNVB7B9jWvcWvV2qCxCGyc5ntOMySfdBaRjsMQuXecEoaxBTfHiT5muaDAa/zat7PAzqGWHp5T/LTqqcl5rmpTJhG2gf6vhw0Xd0H2zMZxmKZMxWDXDv1TF54qG7E9B7EtMCvOJ53ira5k6r7jfqfd9QaaB6gA1ck8JvjubUGKYYXKRVeaE5dAgvo01GFaYUffqa2Q@AIhEI9JxjfvQhW0X9un03QO0zNZeqk5VILLdDq112rdRDJ3LY8nnLSyFswa3VQY5IzRcYxlDFAxeLFysFD4Dp8sUMWL431GfW1r0n7V38VP30TtYTjyVNPQgoeokSKayY/6wljnQVeoNNW5Cz3jTXUTpaeyYfg3y8X2Yr46Xxvpc8xsXQ7l0g0JVarkhgVkk27C@Y3q5Q6ejzOQbZ3Onz5zj/kTRdwQxTQWbxPJsrrovIEChIVvKBPTkZ6QogZJJ7NZhmUzsQr7MCWfz8yB5A2XbLwYg6sz7VKo/dahXbAJHq91OFmadb2olHhHL4KsWbZIFiEYwtOjMfWJDo/R16bCGoBv2xh4AWiyprWjLgA0PjFnl5OIZmmW28VoGwNkP0ZnerrLE6MtVKsJyxpScA9uIbuOKCiXPmIW9okEvnAAt31ish/ZrD9qka3S33YJGTKKo9OLyX7aiM60FtPxXCs12fTzZXRt1fCoRq8xQCz@PrA3wtYzksYI9Q2UETuueu3Hi/E7RistGRHjNlXTmF9FkGA1o0iOSrjZ29N2A1d3dGzgpTN2XrVj/ORAqpJxXOkort1jO74GTFfNPS6/XL@2Xr8JzU9cokNnqxYZFnXFA5OCbtNprrXZBF7T7qsmzrhaxfnqkPuFJe80udK535MGO8T5Am3inVkiou517Uf4vPAD20Bo67IgIRwPq5jO308vQaz4BUTC4mashudIE2YZHTgLfm7b5W6IMs5GHo@svV0/RdNRVZRMqH9bSWPVE6Hpz@RRVFKI@LWEtYiyJYuVHYrMqdeKJ/CqQQqhIOUmslbTeM0bLJZwXfv4w4raR2cAbW7oC2M2H2tgOB95seQ636Tdg9i2CsVnRNEgbaR3ZiJhtDfXdeGUuFJxKNZMdeH/C/5Q8hBHopouDq2AbwmowrNoIeiU5/djdVneLOFky@5MliqwZeEDp2WHMvuG@Qx0UL3@Z5ffOf1XN7kPl69mNy@gpbiFTCQr@fU6WnRf4cghpU5842sLr4rAGM2GtVlFXt2Gz4ZwxSxUZLZHAy/Rw6Ayq7ImiKatZ0egCSLN8xbOChil8nUYdrC0YXfTkwbAagMA57Tm63975NqyoLTirUmPnsUFkfLuzlmFj0d0hFmk52iib3csnnNvVKHoguxMcFns5xlV6C1lO/H@jZ9cdK92NkVeIfV2eoU43Wmdme08jHqb9HNL7uzmKWFMEax21Kkbg69mvv9Ij0ZIk3RoZFjZqlxDiBaafJs23KwZZwZci7BlCGQ5aKQ9/tDhFCpKU5iIkl6rxFXMTaZDepbYzPERtp69fZbTcPACB4sjRpe6hepUp56JbplGGZVfFNx5Q@F5vOd7NXcibQtx8pvd7ugH1atrXerrMX73oyn16cijeFjO0HVUhrUlndlDGf9e2VdsQyqYYdrylCp@K3shMDOFZiyVlAuXvD5vBo5Z2zGNdGlQn5lENqKLaqeTCA7Buxu26yCHQC5E8p7Cp/cnPFv0JHlLda7oayRRbyhcu@TYZf@8Lk1mIXMNq/ElQjlkngKR92q/K35ZxQEp5K81RGnRnegPBtr5bdYUL9Ne8LHPbxHt5N9gl6FMvFOHmymWOQkSiYHBGbuUN2DSjkPkIm2jNXvumeyBFjb@Hidgng41wLB/fBBBJU57ssamY65kRc3kZkiJ7RGVJrPhrFEtizPOsKEf3H234Ko6zY7wkoJf6tmpy46IFfxjefCBTUnZ5pVC4C52cIuupPONmm/Uxth2O1S1PtfZ9YrMtrWMFotBXXW1PzjJo17GzbJhgLGBZIadIQFN8hspmH9p@tWGzvnq6647VAA/yx5v8DdE4Odim8QlHYzFR135Df8xB36C5s/xjvXLBbAddbmrrdhUAM@XhN@JrEpYh7f1pAjpmYsNv0D4FmPjTfvbKWeanJIPpmVHNGozx8TD9euaWAwixkyRTHTm1Q/c@QA5w@Rm2P2aScezEI125Ce@ZOik8qLo5UmtrjoxZTOGoX0ge5Z12J7M0qJJLKcoa1vsAXlpFwoXR9@JH0ezsIBH9BwW3faSu/PAit4hS3sjpLM9Tva4tjh@bckPD2O7q6bpth9w2BL/K0xTPWIzJ9bcxKP3QtCfHIhmf3UV3IMwqBh7WSiLm12No/mdCEiqX5U9X9LVTvIjLAc7ddtweKrVM62@s7RxJ26ut87Z9BWri@lnEgtXrvXiSi/bs0dSiNu4jGiX9Pk4p6/B3uVNXA@@ZrMTG0NNCrWOqwH@FGLP5sfk/FRAm/DPeIsYa1w4zVlS1aqu9OM@VZd/@nD6X7G6Pjsqbtr4R21wtbbdfm/5bZ/r9qPGrMiD52GuJLrFWGU4vEeWEJyJ7j/jQEQvsySkNHKUrch3gFfs/ZeIppbeDoA2d1H10mSbahpmNasux@EU4hrRroezJLFui3dhJgTThbDb7I@G3cUBGuviIzZEYs2q9Q6d04XVmZkez/eq9wwp8PFkSW82edQ5nvbZxm3W10hs158couXKMMgwN7nKjZWFgTHukg58VknOYBFeeK49FRC27W6u8jUpMml6W5p@7ZHoWza16cAP3QM3aXVdblDa9p@usTlO3cHztkhp6TU50GATdpcVVHH1IUGVsjrIcDeYFNucLPPls5rsIbivAI/lf33vFEkz4NjFFWKFdWiFh21gMEUXXimMoNNsedFHd1gqA@n6jgybUag70tbwoaPq2Nib/Q4GE/i3r82qkUd8rFO7UrIWT@l8OTaN3x/@s6mYw4PWZKeDCyF3q1dCzTccw4cJt4PLzSgyN7FO4As6yup4sptCYGdqOx9rCjUgMtYXI9zEXXaFNmCTs2HFCOnbDXfValcnlb4NLV/g8HYWP2xf@s5ntBEzG07KGB2QjdYrMQYUH5N6u4XBF9EbPZwqN174RTF/rv6CuG/oDunw3K933rbicTiJ1Gqc4sEbrqcTaY2tUTNW1SVpDokMs8gCa/CCq5rL5SlmvFIwTGeUTwyyqpuQCfcsAFqy4jPJ3LGevdqqrHLMY9gxqJ@WfZQOC92zDduaThiUo@HoUXDW4f3YrAOXo5uSU4qMTKD8NEcY1IYxixydo5Pgnc5qSzUHlWOTFjBqwwDZDndN1kzRrwxQoGwjDQ@gz1VnPShGNtqZsbAql4azXC49SDKg/nrWr/ke5@2yLM0H8VQky1ZOL2WLlZ/TqwFKziRZtnOHGlEH3DeCLFWXF8A8J26UG/d3ddYV4@dpbXNqj9DnTv49ERgJBy28LZonJd1i8sTrbZB4OpPALtLgX0VwhgLjwR5CcH/TeYxc0o0WbvUFfp0cutDA5yqk5RBoFbQ6CGUbbpMFMOIgFVOW2fkGSBCUis6o27FrkOPXL07GkPBaVSyrVlvnndqfcVpgJ/uF4t2cOaQ950pvesJCg5XIV@0QyRzqZtPAsh/34eCKgSfavSvsS9x5b/uxBnin/SVoeifvyGXvI@bd2SVTVCu0ugvlehVFqU2MWjG@WzZhNAJq@5vktHAezYJAf6C79WPDFfQJGB6LqcCEhyKa/1S3uHVp1fWTjTHgFh9m4pEXrObwrfJ4NkeT4lyCYaFCWk8dlyX0XrbVJjYusJHLI5nk9aT9uD5ueD8BZuqJ12T/mjs61Sxx3BeWPcs@S8N2KE7N2h6BjkKgqA5WKPdFwUzbeTb4H8n@B1NNyIghDeYQixPTGh4v@Ga/sstxKqYUFmfAxEpVHRJXFMSKiZtHEzLSyfrq4pQXlnS0ftlWRlNuM2s4NNEtOpXwmvY6h@3ShWBcs0tCT4@51bpIbxsvCzEquUQ6mhTAHVspnLevx1lBT@V1NpHDKhaBPiIyVE/mm1kzZTjSWgPeWzIP7cbtrTylP8I@Qs@DCo8g1JsR6CTOrUy34tq4KhKvw4KJya/bOATooKwVE5ue3DDTmzvEuDLwKUxbERie62p187ydp4rYOm32mkUdFZmopTDQBURKoDVn@NO0qfp6eT7qIy1yLtTQZOMIuViI0Meb8xSiBmsZLsR7/qfjkgIXw7RNSWxNvNOg8FglXXTE5uv9VyaDA8I5K1qdo@6x9cUo7@C8MZdfJA1HjYRWd91AUBO6MiK2m92TMfuxTvQsqHB4iMIV@va1R/OAoXYiekTkOH9q2s2/4CSNC9v3HWp5xdTlmhLxSIbdHMAJjg7UIqQED69BA82Xyo9tt5SgaknqnYKKSH4JSH7A2RSA5Lku7kOBo@hAmT7YG6zeZk2Hbi3VfckKdSZSFQ505bSbjmJ3seU1ErJVl7gS@dZ@g322cpYXWtko@kB5o5beZoU3M5xtlDDrm24V253g2bpv4y3lioZBZZtyYqatXeoaSMlyYV5fj3fLNzXVRXpIOnOwroEqLnsgeMmdUYc6s@DTfzXrBK3rzvKhhk22kOGTDPsKJNn4hnJLw/eZzY43NjWcjGLri@TMRqECt4SskAESEOj2xxcgEHZTQi6uucoaqCcgRpkJfv2BF7PBURytE/djk@WgvdeuFL83QgrtbybrtK1TfL8m9ENI/BJyzDeaGY94DT8yOhiiJh2zoeR0c@WD8xYF8QCYHdT8rflsXW@ifc8m19fXNMF16CSUmiiYGI6n38BlxwZ0bh78ZSsnUuaNVaEgCmJgajXnuxwsbVepYSGc0PXajcd9NOxxq@LlOJmsxiHfEb75MM0coPGY7ZLzm67wkkLIwfC5Wo/KhHmwKh/GRQPq7vmJohwMD6oGEdlRKV4XiguxFU57dW2bLozDvEFIXw6yQBJWf@3o8BuzLrU8wYRFdUAAPA5KJk1PcLvogcsIGMQnACYbOlH5RpY87f0qHuLfKKX9KFXKeC3rmmY69frTilO8sYdoHnf7oRWRB6GrBC4qc/XyuBRX7dD@eKH0ROgJAfLRyzN5rtnxQRIgVxcxwwb/SYjXOUqijxIlqE2ntGBYUVBCb@eBVVE/hkOB9GaayeFWAsuk0NHVNjCZ8Mti4kNCR2ZOU5Z1Rx6aNgzYTcqgdZsGs8z73g609BQLR6OEMVJjAAOOELV5ND/pNU4726nfb@yohpsrmwjVkcPkqNeJXdwph9U3rYACD8ZIlNKfZyyA7qYdKCtuS0/Sth0cSc2OEVTf3iSEtl1pF9GQFX@EYROlfaNMEWssUV3P4hn9pZ8pqx5GyXUYDRYkLO687LR3lfQDdBHMcDObqLp3BtQCgJA48mMW/Y2tZG2twWV5fdv8U6N4zsoMG3EdV4yiW0aRgx@Z5gteMm5/T7/UHd3WLOu0WmvzAeB1TQ9HYQq68NgwHrc9EnuCyq6WoIsaU0MY0Dx87tkiTXCO7XJtvpnpjRFXvfxaupbSRVZEtuG7JWFtgbdoddZhIxRnVosX@pPVV3gI@AtNj6YykrazljvBgYEZ034Z6Bl0wZqvlGHTG/0s3THFh0vj4S44HpZEdvp4q/hH/bE4NBxcFSJcYkY9@wM0Z0Ceopul2p4To1C20IX/nYUS0AUfotywWvNbVPED7unxNjqGhbVZRzmtS7AAFsTeuyEBS4jSmPjKVEvXhgvmZcH59TBSzxEU0I48T10Ro/lJ2m6mRnVYQ7xRa7A3fJdsa8AGv3A6GMJM08L4IvpPvOcaWMg2kaaRb9Cdg5upoMIlpDrrloBVmxtueFDNXqsEiJwvsYoblvqmXsfryI95tx2TC5bbyy/Zmcc6XHGWbQ9nWpkxi06uYRNOzJwBjDswWSLFjeTZnhh/0tADxGaHOWsVOLPJKF5MduuJG1Jt1JK80dDjZRT@7o/B/OFmnK@2Lasxj550Xgh6tniYGB5cm0mPzHJ9h5R6e46h38viyW0OPa1LRpx7bJQWY4ptE@vXsqJpUOmypZL/FbYcUg1GkQyiENNHyIMd4WdXJ2rPIaLCqte@xV/5jZ@IGBDS2GY30GsyRjZYCR8s9uEyNj1Bxl@pUmZIl/2Y2k1DGJdWGWSABqSYcTUnT1UaX0sjWJz75sS/jKRhQWJeLwxZXPbLEwEnaolsxUQyGB2YAVWjHQgjUhvGeqIwnPMZl2fp1h52N6hILy@vSUnMdP7Deo1mL@16DasG2rp2Yx2I1RmoAkt4Kq87Iea2mPyFDeGsGVAPudi16ULBM5n4OylK47RlwUi96VHZNvqJLRQMe@cuV7LNpvk4hYjYSXGy3HrDvEhWAqtVwa2xW4LFsKbqGhtGe6pnBzM/phy54G1siWlbpngWJ8uSqt6wOIFOYKKxBwbno2yCukY3fJJ9mvu7B12ukSTksaUtbLr3XqXz6J7Umo0IeK5CL3tscu/kZijnW7kY8pX0mFH3apZt2IWH@ZSSbFcwGG@WkJOra3tyFbLD1lANVs@xrhF7o9xtw3lpyPHUQBjFRbC0Hr8z/GunV1hTWSQlI2FB@KTfOOrqonwB/tkNujMKW1Ss/fFa2tvyZ1tY2hu9bDOnmYhnfPxrVLqb6JpqqLYrSDsbd9uLXNiuXlsOT3c4Wy@ajqAuipFsAmHFFxpIsZg1nzmDK8XK5Bm58Kv9zUjOrKeFBdO2T8lQ97rAGTGQqL7kO24wDa10b09BUa4phtl9UXMeaCATWyXchXGTjutiB9jqAXTU5sMO/NnlBgjfluycEJTqZEH1Ek9kpVsdQC1IIBU1dJt2xb0jFbr07djFTtl6DkNutCEueaxk@6MuNIklvZNJkP3vPNwUORui2UDnkusrjI3S3F4Bt2zpN6YtoMlDL0CfXxi7iPzUf7zhsIVrkAd@kuHasDgrP8ar@WYue2AZpHFT0NtV5lnyM3CjIt1NNMN1yWML4s3kpqmLuN2KaYO@L/l5IpDhZpe0PXe1DB2LbOXyNl9nvnA1jC37WAc4pdmCDThi7acjNu3ffhmFTOAyfiJIJwL6m6PpSUXC9XN7y8/nsLRbYZR54KKBRDdoulai/fA7Inxu4edGEm6mGMVoSomCUdTAL0@OTC7igDKLmahpnaouqfXrN3Wxo@yNkYjmcBJ7sVh/YlGZfvJtan6ZqOd/bi5MVAS2h1JkMSzlQn0WazhLhByTYW2PnqxJmK/R9GIPX2OJ6oSpZnosPTKgR8P84Bqy4JHUhW9uugjn77r1Kq6hbmyXqWgV45GOTdf@4AFROS1Cw1Su4k7YwCIFMLRhPiLI7pWc2fVAtpXTOOn@6ZkwFpaiz1zlOomG3A9COKidbzZLW47kMlzmyKU4GDLKy0jS7a/Nbak28VNLumCtJ04om1t1fJMWH7MIBp2yR1QW@b4M//BEbLYzhCnemQKdTWC2LqZiSWXH9ekqdiUKvKES1DBNzUk/X/Ze/xv@RxOzeQ44oFE6w0jbqK@TPtSG4YEjYQwMCDoq3S5OGSnlFT8v0Gdci9dyH0WEM5Mduzy3psrB7v8cvaGDPVrWS3uov9NI8qOv/bWtxqGMHGNBSrTOtHjd6Iry5vE4TkHGlS/5SUSOYp5fY9onZql5MN3TWJdp1XHezS6t7fpcUZVcD60tWwGZ09wUV9cOE4etaiACp6WGW3IcNg3XJBMfq83b0S5O0YM7LdFgsFk5a7fk8ROCd@iJ9k8hlnCTiBqBmZ/IbzbovDH1vfz4pMCLqdiBtfrsVjvuOuNvCXG1fViAI8sDnGW3f7sTG6Gp9LfTd9xT5ptCwy0VlB@IQk2a4TiYkuYlhGsd6tUwWFFlnNPjNBVfuNjUxK7PJZAtraabxQsV0iKAY8MTj8eelZP88EGRdgSQvqGeAqTbRWbYfFWs8mpptxUNE3BbfmqQJ4S1TPCKTT04dYMso91ma6xfAkfh3FikGNgpJ18DZoFP4jAuxHpTYP92@bKcLYML8nwvzkqim1XRa/omzxis2q@tI4zbLuPquIzE6t5dJXCVdLPD6VliXLo9RxvQLZAtxmUc5bMIBN48nMyfzNOXkZ0KEx714ILNDcK0/9Brkqh5QiPfZVhQduPYoyyUob2cNha0kAKr5YY4dfiPyWoPJ8JNFEeOqs0e0Ns0fWsAMZjy3vkc@T7im2Gs53j3bpPY4sxvQHeHBSdCwG2kwjS24HzvhRpzcc@5s@fr7bq0dNWFVctq6DV1rt@JlmEQn5bJoM8ebOT9FA1CR@luhx1VMFivBlUhijTCqC9@TUZdjDORTqZt62pZxmUy/ZLZeOnVu0ed5Wm1HiXas4q/aPXU08aYgbKkh5XZ@K7bfg85TqRqjdMu5s2D5G1PsiDIir96Hd9umUSzM4VBL/Dv7HRR9JvKRldEWx7ODHIYBc/OA6Sx1cmkV91TxTjr0PqdIh8EhGkr4eSc5Qa1I37TjJaqCo1YqFLJMEter@vOSkzYu/w9pBq@7LLf1RbW1uyWuMmGEJFCGuZVXqQ8KAG2XN7ETE3WjZmP9h@XZcbgXJOLP9UCen1NZmgpFPIIp6pdt5vyzu4vB2PoJrSf9Fl83cYT7vgHvVQo4zGCuCa/RHROAxzFZFFYnN0p9K3bK9M03K7iLZLlzpFKqd1McJ6Sbw1hqrrfzS5pJlRlzqoCPD91@tb9BHNO6HqZPLyucZM07Q5hzYDRmbakEwsQtiRohIa5@77G4RVHOUZtF6MZ5tPO4qwGsWUor/Bx6RpiIR1eSbObPdOnCkd0TZcIlFJRIiW3ZcJ6UXI63HFKYzn7Dd60m2a3nHayVvPjLmClcNtPbaRqRzNWO/m08UZG4bfR3VaJP9X49nVh7Ot0gqzd2qXDc9bPw9Xaj4qOIYUini7ARs1GsmJx8FtGzOGgAHFUDrr4lafypMaw7ihGsWyxdzqi8wSw2W3UWG@IQzFjlfN4UDpFT5S5UywkrEB67Y2uHtNMbjqookztAPW8SA9xtOm3Vd6nyT4GKws@nlUW@4Ko4PMXjhcY4dnkua5S2oZBvcE0UYbduf3gcJXG0QJe028YrysmU6VggBfiRbP9B@K/GZTGbjjursUZNF4gKiqq8VLqo5SpzIim46w2UkqsDmw6GkfaDIx62hnFlvYJ1x0JdPE4PK@kt8s5i8HdIJ6YL9BMOkxo4tFWax6IkjZ2Yz0pr9X6dYTjgxfbqnkdAyltNWDJTHsMr7oftBHyNmbp0Tk4be2GOGY67ulM@DlMcKcLJ0Xp7Dr0RjlbMYUh1GuSnQ1GD4E6wxoMxrZxsyodT1Qog8uZfYDVznRmYDGPMqm3af16vd4tEvp2Xe3atAqom36@mdApqfTldUg23zamY9uLWFbLM8Vs@pYseeKMcHzA0GgEslPHpXya@4IMYOpccK6hJrBOAsVAt2AqAZM3DKZd8eaN6Ur/9wrW2Fs68PZ8pe3jCh67t0FcBB@26qut7xeQXtQ16zV6C86zMwPNBQ8UzJtmMh8ZyblKyWJtx2NRs1YPnazr2FCTLvDUYJ1uHxxRb9bobda2@Way5@abXFRceUCMu/xZq26CDUfOj6p7k5cEY/W4O4at5LOt1iRWCwFviyVXYb0qes14cRmeFtqMjnMMPXGYny7zkp1wkBh/MaQbgJ2OYP2WWC@Axu4Bbi4mwlKdvgpNsYdV8XjCEH9IQ0TTB6Zs46qNZIaC2Cwljg4OguGxUFWg/XZ9mT0UGRW9wn5n9un4sdYb7e3AY6shoIFnL8ee35Q2N6Bd47/tcGZM9qPY2tdWG5u/bNVpvn4D5xNSl2umu/nD1fVjw3A1ECjE5sv@ltTeYXnBSCsZtncKTjFh26GXIpQwievOyMiXUoI5zxIKjT3LsnFASpdTqbBFlEjNfUWVUM0MsUKoh50Dp@8SO4YF26Fg1VFJq5/cr6ggt3S7O0Ei9qIqqOfqtozNZ9FYD6nSzj@BrFXl8M39czoEgfPmpeIei0oiEQbgBNZiDDr0Zagml/UOG1pvNv4R9Wt2bufieO7tSdhqply9zg9LtVvPzyQ7433ZuS@WgOA97H8gUGdraLH3E4t@HnQRg7ralrFkZF2K/tpyxPJHUQfNnHchGA1Hp2Y1Anw8S0R6trNrRdiubXsUWYw3JE9PzgaEOz8sWkxPDl@cGqdYcqq8veILEWmkEEkF5EoUm3xA69DEatA2wU423XZlGVeSPGToS@5FswzfSsBk6L64DiOJek3MQTMcr3pVxurL7JdyOgt8uaZUjSbDhFct5GLnl23qzG6AZ9whfzTEAbse7ArX9Mqkrtihgd5yWhhK/mCxH6ln0QnmUXVAAMaBcSXGRegoQuqrZhJcEx0oNly6X9PhCE146XmX01khyYHK6Ye3rssdrfNNhsvrtfu95WuDoei2ZzmLBHhypCdwr0LfPNzL4oMZTdfAI7h7tIVDaxUnSSoCiXiGzJdvonash6nl3IVF9MuVwE21oiLfoIgLUxg6srxssLBwGxf6sXHp7Zw44Uonnle2Df01MX8maNWcCi@aYSFaY0Y/r62U28cZa4Mwy/Tu4Zi69u/6v9mRwzVVwU3Q4QLlmkYnhvQHZGRgOC7LI0roxLE9aO6HN0PKWGAuX6pYWTmVLQYctqQym70glAleDc5IK@Lg44MmXkJj5YzyutfZQS1ll3xSts4bJ3ajzTQAQqW97LdW6k3lvihoVozl1e051bktlqwLxeXSYLDGGlwwceuxcjIiG4VXcihhkQ/FWRcTcW0mLdTnQwICbt1eV@tl1IgMzFg78F3D5JKwIaGITPT9XLHFzq4@tcd6nbX6fhkLF3S4GdfO6ZJGjpbzkqLTqVqN6BegpvMQG7qIZUeVZYJZZQRmPLkj1qTebzYToloq9c1vK9yPYVjL3VuAwrralEAx2qsR6huJrlOsugOO8OGZ4CStP/xJCaRItHM88SWDBaXTQGFptr9IUFZoX1t6bu/Y@8UFMihoxaA1bGEobRLk2a7hhS1nlpSlfdhYc/H0ptiO15wiejdpB6JD1KfbiOenAMgmZGQhKLRcsVl8M8abcZiMgiZ81re7tLYfxyeE7CrFONAWas5CM02juEUk3OBNSwo22VhmDwojNdF6rGQWVbJLfL5uB0tV5bxz7khZEnlmPjG3w0Y1FReZJoy8NFu2sXewIkpMhZtD4YcdV4rB5@a5ycY4rAkRKk@9kH/pudYtzuzkATuv2TdyQ2hf8P0gLPpErQ5/PyFtyQm7Jn7RSjQMsEWp355isr4aJNZm25JGjE2TH8gqJpghMc3OEwoYy29qmIHT1k80zIRXvwkDwHUsyKeu4MzgdjBkF@y1iemN0Unz@xge5yzfWr0/SE01hfo85xrXvaPHBpiZhb72AoZRPDxeXOyq2o5/UIYwJbp4t@wEelrF7/6aZVQSp517eRBRzUk23U8hhC3b8FiZdT9fSCoZqYDWr5QgOLhuosw/A7wijb4lN0xkkGyKbBcNxSazDXi@obnWGHVjC4vVf7736NV4ZgsPbMhxc1@mas5uV4CCtWEELVk9YOaNGgmcGzPdfrYJ3HrtVYekBAIBk1M9wK/OUQSFOzv0kDTzgAwqwLkN76rLg5szUoelfNiNyMD1N4ksSVd9vY5uLWpXw5jFOCceN5Xlz5xM9rcTZ4W/tU76RbIAgrkXXFSvrwozZtYXDu7T9qwIMitGNiTLTF8bFwyHJt5cE26IG7ywge0oi706IyBDD7p2VTmLDAzLz5qwhibZ/X/j4l88@CZd3YBmt@xAfD2HJjM5TwhafkNRgqEqj87NUinpiXe7kvdrWuFCJQ7ww2pet/tIV/xAbzjobLrDEMfmwAT73jdYWwf3ZmbtSacC3cEX5psVrakL/cbCTfhaRkNXaz/WZGtdK@iO1Uh/BycFvUk209s2WwULgVIe7wt1dR@G1a4rNO1wxddNaRFBHysUb1sU6W2b@UTs2AR4VBb7BUqT7RqyBZjXYzEL342Tf3N8NHryze1zfNysaUm@cc8uReoeV3XoFScERgf2XbM2HS8NLCDAqtXNcoO2sR1oAqcvUpTowTxRz1cHmKiPszOGlqwxgo@@VPnO9WZbatZiWoSnhSV4llv@oe48r69KDOQTAKl1QRkl2JW19F@smSnlTmZv7DcYKI7x/sbMB7ZGkzick9ss24IPVG444hhPldGR7ieXI5labcoKLSDSjklq9gT6Kwt2oS69QltSa53MEqPSMiCOADqmnx6z0cHWCvtCRUwRrj5txuswMA@uJV/PtNMDu/vVHyENEhtfWMXD@CSjgga3ogkPNQTdu3UDBXsEK5FCvkTstLz17tgzmmeH8myuqpndOd58dBtdeR@7R03eHXPZkFQA6WK@Nynw8iVNdiKHpjTPrdmqdlt7jZsjbHN7sk2ArbAOKdL6wpLs7K@HahcnluU8dF7K8Ky8bJmmdxizo7@pJwUNe4hfae2WufoyVbpY@zYVqGE0EMK6z6aNUFdSmTLONBq4VdRTY1k@B5xj2wWkHsNORbZ5HwDmBB9N63BvBJIheK/d6ouyegWah34169MCpNZdHPMpBpqSEYOWm1@yfA85MbNjgHxdbWXZOTFNR5@2y1sPy5vDhkmMeJuSZoo4@qZu//@FnctyW8cVRef6CmQQixAlqt@PyHRmmeULGA5UMmSxSqZUJFRWleP8ugPcPmt3Y5DKICmxTJDgRd@@p8/Ze20/Gr4ZrexYwPR6c1BMGGCJpNgzqqts6NSOLGNcuQyHxOucScCYeTGE3uujEdO4W6NB0iTOJQq5WN7eeEpGt3RX7S7Vka8T7uCQ2BtFjA5xZt5W8QqwGUSUW56j5xAKjGfMWTyQOURHOWobw4gxY90KO@VJelSTfibUtyl1NpqFDY@6V3AN3zvjUZMiOmwKMiU/FYN6zQQdCFQk4IhFn49oDxsH8RSeOu5UedpxfCVJeazWCG3Hj/69sqfH7e1ZLFKDCIiUFvu/BUKZUK8lpRWhrKeFVGkW@oLKwKntAyAliy/s5h@TzPGV@AACUpjxW/iAq1KPkS@nWbt0m3hMa2AD92dAxdGpkjQuMteKGr6lCwFdIJCkR@br0skrB3Erq3XWH0OVSB@9J2m/7b4wGTN3vm6xcx2gqM4Ef8Vh@lF0TkT8J6FOMsGRhRSQeNHgbEWqXZmNxhBRh5cJMZjZwllzDUFEGCgLmKL@ry/06snc8GS7qdudvHLjkbTmsbzLJDIjNTEcdMVDXmyRMe/IzJ3iCvuSO2vU11Bys1@yAjd/qxk@YUZmwvcq0WHJi64KNzKDREh5ZaE0xgSFLolzEoZjx4r4dWKF7mhe@Sb6TVLOkqPQ7cJdOjSrNJdqn6mmdUlvykmD0Lo40sztpyZq5hOPEQKVAxuswbjP0sjzkW@Oqi0ei75mCWvUipcfyHLq9U6sk1ovJnxmWTBEGKXmuBwIM6y5qgQNGebA1UjqaOITljC0VIBmvWLrlqg/068u1sko6iQm2thR3lQ3GWtlTSXtQiS3ZbLJWKCYsCEYIwTCtVzF4m95vP@5LPjDoHz37SoFZBqZicEoeOQcYHAADCuKH2s6ELXzGxLCpMaR05ZfZ/5aln26AwJQaLSDGNNt0Xe3dgywwkVlq2mJRRLuKKlnJpRv8nvWiwwsMR2nl9Ij@aqa09hga@O1N@HKFSgikOZQAV8gUbtcaZVQ6nixS476r0vK6tfIpVHtsC@LXT8WCf3rqJzaSmFSpkQfgW1SmmSZ4UckeBcwYl00yLhu1wlJpMzEzfbDmRBb8ypdUviqj6QBQtCLHJn0RE6IkaoU4zp4FjPzdFMhKscmiF2WLBwuaS45Js4RO4uol3pGz5jLqrNVWW2oIoWMy6@9lIHUthC72dOzl2WD5uTQ@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@tjOKY3QaZv7l1eBSqgqX8dPYax7EoMZNBV0IzPQ4Fra4@FuvoSpNRKOOB7c4YbKNr0UGgi@fpY3fFn2xfGG14DHImJLIu4LOCN1OdpXQBv1lMzSqjith2iFz8tHmPLc5ZJp5NcUUILOxK2SuNGRsNUUXdSv4sUmHiwBfEjMxdDAzERlXIRtIIo0JxZSQwPwblcVRHW8HxmqkEUx@N6l5ACrmhGg0Azee7XNLWzI1yVhgvh5bFpCjowMaeWsJy05v/BsNJADgrFc9sKU9WZJGjheD4MkGw4oEKLqro@OHREUssilHNfY/M0oQHrWlFaNwxJ/KwqYpR00yDJAbgtpSz8aaH@fbcFoiYTZNocWP8pNhOR5ALncaCIrzwuEqzvSGryxTROVWzJWMWovlrsjUpmBq@OWv/5WUkWnTuxa1R1ORX@FhfTSYGhieKMStJyZZ75pps3x1tsRR14GqZMcTZojc7ppwipaFd0M5zJEmdXS6F98g4DP@HFLQEhWL6mftu/ivumKx5boGG0i0ryoQvcek@FLnPFdLIE2iOOxO4H7KGB4nP1POxK/ROsZhOY5DC8SppOlQ1/VJbKzPnabZbtqzemNC2DchuAHwCIs6c1mUjDo@/tXEGnGZDBAJVDXC0GPQFxS4MGC0Si93r4BuRpWJbdCbZQfBpxzJ0lqPgRSVv/aW6kh@bZB29rxiZoHDbYNGePWhoLgqRt8awY6BY0UUghh42V1qHZQkWHswRi60pLH2VX0F3aZqwaREwOq2cylYvgqz3HEzcgvbraVGuJmGAx1g@SimlrTXYMboR6ELuT8Tl3@3o0vBujuqPqmKU5fI/bndXZhDDsSzpWyadUIGL9aLI4oBdinYvVph2o@2G1kDFUDGRADxvtA921BpWaL3BsCuDgoyQo7Mgt48UVUexyZWVNCkqGsKoSnZQ46w6fBeeM6kOY1PuE6azpMvtEyaHcSBglN0RyqrosMUfkakJiTSmlgm7IPq3mYLjkaZ2dHeefCHJLWhdNjuVDwWCgxQ2DJ6aeNDuC@RZV8rNaJaacV1lCqw2fx@HJf1x2fSfo/pQiyGPz7W0xV2/3S2J0NtOGNNYjMn@@2q8sxA4BYCLIeNIYkfV5qJ2IM9h0ibrY91ETF2W5gDrOdKbZA0WkuJUW0o1P76sZrzJqjTHyXJLc43LbGXIK4SyyQwALHh4HGxC0aKCmWPyIgrGIVGpXRBRGKyJI6/I9jPV0VmZWNn6Y5BsSOpV8E@jDpTLykMr6jSMK9ErMQvnQDxQIuUWmOoodsjvUirtPL0FFCytLQu@yO0f8UzICJLbjEMTgqlIXUxLOlsjtnM3LWHrTeXdAMV0kUhn3KQnBosxzuCQYC8oVqilGVNQBKFnyBtIipVuyKS0aFPFQvXTxuvSmiM4CUUebXhdE1W9dRoKOS2JAZhvKmmVBoU23wa5ljw7ZmDnasAE8NPSS2jwqMsjf2eDqGyW3SSijJPJOLACkh3s16O1nZm1Ip1Nuz1/zyjjNCjVISHMviWw3G35jXLTVJpxxrKItudAqTlpt6LUJIMZqe5vog9WPesdHIr03SWS9qbQZaNCji0@Kv1Iqk2B3H2emkH06plUyuCXA870P8XRcOpJWBSLd60qnywvaPTd40opH09aHqgL42szxWXE@gQ5QMaUJHx7eiS3cF8qPP1I5o2RDe0aJYBXTio77ewdw@2EfwaC44MCUTzB5tlYws4W2/Aeh62HlYk7UL5LkpEXqXQPoHy7WuEBMb61yCon9sqOoWTFUNXTUeSKX5M9knaYVifqRfGBdHMVAlRpEdSiCdjEXCAlyuJUBa9Zf0CRYQGohlGWzmC780pcE@gUHh4JWmDGXtT9KahwZhbedktkM7xEzoqCCE@5aZdzV85H6wBgBsTaxmx5yq@Lm0PiyPbZmYZXrKNImSu200phUosCx41X0hYkR1Hs1wB@1HLRrohggSu2/iYTlZd8iSdHMW2tJRhRawTFOtn8qM5H11YEJDqFdn7s6K2B/6eLsAISkw1zYmfvRHybU3I1FMsAgM/sP2YTDBABkvF2sgLis13trCJtQkwrsI9i1pECUDLYZH8IMnjKpijTSABdT6fKI9NN9CaUhVey5iyEJwrZ501@08R2a3S9eBWI25GxpPFtVNlTFSBvb6PJdnpJi4UlMWJwMbnb/hbEE5oVw9hFV@KNGeUclxjnizMmVTbIHBHL3oqd1C/A39uzMmv4r4hhPcVo03SnkJYLc3KneAAhUj1JI7YHerPecbwdHkId3FLSaSosSPuQlFJjdWb3M4ekrECEbsdpkVOHgpb0xmafdYsrf90RfNk5ola5DrOAc7SSw0Xg0UjERgtVYAc0S2Sx4ropstTjuc9pzbQeFXBQT4gtkdTEgO@@UoyXspBVg5RHXSO4Jq5jo8fYNT1VZEq2sKHipp16GgvAoDWn3UruUbf26IzUTmD7KGJCFgwLr58tXaanefZWNCxNjMzzkLu0oJF9g4ON/aZ1gUjssnoLcd1@VhPotIMEESCVtKrOE6obfUx3tMvzjLVRBaPOTzhtMj3m6gSfwM@gtm@TltYFpdCalCc3zdtUJwdALdVOzl30dBmouqKgGjYY5SyJrNfXEWWSVKOpM2S5V9UGX6krG4BnQDNpqrRw1h8tuCOa8a66cq6CzILWhUwomqpc5NRQ1R5iEVLfaDAptWIN46aVkIZPHMmoqU9tveTpR2VzDGSzjNIP47cz3Ynm0lK8bR9OzqgulKfswP/Y5C7KKxgJxtg@d@W1jHnrNF9uikK/InBGp4Q4aCnZtkdzZXMV1Ei2wCloENN3eAM2LUCSN8nNgTHyxuikeA1r8mIXibopG2FC7RQOVpaNsEw6NeabYry5sciVLDAaPmK0ewsXqvTjhxqAAMGswMWkpZz1gBrdAbXpkwIyR4gaOa11Ni3sLJINx17rysocGgCupzMTj4kR4NlLKDPukEzJ1HkijFFCTJrxRSE5CEaKysPr4npkzSK8LL0KuWt4j6okR9UOxs4sEsk27AzJIoChTEHCDZqPKcvmExVipmGw50GY4xK50Sm55g1A61Miqkmas8Eg2tsaERqIbdGExJQpaIhsBMDySMtmlqNsDWPUrQgE0/g3zXqclWqy26lt0OYkeLQ5A5oKRcBkZMaFENbASXP77LI5zqtCFZQ2ZuiDwkhR8lQHz5QWWRdVui7P86Adf8y7oOIEiVqzqRqC@LhJ0vASLjA1s/PSEjHeHOaSKbokUk1WoLkli0J4ZitHwI5Uq4or6wGpSZe6RtC5Mk6Fy4BpohQZtDYl7ChpCZbL2EIVMTOr07qMXwdtyhZp5kjUYUrVOHW7WcF5xbRWEZz/cPePRm@Yo/XOg300AVT5bvrASfuMUdKsILIAqfRd5p06f27TpzMLAgQwSbexx5fe0up08ILYxXXfrl62NY78M7fLNY0@bBbeZP8vIhDokJvkF9SDoipuxhLxKkqoPL1j4J/yxYqkUt6qMliZxeYGURzqGGm0OJGThVfLEj2IzmS2L4G584q22j6TylGminvMoyUq/TGqFyJDwRwpRRWamFAtnNJ8K0pIUg5DZX4snrr6sd2yxzm6ZJFgElOtphS0IM/i1Joytsr0uEc0cpSotBKHN7qLVVvBULq4@/u7Xw/H9w/37/788Hi8de9efPz2@OH48OVx99vx49X7p6f970@H47enx93p3zefD4@/HD@9@s@b@cUf8xUfHx4fnj8dft5etvv9xW73fXd7/vRend7bq5uQ3@3evt0dv3w@PL0/v@D0DR@/PO2uHnYP24/f776/ubVfe/dwv393@gb75d9/Or@35Xd9@Hacv@bp8efbq3@@P366eX54vJrvbf/q9FCr7XQzR3@9/X9tp/vHhf1f5zf9251/z/HXr7d3d6fb@Py7Tz/v/v717u7@/t14j1cPp1@/e/hxvur01fX1fvfw8erhL7en7x9vZLc7XcXr63fbP9@@Pf3Qu/G3nF955@7/7v7m72@@fnv@tP6Nu/OPWb7v/Ov353d0esXlN@8On58Pl6/46fIVp//ZO3zj/@eLz9/0/PXzw4fDlX/tXtt7HG/mjxfnd/7hy@Pz6XO6@fzll@V6Xr98/fL6uJ8fy@kHXXwqj4fnL0/LB3O4Pf/s7Sr@9unh8@HqL1ojh/1@XLHvr27f5HEZtgV4/sd2yc@r4rBd4sPp3dlb@Olwd@Tf@@Ptw//7/h@X79/98MO2qs//ef/T9/nyA1fj@Nq/vrm5OS@u8@v2uiL2914drl@@3N/8@v744dPV23/9fP32l/NXX6@@vn96Pvzj85f3x/35gvx5cQVfXC3X5fwD3r1Yr@9pyZxf9Od/AQ)